# Em C#, para que serve a palavra chave await?

Tags: c#, async, assincronismo, async-await

Eu estava estudando essa documentação sobre [Asp.net Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity), e nos exemplos em C# tem uma palavra-chave que eu desconheço, que é a `await`, exemplo :

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.UserName };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        else
        {
            AddErrors(result);
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Para que serve essa palavra-chave?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As palavras-chave `async` e `await` são usadas para programação assíncrona. Para referência, veja: [Programação assíncrona com Async e Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh191443.aspx).

Em essência, você usa a palavra-chave `async` na declaração de uma função que dependa da palavra-chave `await`. Isso se deve ao fato de que, ao usar o `await`, seu programa deve "esperar" um resultado, e como "esperar" é perda de tempo, ele "espera" assincronamente (em segundo plano).

A palavra-chave `await` é usada para esperar até que uma função (que geralmente demora para executar completamente) retorne seu resultado -- e ela espera esse resultado sem bloquear o fluxo do programa.

A palavra-chave `await` deve ser usada para receber o resultado de uma `Task`.

Comment: O artigo mencionada contem um diagrama que me ajudou muito a visualizar o processo assincrono.

Answer (score 36):

## O que é

Que `await` é um "comando" para o código ficar **esperando** pela conclusão de uma **tarefa** e **continuar** a execução normal permitindo que outras execuções possam acontecer **concomitantemente**, todo mundo já disse. Vou dar alguns detalhes extras.

Um `await` só pode ser usado em um método declarado com o modificador `async`. O compilador precisa saber de antemão que aquele método vai precisar de uma [máquina de estado](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1quina_de_estados_finitos) que permita a execução concomitante do código a ser esperado e de outros fluxos de código na sua aplicação. Então este código é executado assincronamente.

## Máquina de estados

O `await` indica em que ponto o código vai sofrer a cisão e a **máquina de estados** criada internamente na sua aplicação (você não precisa saber da existência dela) vai ter que ficar **intercalando a execução das duas frentes de execução**. Neste ponto, é como se o código sofresse um enceramento do método ali com um `return`, mais precisamente um `yield return` e devolvesse o controle do código para o seu método chamador fazer o que ele tem que fazer normalmente. Enquanto isso o código que vem em seguida ao `await` que está na mesma linha, mesmo [*statement*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173379/101), continua sendo executado concomitante (em paralelo ou não). O resto do código abaixo do `await` também será executado após a finalização normal da tarefa em espera como se a execução nunca tivesse saído dali.

Para entender o funcionamento da máquina de estados vejamos um [código demonstrado pela Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397):

[image: async]

Como o código utiliza uma máquina de estados, ele se vale de uma *continuation* que é providenciado pelo `yield return` infiltrado no seu código pelo compilador.

## Tarefas

É importante notar que códigos (métodos ou *lambdas*) que serão executados pelo `await` devem **obrigatoriamente retornar uma `Task`**, ou um derivado dele, já que ele executará uma... tarefa.

Se você precisa retornar um resultado, um `int` por exemplo, o método/*lambda* chamado precisa ter seu retorno do tipo `Task<int>`, já que é uma **operação** que termina com um resultado inteiro.

#### Tarefa *void*

Na verdade pode retornar nada (`void`) também, ambos se forem uma **ação** a ser executada. Se o código retornar nada ele pode ser executado assincronamente mas não pode retomar dali em diante, ou seja, não adianta colocar nada para ser executado após a execução do código assíncrono. Raramente isto é necessário. Em um evento é um bom uso já que ele tem que retornar nada.

#### Convenção de nome

Não é obrigatório mas é convencionado que o método termine com a palavra `Async` para indicar melhor que é um método apropriado, preparado, para execução assíncrona.

## Threads

Um confusão comum é imaginar que o `await` cria novas *threads*. Isto não é verdade, o `await` é apenas um controle de fluxo do programa como é o `while` ou o `return`. Claro que ele é mais complicado, mas não faz nada além disto. Se as tarefas (`Task`) envolvidas precisam de uma nova *thread* para melhor executar, isto é um problema para a classe `Task` resolver. E este tipo existe justamente para abstrair o tratamento bruto das *threads* permitindo um melhor entendimento e trabalho do programador.

## Seu exemplo

- Enquanto a aplicação está criando um usuário, que potencialmente vai demorar mais de 50ms (este é limite recomendado para decidir se algo deve ser assíncrono ou não);
- sua aplicação está livre para fazer o que mais ela precise fazer sem esperar esta criação acabar.
- Quando ela acabar, o fluxo será desviado para o seu código novamente e continuará a execução;
- portanto verificará se a operação foi sucedida, se foi vai fazer o *sign-in* assincronamente, ou seja, vai liberar a aplicação novamente para fazer outras coisas e;
- no seu final retorna alguma coisa;
- se não foi bem sucedida, vai adicionar os erros sincronamente, ou seja, vai deixar sua aplicação esperando (nenhum problema, pode ser uma operação rápida) e;
- finalmente vai retornar alguma coisa.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: A melhor explicação feita sobre metódos assincronos

Comment: Só seria utilizado em método que fazem operações I/O?

Comment: @DanOver normalmente é o mais adequado, é difícil achar uma situação que seja útil e não tenha IO.

Answer (score 18):

### O que significa await

A palavra chave `await` serve para fazer chamadas assíncronas, de forma que se o método sendo chamado for demorar, tudo o que vem depois da chamada usando `await` fica em suspenso, esperando para ser executado numa fila.

Por exemplo:

```
código parte 1;
await FazerAlgoQuePodeDemorar();
código parte 2;
```

Se a função chamada `FazerAlgoQuePodeDemorar` em sua implementação interna for demorar, ela vai se interromper, deixando o `código-parte-2` em suspenso, aguardando para ser executado após o término do processamento interno da função chamada usando `await`.

### E no contexto do MVC?

Uma ação do MVC que seja definida com `async`, permite que um método dentro dela seja chamado com `await`, fazendo com que o MVC não ocupe a fila de requisições que são processadas pelo servidor, até que o método chamado com `await` termine, e finalmente retorne um resultado.

Isso foi feito porque cada vez que uma ação não síncrona é chamada, ela ocupa uma thread das que estão disponíveis para processar os requests, sendo que existe um limite a quantidade de threads que fazem esse trabalho. Usando `async`, a thread de processamento de request é liberada para processar outros requests, enquando que uma chamada feita com `await` cuida do processamento do request feito anteriormente em outro plano.

Isso só é realmente útil, para ações que fazem chamadas de I/O, como acesso a bancos de dados, requests à servidores externos, gravações no disco rígido, entre outras tarefas que podem ser feitas assíncronamente.

**Referências**

MSDN: [Usando um controlador assíncrono em ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ee728598%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Nesse tópico da MSDN, tem uma imagem bem explicativa do que acontece, basicamente tudo o que vem depois da chamada usando `await` na ação assíncrona, é transferida para outra thread, que não a do pool que atende requests, deixando-o, portanto, livre para atender outros requests.

[image: Imagem da MSDN mostrando as threads A) do pool que atende requests B) outra thread]

Este [blog](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4), em inglês, explica exatamente as chamadas de ações assíncronas, usando `async` e por que o seu uso faz com que o servidor seja capaz de atender mais requests simultaneamente.

Answer (score 7):

Antes demais, recomendo ler este blog (em ingles) do Stephen Cleary: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

Posto de um modo simples:

A partir de .NET 4.0, é possível encapsular uma tarefa (que pode correr numa outra *thread* de modo assíncrono ou não) numa classe `Task` ou `Task<T>`.

Neste caso, o método [`CreateAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn468057%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) retorna uma `Task<IdentityResult>` que, nesse momento, pode encontrar-se concluída ou não. A *keyword* `await` faz com que:

1. (Caso a Task não esteja concluida) A *thread* actual fique livre para executar outras tarefas, até que a Task conclua. Assim que estiver concluída, o resultado `IdentityResult` sera colocado na variável `result`.
2. (Caso a Task ja tenha concluido) o resultado `IdentityResult` seja colocado na variável `result`.

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com [a documentação oficial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx), essa palavra chave suspende a execução de um método chamado de forma assíncrona, até que determinada tarefa seja concluída. O texto no link é mais aprofundado. Segue também [o link para a tradução para português](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh156528.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Por este [artigo da MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx), e pelo meu entendimento, o `await` serve para o metodo, que contenha uma tarefa assincrona, espere pelo final da execução da tarefa e termine de executar seu código.

Answer (score 0):

A palavra await é uma nova sintaxe para a utilização de métodos assíncronos. Deve ser colocada antes de cada método assíncrono e o método onde nós estamos deve sempre ter o identificador async antes do tipo que temos que devolver.

Estes métodos devem sempre devolver void ou Task. Para mais informações consulte o seguinte link.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx