# ASP.NET MVC5 - Métodos Assíncronos no Controller

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-mvc-5, async

Estou desenvolvendo uma camada MVC pra um sistema ASP.NET escrito inicialmente em WebForms. Ele não usa EntityFramework, então uma boa parte do sistema eu tive que elaborar uma solução caseira.

Pra eu poder usar os métodos assíncronos do Ajax com os Controllers do MVC5, escrevi como exemplo o seguinte método:

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<JsonResult> IndexAsync()
{
    var pessoas = new Pessoas(GeneralSettings.DataBaseConnection)
        .Selecionar()
        .Select(p => new { NOME = p.Nome, CPF = p.Cpf, FONE = p.TelefoneResidencial, CELULAR = p.TelefoneCelular, DEPARTAMENTO = "Teste", EMAIL = p.Email })
        .Take(10);
    return Json(pessoas, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Este método não é assíncrono porque `return Json(...` executa de modo síncrono. A seguinte mensagem aparece:

> This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

Como devo alterar o método para que a execução seja assíncrona?

**EDIT**

O @dcastro pediu o método `Selecionar()`, que está reproduzido abaixo:

```
public override IEnumerable<Pessoa> Selecionar(IEnumerable<Operador> operadores)
{
    using (var obj = new Database())
    {
        var sSql =
            "select p.ID_PESSOA, p.NOME_COMPLETO, p.APELIDO, p.EMAIL_PESSOAL, p.NOME_PAI, p.NOME_MAE, p.SEXO, p.CPF, p.RG, p.ORGAO_RG, " +
            " p.EMISSAO_RG, p.DATA_NASC, p.LOCAL_NASC, p.ENDERECO, p.NUMERO, p.COMPLEMENTO, p.BAIRRO, p.CIDADE, p.ESTADO, p.DDD_FONE_RES, " +
            " p.FONE_RES, p.DDD_FONE_CEL, p.CELULAR, p.ID_BANCO_TALENTOS, p.ESTADO_CIVIL, p.ID_NACIONALIDADE, p.DEFICIENTE, p.TAMANHO_SAPATO, " +
            " p.TAMANHO_CAMISETA, p.ALERGIA, p.NOME_CONJUGE, p.DDD_TEL_EMERGENCIA, p.TEL_EMERGENCIA, p.DDD_CEL_EMERGENCIA, p.CEL_EMERGENCIA, " +
            " p.CONTATO_EMERGENCIA, p.ID_FORMACAO_ACADEMICA, p.PARENTESCO, p.FOTO_PESSOA, p.RI, p.TITULO_ELEITOR, p.ZONA, p.SECAO, " +
            " p.CART_TRABALHO, p.SERIE, p.PIS, p.CPF_CONJUGE, p.LINKEDIN, p.FACEBOOK, p.TWITTER, p.ID_ETNIA, p.CEP " +
            " from PESSOAS p ";

        foreach (var operador in operadores)
        {
            sSql += WhereOuAnd + " p." + operador;
        }

        var parametros = operadores.Where(o => o.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Igual))).Select(o2 => ((Igual)o2).ParametroOracle).ToList();
        var dataTable = obj.ConsultarSQl(ConexaoBancoDados, sSql, parametros);

        foreach (DataRow linha in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            yield return new Pessoa
            {
                PessoaId = Convert.ToInt32(linha["ID_PESSOA"].ToString()),
                Nome = linha["NOME_COMPLETO"].ToString(),
                Apelido = linha["APELIDO"].ToString(),
                Email = linha["EMAIL_PESSOAL"].ToString(),
                NomePai = linha["NOME_PAI"].ToString(),
                NomeMae = linha["NOME_MAE"].ToString(),
                Sexo = linha["SEXO"].ToString(),
                Cpf = linha["CPF"].ToString(),
                Rg = linha["RG"].ToString(),
                OrgaoEmissorRg = linha["ORGAO_RG"].ToString(),
                DataEmissaoRg = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(linha["EMISSAO_RG"].ToString())) ? Convert.ToDateTime(linha["EMISSAO_RG"].ToString()) : DateTime.MinValue,
                Nascimento = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(linha["DATA_NASC"].ToString())) ? Convert.ToDateTime(linha["DATA_NASC"].ToString()) : DateTime.MinValue,
                LocalNascimento = linha["LOCAL_NASC"].ToString(),
                Endereco = linha["ENDERECO"].ToString(),
                Numero = linha["NUMERO"].ToString(),
                Complemento = linha["COMPLEMENTO"].ToString(),
                Bairro = linha["BAIRRO"].ToString(),
                Cidade = linha["CIDADE"].ToString(),
                Estado = linha["ESTADO"].ToString(),
                DddTelefoneResidencial = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(linha["DDD_FONE_RES"].ToString())) ? Convert.ToInt32(linha["DDD_FONE_RES"].ToString()) : Int32.MinValue,
                TelefoneResidencial = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(linha["FONE_RES"].ToString())) ? Convert.ToInt32(linha["FONE_RES"].ToString()) : Int32.MinValue,
                DddCelular = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(linha["DDD_FONE_CEL"].ToString())) ? Convert.ToInt32(linha["DDD_FONE_CEL"].ToString()) : Int32.MinValue,
                TelefoneCelular = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(linha["CELULAR"].ToString())) ? Convert.ToInt32(linha["CELULAR"].ToString()) : Int32.MinValue,
                BancoTalentosId = linha["ID_BANCO_TALENTOS"].ToString(),
                EstadoCivil = linha["ESTADO_CIVIL"].ToString(),
                NacionalidadeId = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(linha["ID_NACIONALIDADE"].ToString())) ? Convert.ToInt32(linha["ID_NACIONALIDADE"].ToString()) : Int32.MinValue,
                Deficiente = linha["DEFICIENTE"].ToString(),
                TamanhoSapato = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(linha["TAMANHO_SAPATO"].ToString())) ? Convert.ToInt32(linha["TAMANHO_SAPATO"].ToString()) : Int32.MinValue,
                TamanhoCamiseta = linha["TAMANHO_CAMISETA"].ToString(),
                Alergia = linha["ALERGIA"].ToString(),
                NomeConjuge = linha["NOME_CONJUGE"].ToString(),
                DddTelefoneEmergencia = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(linha["DDD_TEL_EMERGENCIA"].ToString())) ? Convert.ToInt32(linha["DDD_TEL_EMERGENCIA"].ToString()) : Int32.MinValue,
                TelefoneEmergencia = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(linha["TEL_EMERGENCIA"].ToString())) ? Convert.ToInt32(linha["TEL_EMERGENCIA"].ToString()) : Int32.MinValue,
                DddCelularEmergencia = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(linha["DDD_CEL_EMERGENCIA"].ToString())) ? Convert.ToInt32(linha["DDD_CEL_EMERGENCIA"].ToString()) : Int32.MinValue,
                CelularEmergencia = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(linha["CEL_EMERGENCIA"].ToString())) ? Convert.ToInt32(linha["CEL_EMERGENCIA"].ToString()) : Int32.MinValue,
                ContatoEmergencia = linha["CONTATO_EMERGENCIA"].ToString(),
                FormacaoAcademicaId = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(linha["ID_FORMACAO_ACADEMICA"].ToString())) ? Convert.ToInt32(linha["ID_FORMACAO_ACADEMICA"].ToString()) : Int32.MinValue,
                Parentesco = linha["PARENTESCO"].ToString(),
                FotoPessoa = (linha["FOTO_PESSOA"].ToString() != "") ? (Byte[])linha["FOTO_PESSOA"] : new byte[0],
                RI = linha["RI"].ToString(),
                TituloEleitor = linha["TITULO_ELEITOR"].ToString(),
                Zona = linha["ZONA"].ToString(),
                Secao = linha["SECAO"].ToString(),
                CarteiraTrabalho = linha["SECAO"].ToString(),
                Serie = linha["SECAO"].ToString(),
                Pis = linha["PIS"].ToString(),
                CpfConjuge = linha["CPF_CONJUGE"].ToString(),
                Linkedin = linha["LINKEDIN"].ToString(),
                Facebook = linha["FACEBOOK"].ToString(),
                Twitter = linha["TWITTER"].ToString(),
                EtniaId = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(linha["ID_ETNIA"].ToString())) ? Convert.ToInt32(linha["ID_ETNIA"].ToString()) : Int32.MinValue,
                Cep = linha["CEP"].ToString()
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Método `ConsultarSql` (eu não escrevi este código. Ele faz parte do esquema de acesso a dados que já existia):

```
/// <summary>
/// Método utilizado para a execução de pesquisas no banco de dados com o envio de uma coleção de parametros.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="pStringConexao">String de conexão com o banco de dados.</param>
/// <param name="pSQL">Enviar o comando SQL que será executado.</param>
/// <param name="pParams">Coleção de parametros esperados no comeando SQL.</param>
/// <returns>Retorna um DataTable com o resultado da pesquisa.</returns>
public DataTable ConsultarSQl(string pStringConexao, string pSQL, List<OracleParameter> pParams)
{
    #region Abre a Conexão

    OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection();

    try
    {
        cn = GetConnection(pStringConexao);
        cn.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        cn.Dispose();
        throw ex;
}

    #endregion

    OracleCommand dbCommand = new OracleCommand(pSQL, cn);
    dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    foreach (OracleParameter param in pParams)
    {
        if (param.Value != null)
        dbCommand.Parameters.Add(param);
        }

    OracleDataAdapter oAdp = new OracleDataAdapter(dbCommand);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    try
    {
        oAdp.Fill(ds);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            cn.Close();
        }

        dbCommand.Dispose();
        cn.Dispose();
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            cn.Close();
        }

        dbCommand.Dispose();
        cn.Dispose();
    }

    return ds.Tables[0];
}
```

Se houver necessidade de colocar mais códigos, só pedir via comentários.

Comment: Qual e' a API que estas a usar para selecionar as pessoas da base de dados? Podes mostrar a linha de codigo que faz a chamada?

Comment: Esta é a linha: `var pessoas = new Pessoas(GeneralSettings.DataBaseConnection)
        .Selecionar()
        .Select(p => new { NOME = p.Nome, CPF = p.Cpf, FONE = p.TelefoneResidencial, CELULAR = p.TelefoneCelular, DEPARTAMENTO = "Teste", EMAIL = p.Email })
        .Take(10);`. Este método `Selecionar` faz o acesso ao banco.

Comment: Sim, mas qual e' o codigo dentro de `.Selecionar()`? Esse codigo pode chamar outros metodos, e esses podem chamar outros metodos, etc, mas eu preciso de saber qual e' a linha de codigo que efectivamente comunica directamente com a API da base de dados. E qual a biblioteca que esta' a ser usada para isso.

Comment: @dcastro Editei a pergunta explicitando o método `Selecionar()`.

Comment: Essa ainda nao e' a camada mais baixa do sistema :/ Esse codigo chamada `ConsultarSQl()` num objecto do tipo `Database`... Nao sabes qual e' a tecnologia que esta a ser usada? Disseste que *nao* e' Entity Framework, entao qual e'? ADO.NET? Sqlite-net? Peco desculpa se a minha pergunta nao foi clara.

Comment: Eu que peço desculpas. Vou editar novamente.

Comment: @dcastro Veja agora.

Comment: Estas a usar o [`OracleClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.OracleClient(v=vs.110).aspx), so' precisava de saber isso :) Agora estou ocupado, mas mais logo eu respondo a pergunta. Spoiler: vai ser preciso mudar muito codigo para deixar tudo assincrono :/

Comment: Não tem problema: Ganha o joia e mudo o accept se a resposta contemplar tudo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que a execução assíncrona fica mais interessante na parte de chamada de dados do banco:

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<JsonResult> IndexAsync()
{
    var pessoas = await Task.Run(() => new Pessoas(GeneralSettings.DataBaseConnection)
        .Selecionar()
        .Select(p => new { NOME = p.Nome, CPF = p.Cpf, FONE = p.TelefoneResidencial, CELULAR = p.TelefoneCelular, DEPARTAMENTO = "Teste", EMAIL = p.Email })
        .Take(10));

    return Json(pessoas, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

O problema é o seguinte: Um método `async` **deve** esperar a resposta de alguma ação em algum ponto. Mas o compilador não saberá aonde esperar por conta própria, ele esperará quando achar `await`. E, para "converter" uma execução síncrona para assíncrona, você usa uma `Task`.

Comment: [Referência](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2798/1589)

Comment: Na verdade, usar `Task.Run` neste caso nao vai trazer beneficio nenhum, so vai degradar a performance. Esse codigo liberta a thread actual, e encarrega uma thread da `ThreadPool` de executar a query. Por outras palavras - libertar uma thread e ocupar outra thread, nao traz vantagens - so adiciona o overhead de 2 mudancas de contexto.

Comment: @dcastro Fiquei interessado no seu comentário (afinal, não sou nenhum expert em `async` e me interesso em aprender). Se minha resposta está errada (mesmo que parcialmente), porque não postas uma versão correta? Terás meu upvote, e certamente tua resposta será aceita.

Comment: Sim, eu vou postar uma resposta, mas primeiro preciso que o OP responda ao meu contario, para saber se a biblioteca que ele esta a usar suporta chamadas asyncronas nativas :)

Comment: @dcastro Pelo que entendi, ele está portando um código Web Forms legado para MVC 5. Acho que ele está disposto a converter o código legado para assíncrono. (Pelo que eu conheço o OP pelo chat, eu sei que ele entra no SO um pouco tarde)

Comment: Sim, mas qual e' a biblioteca que ele usa para aceder a base de dados? Actualmente, quase todas expoem metodos asincronos, mas e' melhor verificar.. Assim posso dar uma resposta mais informada.

Comment: @dcastro: Ao usar `await` neste caso, não ocorre uma símples troca de threads. Será a troca de uma thread do pool do IIS (threads que atendem requisições), por uma do pool de threads do .Net (threads genéricas).

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Mas o IIS usa a ThreadPool do CLR, que e' a mesma ThreadPool que o `Task.Run` usa.

Comment: @dcastro: No modo integrado, a origem das threads é a mesma, entretanto o IIS possui um limite de threads que irá usar para atender requisições... mas isso não importa, pois pelo visto o limite padrão é de 5000 threads! =)

Comment: Referência: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee377050.aspx

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Leia essa pergunta/resposta: [Operacoes async em ASP.NET](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7760/2360) e principalmente os 2 primeiros links no fundo da resposta.

Comment: @dcastro Eu acabei de ler... muito interessante.

Answer (score 2):

Se o seu método não faz de fato nenhuma operação assíncrona, não faz sentido ter a KeyWord async.

E métodos assíncronos devem ser precedidos da keyword await para que sejam executados e aguardados, liberando a thread corrente enquanto isso.

> Código original

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<JsonResult> IndexAsync()
{
    var pessoas = new Pessoas(GeneralSettings.DataBaseConnection)
        .Selecionar()
        .Select(p => new { NOME = p.Nome, CPF = p.Cpf, FONE = p.TelefoneResidencial, CELULAR = p.TelefoneCelular, DEPARTAMENTO = "Teste", EMAIL = p.Email })
        .Take(10);

    return Json(pessoas, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

> Código ideal
>
> Partindo do princípio que o método Selecionar é assíncrono (o que só faz sentido se internamente ele faz I/O de rede ou fileSystem de forma assíncrona também).

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<JsonResult> IndexAsync()
{
    var model = new Pessoas(GeneralSettings.DataBaseConnection);
    var pessoas = await model.Selecionar();
    var result = pessoas
        .Select(p => new { NOME = p.Nome, CPF = p.Cpf, FONE = p.TelefoneResidencial, CELULAR = p.TelefoneCelular, DEPARTAMENTO = "Teste", EMAIL = p.Email })
        .Take(10);

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

OBS.:

> Não é recomendado acesso **direto** a um banco de dados relacional de forma assíncrona.

Comment: Dentro do método `Selecionar()` eu tenho algumas operações adicionais, então o acesso não é direto. Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Esse seu método Selecionar é assíncrono e retorna uma Task<T>?
Se não for, o posicionamento do Task.Run também não resolve muita coisa.
Se for, o método assíncrono deve receber a keyword await, do contrário você vai tentar chamar um extensionMethod de IEnumerable<T> em uma Task, o que não faz sentido e não funciona.

Comment: Bom, agora é só editar os demais métodos para que a chamada interna também seja assíncrona. Obrigado mais uma vez.

Answer (score 2):

Para perceber porque e' que nao devem ser criadas novas threads ou usar a ThreadPool (com `Task.Run` por exemplo), veja esta pergunta:
[Operacoes async em ASP.NET](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7760/2360). (Achei esta explicacao demasiado complexa, entao criei uma pergunta propria).

### Problemas

Problema #1: o `System.Data.OracleClient` da Microsoft foi deprecado - [a Microsoft recomenda o uso de outras bibliotecas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7(v=vs.110).aspx).

> The types in System.Data.OracleClient are deprecated. The types remain supported in the current version of.NET Framework but will be removed in a future release. Microsoft recommends that you use a third-party Oracle provider.

Como alternativa, a propria Oracle disponibiliza a biblioteca [ODP.NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) (Oracle Data Provider). E e' aqui que surge o...

Problema #2: a biblioteca ODP.NET nao suporta chamadas assincronas! (ver discussao: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1043399).

### Solucoes

Neste caso, tens 3 solucoes possiveis:

1. (Nao recomendado) Continuar a usar o `OracleClient` da Microsoft, apesar de nao ser aconselhado pela Microsoft.
2. Migrar para o ODP.NET e usar chamadas sincronas.
3. Migrar para Sql Server, e usar bibliotecas *actualizadas* e com suporte para chamadas *verdadeiramente assincronas*.

A solucao 3 envolve uma mudanca muito grande na arquitectura do sistema e na infra-estrutura em geral.

Na maior parte dos projecto, a equipa tenta evitar mudancas desta dimensao. Mas, ainda assim, considere expor a situacao aos outros membros da equipa, e ao gestor do projecto.
As' vezes e' preferivel fazer uma mudanca grande hoje, do que uma mudanca ainda maior amanha ;)

Alem disso, os beneficios de fazer chamadas assincronas a' base de dados sao *muito* tentadores. Este e' um aspecto critico para se conseguir uma aplicacao web escalavel e com alto rendimento.

No caso de isto nao ser possivel, recomendo pelo menos migrar para ODP.NET (solucao #2). Todo o processo tem de ser sincrono (sem Tasks, nem await), mas pelo menos vais usar bibliotecas actualizadas e com melhor suporte.
A migracao deve ser relativamente facil, a API e' muito parecida (ou igual) com a API do `OracleClient`.

API do ODP.NET: http://docs.oracle.com/html/A96160_01/intro.htm#1007745

Comment: Sua resposta é ótima, mas infelizmente não posso sair da topologia do Oracle. Se eu pudesse, possivelmente estaria usando direto o `EntityFramework`, e não essa solução caseira de baixa qualidade. Agradeço!

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez De nada :) Espero que ao menos possa passar a usar a biblioteca oficial da Oracle, sempre deve ajudar um bocado :)