# Operacoes async em ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, multithreading, async

Em que situações é vantajoso usar operações assíncronas numa aplicação **ASP.NET** (clássico, MVC, MVC Web API)?

Quando é que o uso da `ThreadPool` para executar algumas operações pode ser útil?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Async na Web

HTTP é um protocolo *fundamentalmente* síncrono. O cliente envia um pedido -> o servidor processa o pedido -> o servidor envia uma resposta -> o cliente recebe a resposta.

O objectivo ao desenvolver uma aplicação web em ASP.NET (clássico, MVC, MVC Web API) é tentar processar o pedido numa só thread. Quantos mais mudanças de thread houver, pior será a performance - sempre que se muda de thread, o CPU tem de guardar o estado actual duma thread (stack, program counter, etc), e recuperar o estado da outra thread. Este processo chama-se "context switch" e é um processo caro e pesado. É tempo que o processador gasta sem efectuar trabalho útil.

Por exemplo, imagine o codigo:

```
ProcessamentoInicial();
await Task.Run(AlgoritmoIntensivo);
ProcessamentoFinal();
```

1. Com o `await`, estamos a libertar a thread do pedido HTTP (`thread A`), e a executar o algoritmo numa thread da ThreadPool (`thread B`).
2. Enquanto `B` estiver ocupada, a `thread A` fica livre para efectuar outro trabalho (servir outros pedidos que cheguem ao servidor, algum trabalho pendente na ThreadPool, etc)
3. Quando a `thread B` completar, o processamento final vai ser agendado para executar na `thread A` novamente, e enviar a resposta ao cliente.

Sem `await Task.Run`, o código ficaria assim:

```
ProcessamentoInicial();
AlgoritmoIntensivo(); //bloqueante
ProcessamentoFinal();
```

Neste caso, todo o código corre de modo síncrono, na mesma thread.

Vamos visualizar o comportamento destas 2 soluções, quando temos 2 threads (`X` e `Y`) a servir 2 pedidos (`R1` e `R2`) que chegam ao servidor simultaneamente.

[image: Diagrama de processamento CPU-bound síncrono]

Como podemos ver, na versão assíncrona, a thread `X` deferiu a execução do algoritmo para a thread `Y`, e a thread `Y` deferiu para a thread `X`. Isto acontece porque ASP.NET e `Task.Run` usam a mesma ThreadPool. Então, as threads interferem umas com as outras.

Devido ao *overhead* introduzido pelas mudanças de contexto, a versão "assíncrona" teve pior performance.
Os dois pedidos são servidos mais rapidamente se processarmos tudo de modo síncrono.

Desvantagens da versão "assíncrona":

1. "Context switches" desnecessários
2. Lixo desnecessário (devido ao uso do idioma async/await, o compilador gera uma máquina de estados para gerir a task)
3. O algoritmo usado pelo ASP.NET destabiliza momentaneamente (porque `Task.Run` pediu uma thread emprestada "inesperadamente"). Este algoritmo calcula constantemente o rendimento do servidor e faz pequenas optimizações de modo a aumentar este rendimento. Interferir com este algoritmo é.... indesejado.
4. Se o cliente desconectar, o servidor nao poderá abortar o processamento do pedido, porque quebramos o fluxo síncrono.

### Async I/O

Porém, existe uma excepção! Ao contrário de operações *CPU-bound* (operações dependentes de trabalho de CPU, como cálculos matemáticos, loops intensivos, etc), as operações *I/O-bound* (operações que dependem de comunicação externa, como chamadas a bases de dados, a web services, leitura de ficheiros em disco, etc) **devem** ser assíncronas!

Ao contrario do exemplo anterior, quando se usa I/O assíncrona, nenhuma das threads fica bloqueada. Em vez disso, as threads do processo ficam livres, e quando a operação I/O tiver completado, a "I/O completion port" recebe um sinal `interrupt` vinda do hardware I/O. Pode-se pensar numa I/O completion port como uma thread *lightweight* dedicada apenas a I/O, e a nada mais.

Vejamos:

```
ProcessamentoInicial();
await BD.ExecutarQueryAsync(); 
ProcessamentoFinal();
```

[image: Diagrama de I/O assíncrona]

Agora, como ambas as threads deferem a execução para as completion ports, não interferem uma com a outra - ambas ficam verdadeiramente livres para processar outros pedidos, aumentando o rendimento e a escalabilidade do servidor.

Mas async I/O não é algo que possa ser simulado em C#.

`await Task.Run(() => DB.ExecutarQueryBloqueante());` terá as mesmas desvantagens que o primeiro exemplo, em que se utilizou `Task.Run` para correr o algoritmo. Este é um erro comum.

Async I/O tem que ser suportado pelas drivers nativas no caso das bases de dados, ou pelo sistema operativo no caso de leitura de ficheiros em disco. Estas APIs devem expor métodos não bloqueantes (ex: [`DbCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh223695(v=vs.110).aspx), [`StreamReader.ReadAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readasync(v=vs.110).aspx)). Estas APIs usam I/O completion ports, em vez de threads.

### tl;dr

1. Em ASP.NET, todos o trabalho *cpu-bound* deve ser processado de modo síncrono, sem criar novas threads nem deferir para a ThreadPool.
2. Para operações I/O, deve ser usada a API assíncrona (não-bloqueante), caso exista.

Referencias:

- [Stephen Cleary - Task.Run Etiquette Examples: Don't Use Task.Run in the Implementation](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html)
- [Using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem in ASP.NET in a high traffic scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2642789/857807)
- [ASP.NET MVC what threadpool is used for custom tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19695206/857807)

Comment: +1 bela explicação... entretanto existem casos em que faz sentido com processamento CPU bound também. Adicionei uma resposta para cobrir esse caso.

Answer (score 9):

Uma utilidade que vejo para operações CPU bound, seria a execução de múltiplos processamentos em processadores distintos, com um `await` no código assim:

```
var tasks = PegarMultiplasTarefas();
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Isso foge ao apresentado pelo @dcastro, mas é um ponto válido também, sem necessariamente se tratar de I/O.

Fazendo isso se distribui processamentos independentes entre si, entre os processadores disponíveis. Entretanto, há de se fazer uma consideração sobre se isso é realmente desejável, afinal, uma vez que esse processadores vão ficar ocupados, terão sua capacidade de atender requisições reduzida.

Isso é um problema no caso de o seu sistema atender a vários tipos de requisições, tanto de processamento leve como de processamento mais intenso. Se todos os processadores ficarem ocupados, então outras requisições mais curtas, que seriam prontamente atendidas, serão executadas mais lentamente pois estarão dividindo o tempo de processamento com outras threads.

Já se o sistema visa atender requisições de processamento mais intenso, então vale a pena dividir o processamento de cada request entre os processadores se possível. Isso acontece pelo seguinte: num sistema de 4 processadores, se um request de processamento linear fosse demorar 4s, e fosse possível dividir esse processamento nos 4 processadores, de forma que no final ficasse com 1s... então em 4s seria possível atender 4 requests... uma teria resposta tempo `t=1s`, outra no tempo `t=2s`, no `t=3s` e outra no `t=4s`. Já se o processamento do request não for distribuido entre as threads, seria possível atender 4 ao mesmo tempo, sendo que todas seriam respondidas em `t=4s` o que neste caso é uma desvantagem.

Comment: Esqueci-me de incluir esse caso, mas aplica-se a mesma logica. As threads ocupadas por essas tasks podiam estar a ser usadas para servir outros pedidos. Ou seja, troca-se escalabilidade (quantidade de clientes que conseguimos servir por minuto) por performance (tempo necessario para servir um cliente). A performance pode ser util quando ha pouco trafego no servidor, mas em situacoes de alto trafego a escalabilidade e' mais importante. Veja o comentario do Brad Wilson no fundo deste post: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx

Comment: Concordo com você parcialmente. Escalabilidade pode ser obtida adicionando-se mais máquinas (um farm), e performance também pode ser obtida com mais máquinas (delegar a tarefa difícil de processar a um servidor dedicado). Neste caso, não há troca de escalabilidade por performance, há apenas uma forma diferente de organizar os processamentos.

Comment: Tambem concordo parcialmente :P A minha logica aplica-se a cada maquina individualmente. Acho que as duas logicas encaixam uma na outra - ao adicionar mais maquinas, como numa web farm, estamos a baixar o trafego em cada maquina individual - logo, estamos a baixar os recursos utilizados. Nesse caso, faz sentido usar os recursos em excesso para melhorar a performance de cada request.

Comment: Se adicionar esse trade-off a' resposta, e os pros e contras, dou +1 tambem ;)

Comment: É altamente discutível que o trabalho a realizar para servir um pedido HTTP seja trabalho de CPU paralelizável. Faze-lo poderá ser a solução certa para o problema errado. Dadas as ressalvas, é uma ferramenta a ter na caixa de ferramentas de cada um, mas nada que deva ser feito logo de início, pelo sim - pelo não.