# Quais os prós e contras da implementação Task<List<Object>> sobre List<Object>

Tags: c#, .net, async, assincronismo, task

Quais as vantagens entre as duas implementações abaixo. Ambas retornam uma lista com vários produtos (mais de 1k):

```
public Task<List<Product>> GetAllProductsAsync()
{
    var query = Products.ToList();

    return Task.FromResult(query);
}
```

**X**

```
public List<Product> GetAllProducts()
{
    var query = Products.ToList();

    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A primeira está preparada para fazer isto de forma assíncrona, ou seja, o código começa fazer e continua "sua vida" normal independente da execução desta *query* e quando ela terminar o código será avisado disto.

No passado isso era complicado de fazer em C#, embora viável. Com o C# 5 ficou bem mais fácil porque o compilador monta a máquina de estados que controla este fluxo. E a classe `Task` ajuda nisto controlando inclusive se isto rodará em *thread* separada ou não. Embora na forma atual não está próprio para aplicar a assincronicidade já que falta o modificador [`async`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) no método.

Quando você deseja executar a tarefa de forma assíncrona, deve fazer através de uma classe que represente uma tarefa, ou seja, uma [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0). Então você receberá uma tarefa que conterá o resultado no momento adequado, em vez de resultado puro.

Obviamente a execução assíncrona tem a vantagem de não bloquear a aplicação. Se demorar para gerar esta lista a aplicação continuará executando normal e retomará aí quando a lista estiver gerada. O segundo método bloqueará a execução até que a lista termine de ser gerada.

O tamanho não é importante e sim o tempo que demorará para executar a tarefa. Costuma-se dizer que se a tarefa levar menos de 50ms é melhor executar de forma síncrona mesmo, afinal a assicronicidade tem seu custo.

**Salvo o caso da tarefa ser muito rápida** eu só vejo vantagens em usar a forma assíncrona. Claro que o código fica ligeiramente mais complexo, mas é coisa mínima. O que pode atrapalhar de fato é se precisar depurar. Mas o ideal é fazer funcionar bem de forma síncrona primeiro, isto evita um pouco do problema. Claro que se tiver problemas para depurar o processo de assincronicidade, tá lascado mesmo. Mas melhorou com o Visual Studio 2015. Depurar tarefas assíncronas pode ser mais trabalhoso e confuso em certas circunstâncias.

Eventualmente o uso do [`ToListAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.tolistasync?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=entity-framework-6.2.0#overloads) pode ser interessante aí. Mas depende de como este método será usado e o que este `ToList()` atual está fazendo. É só uma suposição.

Para saber mais sobre o recurso veja [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2793/101). Eu dei uma resposta lá que ilustra bem o funcionamento. Tem outras respostas com abordagens diferentes que vão lhe ajudar a assincronicidade. Outra [pergunta muito boa com foco mais no ASP.NET](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7760/101) pode ser vista aqui.

A título de curiosidade, não sei se foi só exemplo, mas a variável é totalmente desnecessária neste método.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Me tire um dúvida, o app volta a ser responsivo somente após `return Task.FromResult(query);` ou assim que chamo `Task<List<Product>> GetAllProductsAsync()` ?