# Console, Windows Forms ou MVC qual o mais rápido para cargas pesada?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, winforms, desempenho

Estou desenvolvendo um programa que terá basicamente o seguinte ciclo:

- Consulta na base de dados(alguns milissegundos)
- Para cada registro executará o seguinte processo:

> ```
> Início
> |
> Parse de um XML web (alguns milisegundos pra executar)
> |
> Download de imagens da web (5 imagens, alguns segundos)
> |
> Gravação no banco de dados (alguns milisegundos)
> |
> Fim
> ```

Ainda estou esperando a resposta do [Qual a diferença entre os async, multithereading, paralelismo e concorrência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/157435/multithreading-async-paralelismo) para saber algumas diferenças entre processos assincronos.

Mas em qual plataforma rodaria mais rápido? imaginando que em todos teriam um layout simples, focado no desempenho, para rodar milhares de vezes ao dia.

Penso que o Console seria a melhor forma, pois ele é rodado direto na máquina, diferente do MVC que roda através de uma camada intermediaria que seria o IIS.

Porém existe algo que o ASP.NET tem pra ajudar?

OBS: O software não precisa de interação humana, não precisará de cliques, nada.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se for um programa totalmente sem interface pode criar um projeto Windows Forms, remover o Form criado (`Form1.cs`) e alterar `Program.cs`, para ficar assim:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    }
}
```

E finalmente remover todas as referências, e adicionar novamente a medida do necessário.

Assim o programa fica bem minimalista e sem UI.
Acho que essa é a forma de ter o mínimo de overhead.

Comment: mas ele praticamente ficaria um Console né? então creio que o Console ainda seja a melhor opção.

Comment: Não seria possível acessar nada do console. Além disso, ao executar, um console não seria criado. Assim sendo, o overhead é menor do que um executável que usa console.

Comment: Legal, esse comentário vale está na resposta, abs

Answer (score 5):

Não faz diferença porque o processamento nada tem a ver com a interface com usuário.

Fica até difícil comparar performance deles porque a interface não deve ser escolhida por qual é mais rápida, mas sim qual atende a necessidade do usuário. Certamente console é mais rápido, mas se a pessoa precisar acessar de qualquer lugar, não pode instalar nada, tem que ser algo de acesso espontâneo, é claro que ASP.NET resolve melhor. Assim como se o usuário não consegue ou não acha conveniente ficar digitando coisas e precisa de uma interface gráfica, o Windows Forms será mais adequado. Tudo entre as opções oferecidas.

Se a aplicação for bem feita, o processamento é tão isolado da interface que não importa nada e ela pode ser facilmente trocada se necessário.

Se a interface estiver atrapalhando o desempenho do processamento dos dados tem algo muito errado na aplicação.

Comment: no caso não terá interface, por isso console logo funcionará...
Mas na via das dúvidas vou de Console.

Comment: Console é uma interface.

Comment: interface quis dizer no sentido de botões, inputs, etc.. mas ok..

Comment: Aí está falando de interface gráfica.

Answer (score 2):

Nesse caso não há o mais rápido e sim como o processamento será feito. Como não haverá interação humana, use console.

Como é um processo que vai se repetir diversas vezes, acredito que em um intervalo de tempo, a interação com o banco de dados (leitura/gravação) deve ser o mais reduzido possível, resumindo, a cada interação trás tudo, processa e grava tudo, de uma só vez, não faça registo a registro e muito menos dentro de laços de repetição, evitando assim vários acessos ao banco de dados. Prepara a entidade a ser persistida e grave no banco tudo de uma só vez. Utilize entity framework.

Comment: para fins academicos vou tentar migrar a aplicação console pra MVC, porém creio que o IIS + System.Web sejam intermediários que afetem bem o desempenho, valeu pela dica.