# Parallel vs Tasks vs Threads

Tags: c#, .net

Eu estava fazendo um ConsoleAPP e fiquei com uma duvida, qual a grande diferença de cada um desses e quais as vantagens e desvantagens? Em qual caso eu usaria Parallel, em qual caso eu usaria Tasks e qual caso eu usaria Threads.

Pra vocês entenderem melhor, eu estou com o seguinte problema, eu preciso iniciar 4 tarefas simultâneas para fazer validações separadas (aliás, o código já está funcionando, porém quero saber qual seria a melhor implementação)

Meu código está assim:

```
foreach (var lista in listas)
{
    ValidationBSS bss = new ValidationBSS(instanceId, id);
    tasks[listas.IndexOf(lista)] = (Task.Factory.StartNew(() => bss.Validation(lista)));
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks);

Parallel.ForEach(listas, obj => 
{
    ValidationBSS bss = new ValidationBSS(instanceId, id);
    bss.Validation(obj);
} );
```

Comment: Veja se isto responde: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123173/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157435/101.

Comment: @bigown respondeu e me ajudou bastante, obrigado!