# Transformar método síncrono em assíncrono

Tags: c#, assincronismo, task

Tenho o seguinte método:

```
public string MyMethod1(string myParam1) {
    // Implementação
    return myReturnValue;
}
```

Eu precisava criar um método assíncrono que fazia a mesma coisa, para processar vários itens de uma lista ao mesmo tempo, então criei um segundo método da seguinte forma:

```
public async Task<string> MyMethod1Async(string myParam1) {
    return MyMethod1(myParam1);
}
```

O Visual Studio reclamou por eu não estar usando o operador `await` em um metodo assíncrono. Mas basicamente estou reaproveitando o método que já existia e criando uma alternativa assíncrona que chamo da seguinte forma:

```
var myResult = Task.WhenAll(myStringList.Select(myStringItem => MyMethod1Async(myStringItem)).Result;
```

> Usei uma `string` para o parâmetro apenas como exemplo simplificado.
>
> **O método síncrono deverá continuar existindo da mesma forma.**

**1.** Dessa forma os objetos da lista de fato estarão sendo processados ao
    mesmo tempo?

**2.** Existe alguma forma mais apropriada para implementar um método
    assíncrono nesse contexto?

Comment: Já deu uma olhada em `Task.FromResult<>` já vai solucionar o seu problema imediato, não sei se tem algo a mais, mas, isso acredito que resolveria

Comment: Não conhecia não @VirgilioNovic , mas vou dar uma olhada aqui agora mesmo. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

1. **Sim**, é possível ter um método síncrono em um processo assíncrono. O que vai acontecer? Será criado várias Task e cada task rodará um processo síncrono.

**OBS**: As vezes não existe ganho de perfomance em um ambiente assim, o importante em um processo async é isola-lo de outros processos quando esse pode demorar mais para executar.

**Ex:** Você está fazendo um web crawler onde irá ler informações html e para cada página lida, terá que fazer download de 10 fotos.
Veja o processo de download é um ótimo candidato a ser o processo async, pois o download dependerá de diversos fatores, como sua internet, internet do servidor, etc. Então ele poderá ser o gargalo.
Se você fizer varias Task (leitura de páginas) e cada página faça o download síncrono, ele fará a leitura de várias páginas ao mesmo tempo, porém fotos, será uma por vez para cada processo, e não as 10 fotos ao mesmo tempo.
Então esse processo de escolha do que faz algo ser async é realmente complexo e precisa de um bom entendimento de todo o ambiente.

2. **A minha sugestão é determinar o que realmente precisa ser Async e focar nela.**

---

Exemplo genérico de um programa Console Async multi task

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
      TarefaBaseAsync().Wait();
}


private static async Task TarefaBaseAsync()
{
    var tarefas = MeuIENumerable.Select((registro, index) =>
    {
         return Task.Run(async () => await TarefaSecundaria(registro, index));
    });

    await Task.WhenAll(tarefas.ToArray());
}


public static async Task TarefaSecundaria(string valor, int index)
{
               //posso ter tarefas sincronas que eu acredito que não serão gargados
         InsereDapperRegistros();

         // para processos que acho que possa ser um gargalo posso usar o async 
         await DownloadFotoAsync(algumvalor, index);
}
```

Mais informações em:
[Qual a diferença entre os async, multithereading, paralelismo e concorrência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/157435/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-os-async-multithereading-paralelismo-e-concorr%C3%AAncia)