# Executando um Metodo em segundo plano Asp.Net/C# (Async ou Thread)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, thread

O que eu precisava fazer era o seguinte

1. Chamar um método Post que se Chama `Cadastrar`
2. Antes desse método Finalizar eu chamaria um novo método chamado `PessoaNotificacao`

Porem o método Cadastrar não iria esperar o `PessoaNotificação` finalizar para ele continuar, eu gostiaria que o `PessoaNotificação` executasse em segundo plano.

Eu li um pouco sobre os métodos `Asyn and Await` , mas não consegui entendos muito bem, gostaria de uma breve explicação ou algum conteúdo em que eu possa dar uma olhada para entender melhor este conceito.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7760/operacoes-async-em-asp-net?rq=1

Comment: Tem isso *links* para perguntas do assunto em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/175305/101. Provavelmente é duplicata de alguma delas. Ou a pergunta não está clara.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vejo que tudo que precisa é disparar um evento e esquecer, então o `async/await` não é a melhor opção, afinal o `await` irá esperar pelo retorno.

Você pode conseguir o resultado esperado da seguinte forma.:

```
public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {       
        // Realiza algum processo;
        this.Cadastrar();
        // Realiza algum processo;
    }

    public void Cadastrar()
    {
        // Realiza algum processo;
        Task.Run(() => this.PessoaNotificacao(pessoa.Nome));
        // Realiza algum processo;
    }

    public void PessoaNotificacao(string nome)
    {
        // realiza algum processo longo.
    }
}
```

No exemplo acima o `Cadastrar` irá continuar a execução de forma paralela ao `PessoaNotificacao`.

Em todo caso não existe garantia que o `PessoaNotificacao` irá terminar a execução com sucesso, então o melhor a se fazer é usar o [`HangFire`](http://hangfire.io) para gerenciar a execução do mesmo.:

```
public class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {       
        // Realiza algum processo;
        this.Cadastrar();
        // Realiza algum processo;
    }

    public void Cadastrar()
    {
        // Realiza algum processo;
        BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Program.PessoaNotificacao(pessoa.Nome));
        // Realiza algum processo;
    }

    [DisplayName("Notificação enviada para {0}")]
    public static void PessoaNotificacao(string nome)
    {
        // realiza algum processo longo.
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah legal, só uma duvida,por exemplo:
Eu chamo um metódo cadastrar, vai entrar nele e dentro dele eu tenho esse Task.run(this.PessoaNotificacao) . suponhando que o PessoaNotificacao seja demorado, o cadastrar vai finalizar retornar a pagina web  e o notificacao ficaria rodando em segundo plano ?

Comment: @WilliamCézar realizei uma edição.

Comment: Desculpa a demora do retorno , irei testar hoje, mas acho que é isso mesmo, logo volto para marcar como certa a resposta

Comment: Perfeita sua resposta, esta funcionado como deveria, muito obrigado Tobias Mesquita.