# Controller assíncrona no C# em uma API faz diferença?

Tags: c#, api

Qual é a diferença entre um controller de API no C# que utiliza métodos assíncronos (async) e um controller que utiliza métodos síncronos, considerando o consumo da API por meio do JavaScript? O JavaScript aguardará a resposta de qualquer forma, a menos que seja assíncrono também, o que não importaria se a controller é ou não assíncrona.

Mas nesse caso, a utilização de métodos assíncronos no controller faria alguma diferença?

Comment: existe uma pergunta parecida com a sua aqui (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7760/operacoes-async-em-asp-net?rq=1)[aqui]

Comment: Obrigado, mas estava muito complexo a resposta dessa questão, mas me deu um norte bom

Answer (score 0):

Claro que faz!

Lembre-se que o Async no seu endpoint nada tem haver com o async do cliente!

O que você está fazendo é falando para o Roselyn não bloquear seu endpoint quando ele tem por exemplo uma consulta com o banco de dados. Se o banco de dados demorar para responder a consulta e sua consulta não for async todo processo do .NET irá esperar a resposta e sua aplicação pode sofrer um 'engasgo'.
Porém se seu endpoint é async e utiliza comandos async por ex: consultar no database via await/async enquanto ele espera o Database retornar a resposta ele irá processar outras solicitações.