# Problemas com thread

Tags: java, java-ee, thread, multithreading

```
public class ThreadTest implements Runnable {

private String word;
private long time;

public ThreadTest(String word,long time){
    this.word = word;
    this.time = time;
}

public void run() {
    try {
    for(int x = 1; x <= 15; x++)
    {
        System.out.println(word);
            Thread.sleep(time);
            }
    }catch (InterruptedException e){ 
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    Runnable hi = new ThreadTest("hi", 1500);
    Runnable bye = new ThreadTest("bye", 2000);

    new Thread(hi).start();
    new Thread(bye).start();

}
}
```

Console

```
hi
bye
hi
bye
hi
bye
hi
bye
hi
hi
bye
hi
bye
hi
bye
hi
hi
bye
hi
bye
hi
bye
hi
hi
bye
hi
bye
bye
bye
bye
```

Alguma palavras não aparecem sincronizadas. Isso é um problema no compilador, no código ou no meu computador?

Comment: Exatamente qual saída você esperava? Uma thread dorme 1,5 segundos, e a outra dorme 2 segundos, então eu esperava algo mais ou menos igual ao que aconteceu: alternando e de vez em quando algumas seqüências iguais. Em código multi-threaded, a menos que você explicitamente sincronize as ações (synchronized, mutex, volatile, atomic, etc.), praticamente qualquer coisa pode acontecer...

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 10):

Vou dar a melhor resposta para um iniciante e não exatamente para resolver o problema (que nem existe).

## Introdução

Primeiro, **seu computador não está com problema**. Mesmo que ele estivesse, não afetaria o funcionamento do programa desta forma. O programa não funcionaria mesmo.

Segundo, a chance de um iniciante achar um **problema no compilador** que os milhões de programadores experientes não acharam em anos **é tão pequena** que eu não saberia expressar isso em um número.

Por fim, o uso ***threads* é um assunto tão complexo** que mesmo a maioria dos usuários experientes têm dificuldade para usar corretamente. Eu mesmo evito ao máximo e só me arrisco quando realmente há muito necessidade, e procuro por abstrações (camadas de mais alto nível) que façam que eu não tenha que lidar com as *threads* diretamente. Se você não tem um grande domínio de programação, conhecimento amplo sobre o funcionamento do computador, sistema operacional (não como usuário mas sim seu funcionamento interno, mesmo que não todos os detalhes), da plataforma (JVM no seu caso) e todas as implicações sobre processamento paralelo e eventualmente concorrente, é melhor ficar longe delas por enquanto. Eu entendo que você queira aprender mas pular um degrau fará você cair em um buraco e não subir mais rápido a escada.

Mas preciso tentar dar uma resposta objetiva para o seu "problema".

## Não há problema

Você não disse que problema está vendo no resultado. Eu não vejo problema algum. O resultado está perfeito e **não vejo nenhum problema em seu código** (pelo menos para o que você deseja, até tem algumas coisas que poderiam ser feitas de outra forma, mas isto é outro assunto).

#### Sincronismo

Você fala em sincronismo. Sincronismo é um conceito muito utilizado em *threads* mas que você não usou e mesmo que tivesse usado não traria o resultado que você espera (ou que eu acho que você espera). Você acha que está executando fora de ordem? Você acha que deveria intercalar o "hi" e o "bye" cada um esperando 1,5 e o outro 2 segundos, certinho?

Isto só vai acontecer pela mais pura coincidência. As *threads* são duas execuções completamente independentes. **Nada garante a ordem das suas execuções**. O tempo em cada *thread* está sendo respeitado. Se você repetir a execução deste código várias vezes, algumas delas trarão resultados ligeiramente diferentes. Mas ambas farão tudo o que tem que ser corretamente. Só não está na ordem que você deseja.

Se você precisa de controle na ordem de execução e dos resultados, que deve ser o que você chamada de sincronização, você não pode mandar dois agentes distintos (as *threads*) fazerem tarefas que são interdependentes (o que parece ser, se eu entendi certo) e conseguir performance e previsibilidade.

## Exemplos práticos

[Aqui tem uma informação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101) que pode te ajudar entender, um pouquinho só, o funcionamento de *threads*. [Outra fonte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14959/101) interessante que fala de C#, mas o conceito geral serve para qualquer linguagem.

Se pegarmos o exemplo do *motoboy*, você está mandando duas entregadores fazerem 15 entregas mas cada um com uma distância diferente entre os destinatários. Só não está considerando que cada um tem seu próprio tempo para ligar a moto, cada um vai pegar o trânsito de um jeito diferente. E se sincronizar os dois provavelmente vai tornar a entrega mais lenta, afinal sincronizar significa um ficar esperando pelo outro fazer a parte dele. Há casos bons para sincronizar mas muitas vezes se precisar sincronizar você poderá estar deixando mais lento que mandar um agente executar toda a tarefa. Sem falar na possibilidade de criar uma [*race condition*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101) onde um fica esperando ou outro e ambos não chegam a lugar nenhum.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).