# Diferença na execução de threads em Java

Tags: java, thread, multithreading

Veja a execução de dois programas semelhantes em Java. Um herda de `Thread` e outro implementa a interface `Runnable`:

Programa1:

```
public class PingPong extends Thread{
private String msg;
private int delay;

PingPong(String s,int tempo){
    msg = s;
    delay = tempo;
}

public void run(){
    try{
        for (int i=1;i<=10;i++){
            System.out.println(msg+ " " + i);
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println("Deu pau!");
        return;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PingPong ping = new PingPong("ping",500);
    ping.start();

    PingPong pong = new PingPong("pong",1000);
    pong.start();

    System.out.println("*** FIM DO PROGRAMA PRINCIPAL ***");
}}
```

Ele gera a seguinte saída:

[image: execuçâo]

E temos o programa 2:

```
    public class PingPong2 implements Runnable{
    private String msg;
    private int delay;

    PingPong2(String s,int tempo){
        msg = s;
        delay = tempo;
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            for (int i=1;i<=10;i++){
                System.out.println(msg+ " " + i);
                Thread.sleep(delay);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println("Deu pau!");
            return;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable ping = new PingPong2("ping",500);
        Runnable pong = new PingPong2("pong",1000);

        new Thread(ping).start();
        new Thread(pong).start();
        System.out.println("*** FIM DO PROGRAMA PRINCIPAL ***");
    }
}
```

Gerando a seguinte saída:

[image: execuçâo]

Por que a saída no programa1 não é impresso o "ping1" uma vez que na implementação do método `run()`, a impressão na tela é feita antes de colocar a *thread* para dormir (em espera)?

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 5):

Primeiro: a classe do primeiro exemplo está conceitualmente errada. `PingPong` não é uma `Thread`, por isso não deveria herdar dela. Funciona, mas está errado. O problema de fato não é esse. Entendo que esse é só um teste, mas é comum as pessoas transporem coisas assim para código normal. Então vale o alerta.

*Threads* são complicadas, são imprevisíveis, o programador tem pouco controle sobre elas. Elas são duas linhas de execução distintas e independentes, por isso não há garantia de ordem de execução. *Threads* tendem a criar [condições de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101).

Depende do agendamento do sistema operacional. Especialmente a primeira execução pode dar uma diferença maior porque a criação de uma nova *thread* é algo custoso.

O que provavelmente ocorreu é que a execução do `pong` pegou um agendamento mais favorável e conseguiu concluir a criação da *thread* e seu início antes. Muito provavelmente a criação da *thread* do `ping` iniciou antes, mas o que importa é a conclusão.

O segundo exemplo poderia ter ocorrido o mesmo, só deu "sorte" de não ocorrer. Cada execução será diferente. Note que ele também não executa como o esperado e intercala o *ping* com o *pong* nas primeiras execuções como se o *delay* fosse igual.

Não use *threads* se precisar de previsibilidade. Elas são menos úteis do que as pessoas imaginam.

- [Existe diferença entre Programa, Thread e Processo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131108/101)
- [É sempre garantido que uma aplicação com múltiplas threads rode mais rápido que usando uma única thread?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101)
- [Problemas com thread](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/18799/101) (praticamente duplicata, só vi depois de concluir esta resposta)