# bug de superposição das threads no python

Tags: python, python-3.x, thread

Olá, estou estudando o funcionamento das threads e fiz um programa onde existe uma função que printa o horário atual de 'n' em 'n' segundos, e gostaria de criar um processamento paralelo onde eu posso jogar essa função em um processo para printar o horário atual de 3 em 3 segundos e o outro processo de 5 em 5 segundos por exemplo, este é o código que eu fiz:

```
import time
import datetime
import threading


def temporizador(worker, amplitude):
    # Não é necessário entender o funcionamento dessa função
    while True:
        unix_agora = (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
        unix_agora_int = int(unix_agora)
        unix_agora_dec = unix_agora - unix_agora_int
        resto = int(unix_agora) % amplitude
        tempo_fim = int(unix_agora - resto - unix_agora_dec)
        print('worker', worker, '|', datetime.datetime.now())
        espera = tempo_fim + amplitude - (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
        time.sleep(espera)



i = 0

threading.Thread(target=temporizador, args=('1', 3)).start()
threading.Thread(target=temporizador, args=('2', 5)).start()
```

o programa funciona, porém frequentemente a mensagem printada de uma thread se superpõe à outra ficando tudo misturado. Isto é o que acontece quando eu rodo o programa:

worker 1 | 2019-06-04 21:08:50.108693

worker 2 | 2019-06-04 21:08:50.108693

worker 1 | 2019-06-04 21:08:51.002126

worker 1 | 2019-06-04 21:08:54.000400

worker 2 | 2019-06-04 21:08:55.001707

worker 1 | 2019-06-04 21:08:57.000754

worker 1 | 2019-06-04 21:09:00.001023

worker 2 | 2019-06-04 21:09:00.001023

worker 1 | 2019-06-04 21:09:03.000719

worker 2 | 2019-06-04 21:09:05.000572

worker 1 | 2019-06-04 21:09:06.001783

worker 1 | 2019-06-04 21:09:09.001796

worker 2 | 2019-06-04 21:09:10.001719

worker 1 | 2019-06-04 21:09:12.001740

worker worker 21 |  |2019-06-04 21:09:15.001721
 2019-06-04 21:09:15.001721

worker 1 | 2019-06-04 21:09:18.001723

worker 2 | 2019-06-04 21:09:20.001753

worker 1 | 2019-06-04 21:09:21.001057

.

Como eu posso corrigir este bug? Agradeço.

Comment: Não usando *thread*. Provavelmente é o mesmo problema que este: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131126/101 Ou esse: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/18799/101

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi então usar threads não é uma boa ideia, neste caso, como eu poderia fazer este processo funcionar paralelamente com mais ou menos o mesmo resultado que eu obtive usando thread?

Comment: Quase nunca, especialmente em Python, eu não entendo porque as pessoas fazem isto. Claro, tem casos que pode ser vantajoso, mas como isto é uma das coisas mais difíceis de usar na computação é melhor ficar longe a não ser que precise muito e tenha certeza do que está fazendo. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101.

Comment: Entendi, procurarei outra alternativa então, mas não sei por onde começar, pois preciso de funções que coletem dados paralelamente, você tem alguma sugestão do que eu posso fazer?

Comment: Não tenho como sugerir porque nem sei se realmente precisa disto.

Comment: Threads podem ser úteis sim - em Python tem que saber quando e como - mas mesmo antes disso, dá pra aprender a forma correta de lidar com threads. Impressão é um dos promblemas comuns, e respondi a abordagem correta (em Python, mas também é o jeito certo em qualquer linguagem) há poucos dias atrás, por isso marquei como duplicada.

Comment: Já o fato de threads não serem uma boa ideia para problemas reais em Python, a não ser que você saiba o que está fazendo, é por que na implementação padrão do Python há um lock global na máquina virtual, que só deixa uma thread rodar código Python de cada vez, mesmo em CPUs com múltiplos núcleos. Se o seu código chama funções nativas que vão fazer o heavy lifiting, ou como uma forma "prática e barata" de lidar com problemas de entrada e saída (por exemplo, para web scrapping, fazendo múltiplas requisições de rede em paralelo), threads em  Python são uma boa sim.

Comment: @Maniero - você não está "pegando muito no pé" de Python não? A linguagem é popular sim, mas tem motivos para isso - eu preciso pedir que você respire fundo e pense bem sobre a objetividade dos comentários e respostas que você tem dado sobre a linguagem.

Comment: @Rafael: se o seu pproblema é coletar dados paralelamente, threads podem ser sim uma boa solução - não são a "mais eficiente" - mas você perderia o principal benefício de usar Python - agilidade no desenvolvimento - se fosse se preocupar em fazer uma aplicação usando asyncio ou um multiprocessing pool, se o problema são requisiçoes web em paralelo. Se o seu problema é a impressão não encavalar, a resposta que eu indiquei deve resolver. Se houver mais problemas, só abrir as perguntas, com o problema específico.

Comment: @jsbueno não, eu exponho problemas que ela tem. Você não é muito apaixonado por ela não? Eu preciso pedir que respire fundo e pense bem sobre objetividade dos comentários e respostas, afinal eu digo problemas que ela tem, você acha que não tem. Ou você acha que eu estou falando mal da linguagem, ou ainda que eu falei que algo é ruim pra tudo, e a impressão que dá é que você se dói por isso. Agora mesmo eu falei de *threads* quase o tempo todo, apenas destaquei Python como um caso que tende a ser mais problemático e precisa mais cuidado, você se doeu.