# Problema com print de Threads em Python

Tags: python

Estou desenvolvendo um código em python do jantar dos filósofos... para quem não conhece, segue o link: [https://blog.pantuza.com/artigos/o-jantar-dos-filosofos-problema-de-sincronizacao-em-sistemas-operacionais](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biYIO.png)...
Nesse caso, estou usando threads e semaforo para a resolução do problema...A minha dúvida é na hora de printar, pois algumas vezes, está printando um filosofo em cima do outro, como mostrado na imagem abaixo... Queria saber se teria uma solução para isso.
Segue o código, e o logo abaixo do código, a imagem do terminal.

```
import thread
import time, random
import threading

garfo = list()
for i in range(5):
   garfo.append(threading.Semaphore(1))

def filosofo(f):
   f = int(f)
   while True:
      # garfo da esquerda
      garfo[f].acquire()
      # garfo da direita
      garfo[(f + 1) % 5].acquire()
      i = random.randint(1, 5)
      print ("Filosofo %i comendo por %i segundos..." %(f,i))
      time.sleep(i)
      garfo[f].release()
      garfo[(f + 1) % 5].release()
      t = random.randint(1, 10)
      print ("Filosofo %i pensando por %i segundos..."%(f,t))
      time.sleep(t)


for i in range(5):
   print ("Filosofo",i,"iniciado")
   thread.start_new_thread(filosofo, tuple([i]))

while 1: pass
```

[image: Print do terminal rodando]

Comment: Tu colocou aquele `while 1: pass` pro programa não encerrar antes de completar o algoritmo?

Comment: É importante dentro do `while 1: ` do final colocar um `time.sleep()` m, senão athread principal vai consumir 100% de CPU fazendo _nada_. (Bateria, energia, temperatura da CPU agradecem)

Answer (score 2):

Crie uma função de print sua que use um lock de thread - é o suficiente.

```
print_lock = threading.Lock()

original_print = __builtins__.print

def print(*args, **kw):
   with print_lock:
      original_print(*args, **kw)
```

E use esse print aí no código que roda em várias threads.

Se houvesse a possiblidade de esse código gerar um "dead lock": alguém esperando para imprimir, mas a impressão não será liberada por que alguém tem um outro lock, aí a coisa poderia ser mais sofisticada -

Seria possível, por exemplo, ter uma Queue de print - a fun~ao de "print" chamada das threads colocaria os parâmetros do print nessa Queue, como uma tupla, e, em uma única thread, você teria uma função "print" real que leria os parâmetros dessa Queue e chamaria o print original do Python. 
Mas isso também exige que você tenha um mecanismo de agendamento que chame regularmente a função de "print" na thread certa para verificar se há impressões - ou,  mais simples seria ter uma thread exclusiva de impressão em loop continuo

```
stop_printing = object()
print_queue = queue.Queue()

def tprint(*args, **kw):
   print_queue.put((args, kw)) # Coloca args e kw como uma única tupla

def printer_worker():

    while True: 
       parametros = print_queue.get()
       if parametros is stop_printing:
           break
       print(*paramtros[0], **parametros[1])
       time.sleep(0.1)  # pausa é opcional, por que a chamada ao .get é bloqueante. mas é de bom tom - pode ser bem menor, se necessário.

printer = threading.Thread(target=printer_worker)
printer.start()
```

Nesse código, as outras threads imprimem usando o "tprint" em vez de "print" (mas é possível renomear as funções como no outro exemplo, claro)

**atualização**: Para entender melhor o que acontece  com a impressão no original, veja a resposta do Maniero aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/18802/500