# Como executar duas funções, ambas contendo loop infinito, simultaneamente em Python?

Tags: python

Tenho no arquivo connections.py duas funções, uma onde estou lendo o campo 'status' de uma tabela a cada 1 segundo.

Tenho também uma outra função nesse mesmo arquivo fazendo o mesmo processo, porém em outra tabela.

Abaixo, listo o conteúdo do arquivo mencionado acima (connections.py)

```py
import mysql.connector, time
import _thread as thread

db_connection = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="meuUsername",
  passwd="minhaSenha",
  database="meuBD"
)

my_database = db_connection.cursor()

def getTable1(): #Lê status de detecção / nome e identify
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        sql_statement = 'SELECT peopleId FROM detections where status = 1'
        my_database.execute(sql_statement)
        output = my_database.fetchall()
        print('Executando Thread getTable1()')

def getTable2():#lê status de reconhecimento
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        sql_statement = 'SELECT * FROM recognitions where status = 1'
        my_database.execute(sql_statement)
        output = my_database.fetchall()
        print('Executando Thread getTable2()')
```

Em outro arquivo, denominado index.py, estou importando o conteúdo do arquivo connections.py e instanciando duas threads, uma para cada função de leitura no banco de dados.

```py
import threading
import os, connections as cn

if __name__ == "__main__":

    processos = []
    processos.append(threading.Thread(target=cn.getStatusDetections()))
    processos.append(threading.Thread(target=cn.getStatusRecognitions()))
        # Ex: adicionar o porcesso `threading.Thread(target=inicia_programa, args=('x.py',))`

    for processo in processos:
        processo.start()
```

Porém, ambas threads não são executadas ao mesmo tempo, sendo que são executadas em sequência, o que resulta em nunca sair da execução da função getTable1().

No console é printado a cada um segundo somente:

`Executando Thread getTable1()
Executando Thread getTable1()
Executando Thread getTable1()
Executando Thread getTable1()`

Sendo que eu desejaria que fosse mostrado o resultado das duas assim (não importa se seja em ordem):

`Executando Thread getTable1()
Executando Thread getTable2()
Executando Thread getTable1()
Executando Thread getTable2()`

Alguém saberia me passar algum conhecimento sobre como tratar isso de maneira que funcione a execução das duas threads simultaneamente?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
threading.Thread(target=cn.getStatusDetections())
```

Aqui você está chamando a função `cn.getStatusDetections` e passando o retorno como `target` da *thread*. Como a função nunca terá retorno, visto que ficará presa em um laço infinito, o interpretador não conseguirá avaliar o valor de `target`, ficando executando esta linha eternamente.

O que você deve passar como `target` é uma referência à função que deseja executar, sem os parenteses.

```
threading.Thread(target=cn.getStatusDetections)
```

Assim a função será executada dentro da *thread*.

Sobre utilizar a função `print` nas *threads*, sugiro que leia [Problema com print de Threads em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/386943/5878)

Comment: Boa garoto, era isso mesmo que me faltava. Ainda bem que era uma coisa tão boba kkkkk.

Answer (score 0):

Além da resposta do @Anderson Carlos Woss, o mysql é meio chato para acesso mútuo ao banco de dados, ele pode retornar algum erro com duas threads acessando ele ao mesmo tempo. Nesse caso, tive que reservar o acesso de cada thread ao banco de dados:

```py
lock = threading.Lock() #Aqui instanciei essa variável

#Essa reserva de acesso usei dentro dos métodos de getTable1() e getTable2().
def getTable1():
    while True:
        lock.acquire() #Aqui reserva o acesso na porta para essa thrad.
        sql_statement = 'SELECT peopleId FROM detections where status = 1'
        my_database.execute(sql_statement)
        output = my_database.fetchall()
        if output: # se houve alteração do status,
            getPeople(output[0][0]) # executa função de encontrar a pessoa
        else: print('Detecção status = 0')
        lock.release() #Aqui libera o acesso na porta para outras Threads
        time.sleep(1)
```