# setTimeout não executado no loop(each)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Veja a função abaixo:

```
$(grupo).each(function (i) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "curltst.php",
            data: {
                acao: "teste",
                mensagem: mensagem,
                grupo: grupo[i]
            },
            dataType: "xml",
            method: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                grupo = $(data).find("tdgrupo").text();
                status = $(data).find("tdstatus").text();
                $("tbody").append("
<tr>
    <td>" + grupo + "</td>
    <td>" + status + "</td>
</tr>");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("ERRO 008");
            }
        });
    }, 10000);
});
```

Enfim, grupo é um array com uns 5 grupos.

A ideia é que, cada vez que for percorrer o array(grupo[0],grupo[1]..) tenha um intervalo de 10 segundos, mas o que acontece é diferente, ele espera 10 segundos para começar, mas envia todas as requisições AJAX, ou seja, ele espera 10 segundos, e depois percorre todo o array e envia ajax, é como se a partir da segunda vez o `setTimeout` fosse ignorado..

No meu pensamento, deveria aguardar 10 segundos(10000ms) e depois enviar ajax, ai ir para o próximo indice do array(grupo), esperar 10 e ir ajax, e assim até percorrer por completo..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ao contrário do que você está pensando, o loop todo do `each` ocorre imediatamente. Só o que está dentro do setTimeout roda "atrasado", de forma assíncrona (como se fosse "em paralelo"). Dentro do loop, seu código não para por 10 segundos.

O conserto mais rápido é usar `10000 * i` na definição dos timers. Isso atrasa cada um em 10 segundos em relação ao anterior. Não tem muita precisão, mas no seu caso não parece haver necessidade de mais do que isso.

---

Outra solução um pouco mais elegante (mas ainda dá pra melhorar):

```
$(grupo).each(function (i) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "curltst.php",
        data: {
            acao: "teste",
            mensagem: mensagem,
            grupo: grupo[i]
        },
        dataType: "xml",
        method: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var grupo = $(data).find("tdgrupo").text();
                var status = $(data).find("tdstatus").text();
                $("tbody").append("<tr><td>" + grupo + "</td><td>" + status + "</td></tr>");
            }, 10000 * i);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("ERRO 008");
        }
    });
});
```

**Importante:** essa solução executa todas as chamadas ajax imediatamente, e só atrasa a alteração do DOM (o `append` na sua tabela com o resultado de cada requisição).

Comment: Mais detalhes: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51268/qual-a-diferença-entre-comunicação-ass%C3%ADncrona-e-s%C3%ADncrona/51269#51269, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16950/como-programação-ass%C3%ADncrona-funciona-em-javascript

Comment: bah! eu pensava que setTimeout trava-se o script pelo tempo que estimei até o processamento da função que continha, como o sleep() do php faz.

Comment: mas não faria sentido dai, pois ele comprometeria o resto do script que viesse depois, mas a função dele é apenas estimar um tempo, atrasar a função. Valeu @bfavaretto!

Comment: Não é assim. Ajax também não é assim, é o mesmo princípio n

Comment: olha só, antes de eu adicionar o `*i` no 10000, estava enviando certo o array grupo: `grupo = ["951179678239911","1559692210955385","860177374023863","722424877870676"]`, agora, adicionei este(somente essa alteração), e em algum momento o grupo[i](no segundo) acaba me retornando o valor 1, e o 4(ultimo) acabo de me retornar 9, ai quando tiro o `*i` os indices correspondem ao valor direitinho, isso pode ser pelo que? para mim não faz menor sentido, na verdade eu acho nada a ver mesmo..

Comment: o interessante é que, apesar que após o 9511 vier 1559 a ordem que acontece é 9511.. depois vem 1, depois 1559.. após por ultimo 9. ou seja, os indices do 860177.. e do 72242.. não são enviados com o valor correto e ainda fora da ordem do array..

Comment: Você altera essa array de grupos em algum lugar depois desse código?

Comment: altero não, apenas envio para o curltst.php o grupo pelo método POST usando  o AJAX, e lá no curltst.php eu faço os procedimentos com o grupo, acontece é que na requisição o que está sendo postado está de desacordo com que era para ser, os valores do array está correto(como mostrei ali encima, é exatamente aquilo que está no array grupo), era para ser 72242.. e tá indo 9, agora testei novamente com o time `10000*i`(antes tava `30000*i`) e as vezes nem envia o grupo(como se o grupo[i] estive-se vazio)..

Comment: Não sei o que pode ser. [Veja uma prova de conceito de que essa estrutura funciona](http://jsfiddle.net/xqbcwd4f/).

Comment: de acordo @bfavaretto, ótima resposta, deve ser alguma coisa então que passou despercebido, obg pela atenção!

Comment: Bom, incluí um outro caminho, se quiser testar.

Comment: Aliás, achei a causa do seu problema: você redefine `grupo` dentro do success, faltou um `var` ali.

Comment: perfeito @bfavaretto, era exatamente este o erro, agora está tudo ok, valeu pela força, ia patinar nisso um tempo porquê essa de variavel global e local nem havia passado na cabeça.. tudo de bom pra você ai mestre! :)

Comment: Esta solução não me parece estar certa. o que eu entendi é que o @AlexandreC.Caus quer fazer as requisições após 10 segundos e não colocar os resultados no DOM após 10 segundos. Onde no caso está fazendo todas as requisições imediatamente mas aguardando 10 segundos para persistir.

Comment: @Gabriel é verdade que o código acima (que foi minha segunda sugestão pra ele) funciona como você falou. Mas não tenho tanta certeza de que isso seria  um problema para o que ele quer. Pode ser, pode não ser. De fato faltou eu explicar o que o código faz.

Comment: Eu entendo a motivação e concordo com a sua resposta, mas visando o melhor aprendizado fiz uma resposta que atém exatamente ao resultado esperado pela pergunta. Infelizmente é mais complexo, mas acho que poderá ajudar outras pessoas que tenham a mesma pergunta mas não se satisfaçam com a sua resposta que é especifica para o usuário @AlexandreC.Caus

Comment: Ótimo @GabrielGartz, +1 na sua resposta. De fato é a maneira "correta" de se fazer isso. Você supôs bem, eu fui pelo caminho mais fácil por considerar que seria mais fácil do Alexandre entender.

Answer (score 4):

Conhecendo o @bfavaretto sei que ele utilizou uma forma didática para resolver o problema e explicar de uma forma simples como o JS funciona. Vou tentar aqui ser um pouco mais técnico me atendo diretamente a questão do usuário @Alexandre C.Caus.

O JavaScript roda em apenas uma *thread*, porém funções como `setTimeout` vão ser executadas com atraso sem parar a execução da função que executou a chamada. Isso é, o loop será inteiramente executado e os `setTimeout` serão enfileirados em seguida a execução, aguardando o tempo do ponto em que foram chamados.

Para que um código seja chamado após 10 segundos em sequencia, o `setTimeout` subsequente deve estar "dentro" da execução do anterior.

Porque esse processo gera muitas funções uma dentro da outra, o código pode ficar muito bagunçado, para simplificar um pouco a resposta vou empregar o uso de promessas do próprio jQuery, para simplificar o código:

```
var promisse;
var waitFor = 10e3; // 10 segundos
$(grupo).each(function(i){
    function ajaxCall(i) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: "curltst.php",
            data: {
                acao: "teste",
                mensagem: mensagem,
                grupo: grupo[i]
            },
            dataType: "xml",
            method: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                grupo = $(data).find("tdgrupo").text();
                status = $(data).find("tdstatus").text();
                $("tbody").append("
                <tr>
                    <td>" + grupo + "</td>
                    <td>" + status + "</td>
                </tr>");
                },
            error: function () {
                alert("ERRO 008");
            }
        });
    }

    // Na primeira requisição use a promessa diretamente do retorno do
    // método ajax, isso vai fazer com que a primeira requisição seja
    // instantânea.
    if(!promisse) promisse = ajaxCall(i);
    // Caso já seja uma promessa, a função de callback vai ser chamada
    else promise.then(function(){
        // Definimos a deferencia da promessa que irá aguardar o tempo
        // desejado aqui, e já retornamos a nossa sequencia de promessas
        // antes dela ser resolvida, assim o loop segue fazendo o mesmo
        // até chegar ao fim.
        var deferred = $.deferred();
        // Isso será executado apenas quando a promessa anterior for resolvida
        // isso é, você tem o resultado da sua ultima requisição ajax e
        // agora vai esperar o tempo necessário pra proxima requisição
        setTimeout(function(){
            // Passado tempo, agora vamos fazer a nova requisição
            // e vamos fazer uma ponte do resultado da requisição a nossa
            // promessa, assim o proximo só começa ser executado quando
            // a resposta chegar
            ajaxCall(i).done(deferred.resolve).fail(deferred.fail);
        }, waitFor);
        return deferred.promise();
    });
});
```

Como seria o fluxo de execução deste código:

- variável para promessas é definida no escopo
- Loop é iniciado

  - verifica se há promessas, senão faz a *prepara* a requisição e guarda promessa (a requisição será executada depois), vai para o proximo resultado do loop;
  - se há promessa, *prepara* o setTimeout para retornar uma promessa que contém a requisição AJAX e coloca na fila de promessas, depois vai para o proximo resultado do loop;
- Terminou o loop;
- Primeira requisição AJAX é executada, quando retornar;
- Inicia `setTimeout` de 10 segundos, quando terminar;
- Inicia próxima requisição AJAX, e quando terminar, repete o processo do passo anterior até que todas promessas sejam resolvidas;

Comment: interessante essa de promessas, vou ler mais sobre isso para me iterar da sua resolução!

Comment: então o objeto deferred ele que vai conter toda a lista para execução, no caso, todas as requisições AJAX estarão contidas nele, mas elas vão executando conforme vai terminando outra, tipo, quando a promessa da anterior for feita, é isso? para mim isso é um conceito novissimo de tratar requisicoes assincronas, antes eu colocava tudo no success já que isso me garantia que já foi realizada a requisição

Comment: essa linha aqui: `ajaxCall(i).done(deferred.resolve).fail(deferred.fail);`, é como, quando a função for realizada(a requisição foi feita) ele informa ao deferred que foi resolvida ou quando falha que houve falha, então, se resolvida, ele segue para a próxima execução(se houver)?

Comment: Direto no comentário vai ser difícil eu te explicar promisses, mas o que ele está fazendo ali é criar uma fila de "callbacks", no loop, eu estou enfileirando, e ao terminar o loop o primeiro `$.ajax` vai iniciar e quando ele terminar, vai disparar o próximo usando `then` e assim sucessivamente até acabar.

Comment: todo comando `ajax` do jquery retorna um `promisse` por isso eu posso usar direto do jeito que eu fiz. O `success` callback é o mesmo que `done` do promisse e o `fail` tem o mesmo nome para promisses ou por callback.
O que eu na linha que vc comentou é, se o ajax retornar sucesso, resolve a promessa, se retornar falha, falha a promessa. Desta maneira eu posso criar a promessa, antes de criar o timeout e apenas retornar o resultado da promessa quando terminar a requisição ajax (independente do tempo que o ajax leve).