# Como pegar um JSON, a partir de uma URL?

Tags: java, android

Continuo estudando AndroidStudio e a bola da vez eh pegar dados por URL, em formato json,

> **Para isso** criei uma pagina de exemplo:
> (http://exemplo.minha.info/nav/2.html),
>
> com o seguinte conteúdo: 
> {"content": "hello world"}

**ENTÃO** peguei o exemplo daqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32549360/best-practice-to-get-json-from-url-in-api-23

**Onde meu código** ficou assim:

```
//  public class JSONParser {
    public static class JSONParser {
    
        static InputStream is = null;
        static JSONObject json = null;
        static String output = "";



        public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List params) {
            URL _url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection;

            try {
                _url = new URL(url);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) _url.openConnection();
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error due to a malformed URL " + e.toString());
                return null;
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "IO error " + e.toString());
                return null;
            }

            try {
                is = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder(is.available());
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    total.append(line).append('\n');
                }
                output = total.toString();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "IO error " + e.toString());
                return null;
            }
            finally{
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }

            try {
                json = new JSONObject(output);
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            return json;
        }
    }
```

E, estou chamando o código a partir do "onCreate" assim:

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject payload = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(
        "http://igakubu.e4dev.info/nav/2.html",
        null);
try {
    System.out.println(payload.get("content"));
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Acontece que da um erro na linha**
"is = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());"

**com o seguinte código no console:**
at jp.co.e_grid.rakuseki.PostConfirmationActivity$JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(PostConfirmationActivity.java:177)

e a partir daqui.. fiquei completamente perdida, o máximo que consegui pesquisar no google, eh que parece ser um erro de java.

Agradeceria se alguém me desse um norte aqui, pois sou novada!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

> A exceção que é lançada quando um aplicativo tenta executar uma
>   operação de rede em seu segmento principal.

Para evitar esse erro, tente usar o [**`AsyncTask`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). E colocar todas as tarefas relacionadas com a rede dentro do método `doInBackground` do seu `AsyncTask`.

Sugiro você ler um pouco mais sobre [comunicação de dados Síncrona x Assíncrona](https://www.oficinadanet.com.br/post/9978-comunicacao-de-dados-sincrona-x-assincona). Aqui mesmo no SOpt tem essa pergunta sobre [qual a diferença entre comunicação assíncrona e síncrona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51268/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ass%C3%ADncrona-e-s%C3%ADncrona) com algumas respostas bem esclarecedoras que irá te ajudar bastante.

Exemplo de `AsyncTask`:

```
public class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL); 

            }
        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    }
}
```

Logo depois pode-se chamar a classe dentro do seu `onCreate` desta forma:

```
new JSONAsyncTask().execute(URL);
```

Lembrando que existem várias formas de fazer isso além de usar o `AnsyncTask`. Sugiro também que leia um pouco mais [consumir dados de um Web Service com Android](http://www.devmedia.com.br/consumindo-dados-de-um-web-service-com-android/33717).

Comment: ui!   brigada!  estudando! :D você esta sempre atencioso! feliz aqui !  PS* tive que "pausar" o outro post(autorização para usar GPS) mas já já volto pra ele!

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto sem problema. Vou detalhar mais essa reposta pra você, mas enquanto isso vai lendo os links para entender melhor.

Comment: bom vou tentar! na pagina.... https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html estou tendo dificuldades para entender o que colocar em **(URL... urls)**

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto vou colocar um exemplo consumindo seu 2.html pra você. só um min.

Comment: ahh entendi!  :D !

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto se quiser fazer um teste, já funciona.

Comment: desculpe te encher, mas... to com umas duvidas aqui.. tipo: o meu AndriodStudio importa o "AsyncTask" sem problemas... mas .. ja o "HttpGet "  ele exige que eu crie uma classe??  isso eh assim mesmo?

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto na verdade o uso do Async é desta forma ai sem mais. Os valores que estão dentro do doInBackground são para resgatar dados do que estão na sua página html. Esse httpGet já está deprecated, mas ainda funciona bem. Coloquei para que você tivesse mais noção. Para importar essa biblioteca, vá no se Gradle e dentro do Android você insira `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` e peça para sincronizar.

Comment: Fiz uma atualização, na pergunta.... inserindo sua resposta e o que me deu de retorno! ainda aparece o mesmo erro! assim nao precisei usar o (http deprecached)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52561/discussion-between-ack-lay-and-camila-yamamoto).