# Como esperar uma função javascript dentro de outra?

Tags: javascript

Tenho a situação hipotética:

```js
function fTeste2(valor) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert("Hello");
  }, 3000);
  return valor + 5;
}

function fTeste1(valor) {
  return fTeste2(valor);
}

alert(fTeste1(10));
```

Perceba que a função 2 envia a soma sem que tenha terminado todo o processo interno, sei que se eu colocar a soma dentro do settimeout ele vai esperar e me dar o resultado, mas a função 2 exemplifica uma função com varias operações, isso em outra linguagem esperaria o termino da função 2, já no javascript isso não ocorre, como resolver?

Comment: Você está fazendo algo assíncrono. [Veja](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51268/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ass%C3%ADncrona-e-s%C3%ADncrona)

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira simples de contonar esse problema é trabalhar com `callbacks`. Basicamente, uma função que será executada quando uma operação ser finalizada. No seu caso, ao invés de esperar o retorno de `fTeste1` para acionar a função `alert`, você pode passá-la como `callback`, como no código abaixo, indicando: quando encerrar a execução de `fTeste2`, execute `alert` com o parâmetro passado.

```js
function fTeste2(valor, callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert("Hello");
    callback(valor + 5);
  }, 3000);
}

function fTeste1(valor, callback) {
  fTeste2(valor, callback);
}

fTeste1(10, alert);
```

Ao executar o código, verá que o `alert(15)` só é executado após o `alert("hello")`, como desejado.

Comment: Mas ai se eu retirar o callback de dentro da função settimeout ele vai executar primeiro a soma, o exemplo que dei é pra mostrar que não há uma espera sequencial das operações, eu deveria fazer uma arvore de processos com as funções, mas não sei como fazer

Comment: "não há uma espera sequencial das operações". Exatamente, esse é o espirito das chamadas assíncronas. Se você precisa que seja sequencial, não use `setTimeout`.