# WebWorker e Async - Qual a diferença e quando utilizar?

Tags: javascript, html5, assincronismo

Estou estudando especificamente uma implementação de WebWorker, e não entendi muito bem a *diferença entre **WebWorker** e **Async** no JavaScript,* considerando que o WebWorker me dá uma solução assíncrona com uma organização de código (a meu ver) mais bem feita.

Comment: No momento estou sem tempo pra postar uma resposta aqui @Bruno, mas comecei a estudar por esse [link](https://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/workers/basics/) e achei muito bom, vale a pena conferir. No mais assunto muito interessante +1

Comment: Marconi, este link é interessante. Eu já tinha lido ele. Porém não me esclarece bem sobre a pergunta em si.

Comment: Bruno tentei explicar da melhora maneira possível, caso você ainda tenha alguma dúvida adicione um comentario a minha resposta. Que tento melhorar a resposta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ambos são um tanto similares.

Funções assíncronas só são possíveis quando usadas com um das seguintes opções:

- *[SetTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)*
- *[SetInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)*
- *[XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)*
- *[Webworkers](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp)*

`Webworkers` também fazem parte desta lista, mesmo que eles não são pertencentes à mesma categoria.

A principal diferença entre todos eles é o acesso aos recursos. Usando `XMLHttpRequest` você trocar dados entre cliente e servidor de forma assíncrona usando o mesmo fio.

Devido à má utilização de hardware de processador multi-núcleo surgiram os `Webworkers` para a programação paralela. O acesso à memória está limitado aos dados que estão sendo trocados com eles. Eles são executados em segmentos separados e a interface do usuário está disponível para outras atividades.

Workers não podem acessar o DOM para ler ou modificar o documento HTML. 
Além disso, eles não podem acessar quaisquer variáveis ​​globais ou funções JavaScript dentro da página principal. O acesso a alguns objetos, incluindo a janela, o documento são restrito.

**Ilustração:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Nota:*** Caso queira aprofundar mais em  WebWorkers, recomendo a leitura deste artigo:

- [Introdução ao Web Workers: como trazer o sequenciamento ao
  JavaScript](https://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/workers/basics/).

O artigo tem um passo a passo bem auto explicativo de como criar uma requisição assíncrona com WebWorkers.

Na documentação da W3C, tem um exemplo de um contador.

## Javascript

```
var w;

function startWorker() {
    if(typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
        if(typeof(w) == "undefined") {
            w = new Worker("demo_workers.js");
        }
        w.onmessage = function(event) {
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = event.data;
        };
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Workers...";
    }
}

function stopWorker() { 
    w.terminate();
    w = undefined;
}
```

> O arquivo "demo_workers.js" deve estar em um arquivo separado, pelo fato de serem
>   executados em sequência isolada.

## demo_workers.js

```
var i = 0;

function timedCount() {
    i = i + 1;
    postMessage(i);
    setTimeout("timedCount()",500);
}

timedCount();
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte:

- [What's the difference between Web Workers and Asynchronous Functions
  in JavaScript?](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-Web-Workers-and-Asynchronous-Functions-in-JavaScript)
- [Introdução ao Web Workers: como trazer o sequenciamento ao JavaScript](https://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/workers/basics/)

Comment: Marconi, para fechar com chave de ouro, poderia dar um exemplo (mesmo que seja conceitual) de quando utilizar `WebWorkers` e quando utilizar `XMLHttpRequest`?

Comment: @BrunoHeringer Use Workers quando for disparar scripts de longa duração para executar tarefas muito dispendiosas.Já o Async para coisas mais simples. A um tempo atrás eu fiz uma pergunta sobre [Qual a diferença entre comunicação assíncrona e síncrona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51268/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ass%C3%ADncrona-e-s%C3%ADncrona)