# Quando usar método assíncronos ou síncronos?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, entity-framework, assincronismo

Quando devo usar métodos assíncronos ou síncronos em *controllers* (índice, pesquisa, deletar, criar) de aplicações ASP.NET MVC?

Posso perder desempenho? Em quais situações devo usar um ou outro, poderiam dar exemplos?

Se tenho muitos usuários fazendo consulta em uma única página `async` com requisição ao banco de dados, isso não geraria uma fila grande dependendo do tempo de execução da aplicação? Como isso é gerenciado para não impedir as próximas de executarem?

O uso de métodos assíncronos evita ataques DDoS?

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51268/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ass%C3%ADncrona-e-s%C3%ADncrona

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Quando devo usar métodos assíncronos ou síncronos em controllers (índice, pesquisa, deletar, criar) de aplicações ASP.NET MVC?

A recomendação geral de uso de assincronismo é quando a operação demora pelo menos 50ms. Menos do que isso não compensa. Na verdade tem que medir a sua situação, tem casos que até mais pode não compensar. E isso pode variar ao longo do tempo com atualizações diversas.

O assincronismo é útil para melhorar a experiência do usuário quando há alguma operação que demanda muito tempo para ser executada. Então um cliente pode continuar disponível quando ele pede algo para um serviço que demora. Ele não é usado para tornar algo mais rápido.

Se considerar que assincronismo raramente dá ganho em operações que exigem só processamento, sem IO, então é raro ser útil em algum lugar, a não ser que configure o servidor HTTP para não aceitar requisições demais e sobrecarregar o servidor, ou as operações de IO sejam muito longas, ou pelo menos você não tenha muito controle do tempo que demorará.

Haverá **ganho de escala** em fazer alguma operação de IO longa na *action*.

> Posso perder desempenho?

Sim, o assincronismo não é grátis. Sempre que usá-lo terá uma perda de performance, [especialmente se usar *thread*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101). O ganho que ele dá é a execução concorrente, então você pode atender mais requisições. A requisição específica não ficará mais rápida em hipótese alguma.

Então tenha certeza que haverá algum ganho antes de usar este mecanismo.

> Em quais situações devo usar um ou outro, poderiam dar exemplos?

Acesso a banco de dados, sistema de arquivos, serviços diversos do servidor que faça IO, serviços externos ao servidor, especialmente pela internet, enfim qualquer IO que seja **longo**.

O assincronismo de IO pode liberar uma capacidade de atender mais requisições se feito adequadamente quando há ganho.

> Se tenho muitos usuários fazendo consulta em uma única página async com requisição ao banco de dados, isso não geraria uma fila grande dependendo do tempo de execução da aplicação? Como isso é gerenciado para não impedir as próximas de executarem?

Cada requisição à página é independente e isso já é algo bom para melhorar a escalabilidade.

A fila será gerada de acordo com a configuração do servidor HTTP. De que adianta não ter a fila no servidor HTTP e tê-la na sua aplicação ou na consulta ao banco de dados?

> O uso de métodos assíncronos evita ataques DDoS?

Tem casos que pode facilitar o DDoS. Aí é uma questão de saber fazer de forma que não cause mais problemas que soluções.

Se o cliente direto da sua aplicação é um servidor HTTP e a aplicação deixa ele atender mais requisições assincronamente, pode atolar a aplicação ou o banco de dados e acabar parando tudo. O problema é que o servidor HTTP é o seu cliente aí e ele consegue pedir muito, ao contrário de um usuário normal. Quando o cliente pode pedir mais que o serviço pode atender é um convite para o desastre.

O mesmo vale para qualquer outro recurso que faça IO e seja menos capaz que o servidor HTTP. Isso você tem que avaliar caso a caso. Claro que tem algumas formas de escalar o IO para atender toda demanda. Precisa avaliar se compensa ou é melhor ir por um caminho mais simples. Não tem regra única.

O aumento de escala faz com que o DDoS demore mais ou até seja evitado em ataques "fracos". Mas depois de um certo ponto é possível que o ganho de escala piore a situação porque transfere o problema para um local onde é mais difícil fazer *throttling*.

## Informações adicionais

Fazer a página no cliente (navegador) ser assíncrona é interessante em muitas situações porque permite que a página continue funcionando normalmente enquanto espera o retorno de uma requisição ao servidor. Mas você não pode garantir que a requisição será feita assincronamente. Vale sempre "a lei" que você [não pode confiar no cliente que você não tem total controle](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/101).

Estou falando só do ASP.NET MVC. Pode haver outras restrições em função das outras tecnologias envolvidas na operação.

Se quiser se aprofundar tem um [artigo na MSDN Magazine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/async-programming-introduction-to-async-await-on-asp-net?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Deveria dar pra escolher duas respostas, né? haha
Tanto a sua quanto a do @CiganoMorrisonMendez estão ótimas!! Obrigado!

Answer (score 9):

> Quando devo usar métodos assíncronos ou síncronos em controllers (Indice, pesquisa, deletar, criar) de aplicações ASP.NET MVC?

Em toda operação de entrada e saída ou operações cuja execução seja longa: acesso a bancos de dados, arquivos, serviços externos etc.

> Posso perder desempenho?

Pode, mas isso depende de como você está usando a operação. Por exemplo, usar `Thread.Run()` pra tudo não faz necessariamente a aplicação ficar mais rápida. O excesso do uso da *thread pool* é uma situação que pode ocasionar perda de desempenho.

> Em quais situações devo usar um ou outro, poderiam dar exemplos?

Você não citou Entity Framework como *tag*, mas é importante citá-lo como exemplo porque é muito comum o uso de Entity Framework com o ASP.NET MVC.

Em qualquer operação com o Entity Framework é recomendável o uso de operações assíncronas, justamente porque é uma operação de banco (seja seleção, inclusão, atualização ou exclusão), e que é, portanto, considerada uma operação longa.

Em chamadas a *web services* ou *endpoints* REST também é recomendado o uso de operações assíncronas. Nos exemplos pela internet, é fácil ver que só são usadas operações assíncronas para consumo de serviços. [Veja que a classe `HttpClient` não possui opção síncrona para métodos `Get`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx).

Já casos em que a execução deve ser assíncrona são todos aqueles cuja obtenção do resultado é imprescindível para a continuação da lógica do método a seguir. A exceção são escopos de transações a partir do .NET 4.5.1, em que [`TransactionScope`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx) ganhou a opção [`TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscopeasyncflowoption(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Se tenho muitos usuários fazendo consulta em uma única página `async` com requisição ao banco de dados, isso não geraria uma fila grande dependendo do tempo de execução da aplicação?
>
> Como isso é gerenciado para não impedir as próximas de executarem?

Depende. Em escopo assíncrono, a carga em paralelo é repassada para o banco de dados, caso a biblioteca em questão tenha o suporte assíncrono no C# (o *client* do SQL Server possui). O caso mais crítico que isso pode acontecer é em operações envolvendo escopo transacional e não houver contingenciamento para balancear a carga (ou, melhor dizendo, [Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684146(v=vs.85).aspx)).

Feito o bloqueio por escopo transacional, o coordenador de transação harmoniza as transações na ordem de chegada, seja para um único servidor de banco de dados, seja para um *cluster*.

> O uso de métodos assíncronos evita ataques DDoS?

Não. São duas coisas diferentes. DDoS é uma sobrecarga proposital ao servidor com o disparo de uma quantidade significativa de requisições em um curto espaço de tempo, afogando o servidor, se este servidor instancia memória para cada requisição atendida. Por ter como alvo a memória do servidor (memória primária), a utilização de métodos assíncronos ajuda, mas não evita o problema.

Para evitar DDoS, há duas formas:

1. Configurando pelo servidor;
2. Configurando pela aplicação, usando alguma biblioteca.

Pelo servidor, [é um pouco mais complexo](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/friis/2014/12/30/security-guidelines-to-detect-and-prevent-dos-attacks-targeting-iisazure-web-role-paas/), mas é um método mais completo. Envolve monitoramento constante e bloqueio de faixas de IPs.

Pela aplicação, você pode [usar o bandit](https://github.com/lebowitz/Bandit/). Tem NuGet. Ou [o método do Mads Kristensen](http://madskristensen.net/post/block-dos-attacks-easily-in-aspnet).

Answer (score 2):

Em minha avaliação, o uso de meios assíncronos traz complexidade que na maioria dos casos pode ser evitada, usando métodos síncronos.
Cada caso deve ser avaliado, sendo que vai depender muito de o desenvolvedor sentir-se seguro, pois deve dominar a técnica.
Há um excelente artigo (em inglês) que aborda o assunto:[Attack of the Killer Microseconds](https://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2017/4/215032-attack-of-the-killer-microseconds/fulltext)
O artigo destaca que o Google prefere usar programação síncrona, sempre que for possível e tentar deixar as tarefas assíncronas para o sistema operacional.

Comment: Mas para esse caso em específico (ASP.NET) você acha que traz complexidade? Pois criar métodos assíncronos ou síncronos é bem simples no código. Ou se refere a outro tipo de abordagem?

Comment: Veja, você deve avaliar bem a solução. A tendencia de soluções assíncronas é dificultar a identificação da origem de erros. Por isto muito cuidado deve ser dado aos tratamentos de falhas.

Comment: Esse é um ponto importante, apesar de colateral à pergunta. Se a pessoa não souber fazer, pode ter mais problemas que soluções. É muito comum isso ocorrer. Sempre deve procurar o mais simples antes.