# Chamando um Método assíncrono e síncrono

Tags: c#, asp.net, assincronismo, sincronização

Eu tenho um método síncrono, nele eu chamo um outro método de outra `controller` que teria que ser executado assíncrono.

Eu chamo este outro método desta forma:

```
Task.Run(() => _notificacaoController.NotificacaoIosTodos(titulo,
configuracaoItem.Posicao,unidade.UnidadeAtual));
```

Este é meu método:

```
  internal void NotificacaoIosTodos(string titulo, int posicao, int unidadeId)
    {
        try
        {
            var unidade = _contexto.Unidade.FirstOrDefault(l => l.UnidadeId == unidadeId);
            var pessoas = _contexto.PessoaUnidade.Include(l => l.Pessoa)
                .Where(l => l.Pessoa.Dispositivo == (int)enumDispositivo.Ios && l.UnidadeId == unidadeId)
                .ToList();
            foreach (PessoaUnidade pessoa in pessoas)
            {
                Notificacao notificacao = new Notificacao {Posicao = posicao};
                _contexto.Notificacao.Add(notificacao);
                _contexto.SaveChanges();
                PessoaNotificacao pessoaNotificacao = new PessoaNotificacao
                {
                    Visualizado = false,
                    PessoaUnidade = pessoa,
                    Notificacao = notificacao
                };
                _contexto.PessoaNotificacao.Add(pessoaNotificacao);
                _contexto.SaveChanges();
            }

            Push.EnviarTodos(unidade.OneSignalAuth, unidade.OneSignalId, titulo, posicao, unidade.Nome);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Eu coloquei o método inteiro, mas minha duvida é se o método está funcionando de forma assíncrona ou síncrona, o método `NotificacaoIosTodos` deveria estar marcado com `async` e usando`await`?

Dessa forma que ele esta agora ele já esta executando em uma outra `thread` de forma assíncrona?

Comment: Sim, da forma como ele está a ser usado(através de `Task.Run()`) ele será executado assincronamente. Em relação ao uso de `async` e `await` veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/19172/2541)

Comment: Eu tinha lido um pouco sobre o async and await, o problema e nesse caso igual ao meu que eu não sei se precisaria do async ou se o Task.run ()) faria ele ser assincrono mesmo chamando um metodo que nao esta marcado como async, vou ler a resposta daqui a pouco, muito obrigado pela dica.

Comment: O que torna a execução do método `NotificacaoIosTodos()` assíncrona é o uso de `Task.Run()`. A finalidade de `await` é facilitar a "integração/interação" de código assíncrono(Task's) com código síncrono, permitindo o código manter uma estrutura semelhante ao código síncrono.  `async` é necessário se quiser usar `await` num método.

Comment: Editei a pergunta com base no comentário do @ramaral que tem razão ao dizer que o que torna a execução do método `NotificacaoIosTodos()` assíncrona é o uso de `Task.Run()`. Coloquei o link da documentação que prova que o comentário dele está correto.

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann por anos a MS fez mal uso da palavra `asynchronous` na sua documentação, pois a mesma usou dela quando queria dizer `executar uma thread em background`.

Comment: @TobiasMesquita então a documentação está errada ao dizer que o trabalho será executado de forma assíncrona? Será apenas em uma thread? Alterei a resposta depois que vi isso na documentação.

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann dê uma olhada neste artigo: [Task.Run Etiquette Examples](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html) você vai entender um pouco melhor o funcionamento do `Task.Run`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Primeiro, vejo que está à confundir assincronismo com paralelismo, apesar dos dois estarem intimamente relacionados, um é bem diferente do outro.

Ao se programar de forma assíncrona, a tarefa deve disponibilizar um mecanismo de retorno, normalmente um *delegate* como no exemplo abaixo.

```
private delegate void NotificacaoIosTodos(string titulo, int posicao, int unidadeId);
public void MinhaAction()
{
    var argumentos = new object[] { titulo, configuracaoItem.Posicao, unidade.UnidadeAtual };
    var notificacao = new NotificacaoIosTodos(_notificacaoController.NotificacaoIosTodos, argumentos);
    notificacao.BeginInvoke(new AsyncCallback(NotificacoesCallback), notificacao);
}

public void NotificacoesCallback()
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

o exemplo acima o `NotificacoesCallback` será chamado assim que o `NotificacaoIosTodos` concluir, não alocando qualquer recurso adicional entre a chamada do `MinhaAction` e `NotificacoesCallback`.

Já o paralelismo tem a função de executar tarefas simultaneamente. Uma forma de se alcançar isto, é criar uma nova `Task`, lembrando que você pode ou não esperar pelo retorno da mesma.

```
public void MinhaAction()
{
    var notificacao = Task.Run(() => _notificacaoController.NotificacaoIosTodos(titulo, configuracaoItem.Posicao, unidade.UnidadeAtual));
    notificacao.Wait();
    DoSomething();
}
```

No exemplo acima, é criada uma nova `Task`. Ao chamar o `Wait` você estará bloqueando a `Thread` atual, então é bem provável que você esteja alocando mais recursos do que é necessário.

O cenário é algo que deve ser evitado, mas as condições abaixo podem trazer algum ganho.

**Exemplo 1**

```
public void MinhaAction()
{
    var notificacao = Task.Run(() => _notificacaoController.NotificacaoIosTodos(titulo, configuracaoItem.Posicao, unidade.UnidadeAtual));
    // DoSomething1 é executado ao mesmo tempo que NotificacaoIosTodos;
    DoSomething1();
    // Aqui a Thread atual é bloqueada até a conclusão de NotificacaoIosTodos
    notificacao.Wait();
    // Por fim é executado DoSomething2
    DoSomething2();
}
```

**Exemplo 2**

```
public void MinhaAction()
{
    var notificacoes = new Task[10];
    for (var posicao = 0; posicao < notificacoes.Length; posicao++)
        notificacoes[posicao] = Task.Run(() => _notificacaoController.NotificacaoIosTodos(titulo, posicao, unidade.UnidadeAtual));
    // As 10 notificações serão executadas em paralelo enquanto a Thread atual é bloqueada.
    Task.WaitAll(notificacoes);
    // Por fim é executado DoSomething2
    DoSomething();
}
```

Agora vamos voltar ao **assicronismo** no caso utilizando as palavras reservadas `async/await`

```
public async Task MinhaAction()
{
    await _notificacaoController.NotificacaoIosTodos(titulo, configuracaoItem.Posicao, unidade.UnidadeAtual);
    DoSomething();
}

internal async Task NotificacaoIosTodos(string titulo, int posicao, int unidadeId)
{
    await ConsultaBancoDeDados();
}
```

No exemplo acima, uma nova *thread* não será criada. Ao se chamar `NotificacaoIosTodos` ela será sincronizada dentro do contexto atual. Este comportamento é bastante util quanto precisamos fazer alguma operação de I/O, como ler um arquivo ou consultar o banco de dados.

Por um outro lado, se vamos fazer alguma operação *CPU Bound*, então é interessante  que este processo rode em uma *Thread* separada enquanto a *Thread* principal é liberada, para tal fazemos uso do `Task.Run`.

```
public async Task MinhaAction()
{
    await Task.Run(() => _notificacaoController.NotificacaoIosTodos(titulo, configuracaoItem.Posicao, unidade.UnidadeAtual));
    DoSomething();
}

internal async Task NotificacaoIosTodos(string titulo, int posicao, int unidadeId)
{
    await CalcularHashCemMilVezes();
}
```

agora um pequeno exemplo combinando **assincronismo** com **paralelismo**:

```
public async Task MinhaAction()
{
    var notificacoes = new Task[10];
    for (var posicao = 0; posicao < notificacoes.Length; posicao++)
        notificacoes[posicao] = _notificacaoController.NotificacaoIosTodos(titulo, posicao, unidade.UnidadeAtual);
    // As 10 notificações serão executadas em paralello enquanto a Thread atual é bloqueada.
    await Task.WhenAll(notificacoes);
    // Por fim é executado DoSomething2
    DoSomething();
}

internal async Task NotificacaoIosTodos(string titulo, int posicao, int unidadeId)
{
    await ConsultaBancoDeDados();
}
```

E quanto ao `async void`, evite utilizá-lo, a menos que o método seja um método *fire and forget*, como um `evento` ou um método que a sua conclusão não é esperada por outro método (como um envio de email).

E por fim, apesar do `Task.Run` não tornar a execução assíncrona, é possivel utilizar o método `ContinueWith` para adicionar um mecanismo de retorno para a `Task`.

```
public async Task MinhaAction()
{
    var notificacao = await Task.Run(() => _notificacaoController.NotificacaoIosTodos(titulo, configuracaoItem.Posicao, unidade.UnidadeAtual));
    notificacao.ContinueWith(task => {
        // task.Result possui o retorno de NotificacaoIosTodos
        DoSomething(task.Result);
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);      
    notificacao.ContinueWith(task => {
        LogarErro(task.Exception.Message);
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
}

internal async Task<bool> NotificacaoIosTodos(string titulo, int posicao, int unidadeId)
{
    return await ConsultaBancoDeDados();
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, me esclareceu muita coisa . Eu realmente estava confundindo Assincronismo com paralelismo!! Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

> Eu coloquei o metodo inteiro mas minha duvida e sobre a sincronicidade
>   desse metodo, o metodo NotificacaoIosTodos deveria estar marcado com
>   async e usandoawait ?

Se vai usar ele como assíncrono ou síncrono a [escolha é sua](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/201998/quando-usar-m%C3%A9todo-ass%C3%ADncronos-ou-s%C3%ADncronos).

> Dessa forma que ele esta agora ele já esta executando em uma outra
>   thread de forma asincrona ?

Sim, o método está sendo executado de forma assíncrona. Além disso, ele executa em uma Thread.

Mas, de forma contrária, uma chamada assíncrona não necessariamente cria um novo Thread.

Para utilizar como `async` precisará muda-lo como no exemplo abaixo:

```
internal void async NotificacaoIosTodos(string titulo, int posicao, int unidadeId)
{
  ...
}
```

E na chamada use `await`, exemplo:

```
await Task.Run(() => _notificacaoController.NotificacaoIosTodos(titulo,
configuracaoItem.Posicao, unidade.UnidadeAtual));
```

No entanto o [Task.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx) já torna o trabalho assíncrono.

Comment: A minha intenção é executa-lo asincrono,  eu fico em duvida em como usar o await nesse caso, eu usaria quando fosse chamar o método ? tipo  await Task.run(() =>  ??

Comment: Exatamente isso @WilliamCézar. Eu vou melhorar essa resposta assim que tiver tempo pra você entender melhor o uso nesse caso com o `Task.run`.

Comment: Ok, uma outra duvida e que estou chamando esse metodo apartir de um metodo normal, no caso quando eu tentar usar o await ele vai pedir para marcar esse metodo com async tbm certo ?  no caso os dois teria que estar marcados como async?

Comment: Muito obrigado pela paciência em intender minha pergunta, ajudou muito.