# Async/Await com threads (C# 7.2)

Tags: c#, .net, desempenho, multithreading, async-await

Tenho esse código e como podem notar criei dois exemplos, Parallel e NotParallel.

Esperava que ambos me retornassem 3000ms, pois ambos deveriam rodar async (2000 e 3000) e o tempo total seria 3000, porém o NonParallel, está demorando 5000ms, onde é a soma dos dois, parecendo que um espera o outro para terminar.. mesmo estando async.

```
static class Program
{
    static async Task<string> GetTaskAsync(int timeout)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Task Thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        await Task.Delay(timeout);
        return timeout.ToString();
    }

    static async Task Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main Thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        Console.WriteLine("Should be greater than 5000");
        await Watch(NotParallel);
        Console.WriteLine("Should be less than 5000");
        await Watch(Parallel);
    }

    public static async Task Parallel()
    {
        var res1 = GetTaskAsync(2000);
        var res2 = GetTaskAsync(3000);

        Console.WriteLine("result: " + await res1 + await res2);
    }

    public static async Task NotParallel()
    {
        var res1 = await GetTaskAsync(2000);
        var res2 = await GetTaskAsync(3000);

        Console.WriteLine("result: " + res1 + res2);
    }

    private static async Task Watch(Func<Task> func) {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        await func?.Invoke();

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine("---------------");
    }
}
```

Exemplo do Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quer explicar em como `Parallel()` e `NotParallel()` são diferentes?

Comment: Dê mais detalhes do que ocorre, e o que está esperando que acontece. veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101 para entender que paralelizar não garante melhor desempenho, na verdade o desempenho costuma ser até pior, só termina antes nos casos que é o correto, Talvez isto já responda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/201998/101 Também pode ser útil: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175304/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/157440/101 Por fim, como sabe que está em paralelo? Eu acho que não está: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166032/101

Comment: @Maniero Estou errado ao dizer que os dois métodos terão um comportamento idêntico e que não se pode pressupor que um "é paralelo" e o outro " é não paralelo"? Ops não vi que editou o comentário.

Comment: @ramaral, dont see the names of the methods.

Comment: @alerya Está a ser sarcástico, certo?(*You're being sarcastic, right?*) :)

Comment: vou editar aqui e por o resultado @Maniero para exemplificar melhor!

Comment: @ramaral exatamente, queria entender pq o comportamento dos dois são diferentes?

Comment: Yeppers - why one is faster than other ?

Comment: @ramaral o alerya é um amigo da Ukrania e nós estamos discutindo esse assunto, e resolvi postar aqui no PT tb. Trabalhamos aqui no mesmo país.

Comment: Agora que vi o resultado entendo o que quer perguntar. Reformule a pergunta porque ela dá(me deu) entender que você esperava resultados bem diferentes mas obtinha resultados próximos.

Comment: @ramaral editei lá, se você se sentir confortável, pode editar também e colocar algo que tem  em mente na pergunta para me ajudar :)

Comment: Agora penso que está bem e compreendo a razão da pergunta. Vendo esse código, sem ver o resultado, diria que os dois métodos teriam um tempo de execução aproximado.

Comment: Eu não sei responder agora, nunca entendi por completo sobre o Async, mas achei a questão interessante, hoje não tenho tempo para parar e pensar, testar, por isso espero que alguém responda, senão tentarei ver semana que vem, pode me cobrar. E de fato agora dá para entender a real questão.

Comment: @Maniero obrigado pelo feedback, realmente eu e o alerya gastamos um tempo e resolvemos perguntar aos gurus aqui :)

Comment: @ramaral preciso analisar melhor ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Um erro comum é pensar que assincronismo é sinónimo de paralelismo.
O uso de `async` também nem sempre é bem compreendido.

Usar `async`, só por si, não torna o método(o código que executa) assíncrono. `async` apenas permite que seja usada a palavra `await`.
O que permite que determinado código seja executado assincronamente é a Task.

O uso conjunto de [async/await](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/index#BKMK_AsyncandAwait) permite [escrever/misturar](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/index#BKMK_WhatHappensUnderstandinganAsyncMethod) código síncrono e assíncrono de forma sequencial.
Cada linha de código é executado sequencialmente, quando é encontrada uma linha com `await` a execução do método é suspensa e a execução é retornada para o código chamador. Quando a operação assíncrona termina, a execução é retomada na linha seguinte e prossegue de forma sequencial.

Essa má compreensão faz que seja usado `async` em métodos onde não é necessário:

```
private async Task<Resultado> MetodoAsync()
{
    ....
    ....
    return await opAsync();
}
```

Só há necessidade de usar `await` se, naquele método, necessitar de fazer algo com o resultado e/ou após a operação assíncrona terminar.
Se não for o caso, não use `async`, apenas retorne a Task.

```
private Task<Resultado> Metodo()
{
    ....
    ....
    return OpAsync();
}
```

Quando estiver preparado para lidar com o resultado, então sim, use `async/await`

Dito isso, analisemos cada um dos métodos:

- NotParallel()

  Cada uma das chamadas a `GetTaskAsync()` é feita com `await`. Ao executar a primeira chamada(`GetTaskAsync(2000)`) a execução é libertada(o método retorna de imediato), ficado à espera que ela termine para depois prosseguir com a segunda chamada(`GetTaskAsync(3000)`).
  Ou seja, `GetTaskAsync(3000)` só é chamado após `GetTaskAsync(2000)` ter terminado.
- Parallel()

  Como não é usado `wait` na chamada a `GetTaskAsync()` as chamadas são executadas imediatamente uma a seguir à outra sendo as tasks executadas em "paralelo"(lei-a simultâneo).

Simplifiquei o código para tentar mostrar que o "paralelismo" tem, neste caso, apenas a ver com os momentos(instantes) em que cada chamada a `GetTaskAsync()` é feita.
Nesta situação(*console application*) apenas o método `GetTaskAsync()` precisa de ser declarado `async`.
Ele é o único que necessita de libertar a execução para permitir que possa ser novamente chamado, no método `Parallel()`, antes de terminar a anterior chamada.

```
static class Program
{
    static async Task<string> GetTaskAsync(int timeout)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Task Thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        await Task.Delay(timeout);
        return timeout.ToString();
    }

    private static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main Thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        Console.WriteLine("Should be greater than 5000");
        Watch(NotParallel);
        Console.WriteLine("Should be less than 5000");
        Watch(Parallel);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void Parallel()
    {
        var res1 = GetTaskAsync(2000);
        var res2 = GetTaskAsync(3000);

        Console.WriteLine("result: " + res1.Result + " " + res2.Result);
    }

    public static void NotParallel()
    {
        var res1 = GetTaskAsync(2000).Result;
        var res2 = GetTaskAsync(3000).Result;

        Console.WriteLine("result: " + res1 + " " + res2);
    }

    private static void Watch(Action func)
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        func();

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine("---------------");
    }
}
```

Comment: Preciso analisar melhor, mas acho que é por aí.

Answer (score 6):

A soma no `NotParalel()` é justamente por que você está esperando uma execução terminar para depois executar a próxima e por fim retornar, por conta do `await`.

```
public static async Task NotParallel()
{
    //A atribuição de res1 deve esperar o resultado de GetTaskAsync()
    var res1 = await GetTaskAsync(2000);

    //Somente depois de res1 receber sua atribuição a de res2 deve esperar
    // o novo GetTaskAsync(3000)
    var res2 = await GetTaskAsync(3000);

    //Logo o resultado será no mínimo 5000ms porque ele parou as duas vezes
    Console.WriteLine("result: " + res1 + res2);
}
```

Agora na paralela, veja a diferença:

```
public static async Task Parallel()
{
    //Dispara a atribuição de assíncrona de res1 e segue a execução
    var res1 = GetTaskAsync(2000);

    //Dispara a atribuição assíncrona de res2 e segue a execução
    var res2 = GetTaskAsync(3000);

    //Agora essa linha espera até que res1 e res2 tenham recebido
    //suas atribuições e como a maior espera é de res2, res1 já terá
    //recebido a sua antes e o tempo total de espera é de apenas 3000ms 
    Console.WriteLine("result: " + await res1 + await res2);
}
```

É justamente por isso que um método é denominado como paralelo e a outra não. Essa é a diferença no tempo de execução entre os dois e aí que você começará a dar a devida importância ao paralelismo e programação assíncrona para obter a melhor performance em tempo nas suas aplicações.

Para aprofundar melhor no assunto você pode consultar as recomendações da própria Microsoft para esse tipo e implementação no C#.

[Programação assíncrona com Async e Await (C# e Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh191443(v=vs.120).aspx)

[Programação assíncrona baseada em tarefas](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming)

Comment: Acho que é por aí mesmo, analiso melhor depois.