# Como funciona concorrência em um único thread com C#

Tags: c#, async

Esta é uma pergunta meramente didática.

Estou tentando entender como o modelo de concorrência funciona em C#, especificamente ao utilizar o modificador async.

Venho do JavaScript, e entendo que no modelo do JS, concorrência é possível graças ao event-loop. Nesse modelo temos um loop principal, em que todos os procedimentos são colocados numa fila. Quando chega a vez de um procedimento dessa fila ser executado, se ele estiver num estado de pendente, ele é empurrado para o final da fila, dessa maneira outros procedimentos podem ser executados sem que o processo principal entre num estado ocioso.

O que acontece é que o código é executado alternadamente, eis o exemplo que tenho:

```js
async function main() {
  var promise1 = loop();
  var promise2 = loop();
  
  await promise1;
  await promise2;
}

async function loop() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    await null;
  }
}

main();
```

async e await não são funcionalidades exclusiva do JavaScript, porém outras linguagens que implementam essa funcionalidade nem sempre rodam nativamente num event-loop. Em Python por exemplo quando uma função async é invocada, ela apenas retorna uma co-rotina, que precisa ser colocada num event-loop criado pelo programador com `asyncio.run`, para então ser executada.

---

Mas em C# eu noto que a maneira que ele se comporta é um pouco diferente comparado com JavaScript ou Python. Utilizando o seguinte código como exemplo:

```
public static void Main()
{
    AsyncMain().Wait();
}

public static async Task AsyncMain()
{
    var task1 = Loop();
    var task2 = Loop();

    await task1;
    await task2;
}

public static async Task Loop()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        await Task.Delay(1);
    }
}
```

A primeira coisa que noto, é que apesar de C# não rodar num event-loop nativamente, em nenhum momento eu estou criando meu próprio event-loop. Outro aspecto que só é possível notar rodando o código, é que ele não irá imprimir no console exatamente alternadamente como faria em JavaScript ou em Python, ao invés de imprimir `0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4`, ele irá imprimir algo como `0 0 1 2 1 3 2 4 3 4`.

O que está acontecendo aqui?

- O C# cria seu próprio event-loop implicitamente, ou ele funciona com outro modelo?
- Por que em C# a fila de procedimentos não parece ser um processo determinístico?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Async/Await com threads (C# 7.2)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/292825/async-await-com-threads-c-7-2)

Comment: Há várias perguntas sobre o tema no SOpt. Tente fazer uma pesquisa para ver se a sua dúvida é sanada. [A MS tem um guia que acho muito interessante, mas está em inglês.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

Answer (score 4):

Boa tarde Júlio

De fato existem diferenças.
O .Net funciona baseado em ThreadPool e este possui uma fila global no modelo FIFO.
Dependendo do tamanho dessa fila global, mais threads vão sendo levantadas para dar vazão (Se você estiver utilizando dotnet core, uma forma legal de visualizar isso ao vivo é utilizando *dotnet-counters* [https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-counters]).

A partir do CLR 4, cada Thread passou a ter também uma fila própria no modelo LIFO.
Dependendo da forma que a Thread puxa aquela tarefa, a mesma pode ir ou não para a fila da Thread (vou mandar um link explicando mais sobre isso). Mas é interessante que, quando uma thread tem alguma tarefa travando sua fila, outra thread que está desocupada pode roubar a próxima tarefa da thread travada (lembrando que ela vai receber essa task no modelo LIFO), para ajudar a dar vazão.
Entendo que é por isso que você não tem muito controle sobre a ordem em que as coisas são executadas no modelo async.

Vou mandar algumas fontes interessantes:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/
- http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/New-And-Improved-CLR-4-Thread-Pool-Engine.aspx
- https://labs.criteo.com/2018/10/net-threadpool-starvation-and-how-queuing-makes-it-worse/