# Programação assíncrona C#

Tags: c#, assincronismo

De que forma a minha aplicação iria se comportar em um cenário onde realizo uma consulta assíncrona no banco de dados e logo em seguida manipulo o valor retornado? A aplicação iria aguardar a consulta ser finalizada ou iria continuar o fluxo de execução normalmente?

```
int id = await GetById();

if (id == 20)
   ...
```

Comment: [Veja essa questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/201998/35358). Pode esclarecer mais alguma coisa pra você. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Respondendo sua pergunta, a aplicação vai esperar o retorno da sua função sem bloquear o fluxo do programa.

Você usa um `await` quando na declaração do seu método possui a palavra-chave `async` deixando explícito para a aplicação que ela deve esperar o resultado em "segundo plano".

Você pode encontrar mais informações e referências aqui:

[Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh191443(v=vs.140))