# Converter Blob em String no angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, file-upload, blob

Olá, estou com um código em angularJS porém só funciona quando estou no debug do browser.

```
    $scope.upload=function(){
        var newFiles = []; 
        $scope.carregando = true;
        angular.forEach($scope.files, function (item) {
            if(item.upload){
                item.idFicha = vm.ficha.id;
                var reader  = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(item._file);

                //TODO Quero recuperar a substring do result.
                item.arquivo = reader.result.substr(reader.result.indexOf(',') + 1);

                newFiles.push(item);
                item.upload = false;
            }
        });
        service.uploadDocumento(newFiles);
        $scope.carregando = false;
    };
```

Bem, quando tiro o *breakpoint* para executar a função a variável **item.arquivo** fica nula, mas se eu colocar o *breakpoint* e inspecionar a variável é está com valor e a função funcionar perfeitamente.

O que pode estar acontecendo e o que devo fazer para dar fim nesse problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acontece que a *API* `FileReader` carrega os dados de forma [assíncrona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51268/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ass%C3%ADncrona-e-s%C3%ADncrona), isso quer dizer que o código continuará sendo processado, mesmo que uma determinada função ainda não esteja completa, ou seja, o código não espera uma determinada linhar "terminar seu trabalho".

Quando temos uma função assíncrona, nós também temos alguns eventos disponíveis. No caso do `FileReader`, os eventos são:

- `abort`: Será chamado quando o procedimento for abortado;
- `error`: Será chamado quando houver algum erro;
- `load`: Será chamado quando o arquivo for carregado;
- `loadstart`: Será chamado no início do carregamento do arquivo;
- `loadend`: Será chamado no final do carregamento do arquivo;
- `progress`: Será chamado durante o carregamento do arquivo.

No seu caso, você terá que adicionar toda a regra do seu código na função `load`, por exemplo:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input");

input.addEventListener("change", () => {
  for (let file of input.files) {

    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.addEventListener("load", result => {
      console.log( `Teste #2: ${reader.result}` )
    })
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    console.log( `Teste #1: ${reader.result}` )
  }

});
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple />
```

Como eu citei, o `FileReader` não espera o arquivo ser carregado para poder continuar o processamento restante do código, porém quando adicionamos um `breakpoint`, nós forçarmos essa "pausa". Isso é o tempo necessário para que o `FileReader` possa ler o arquivo e já armazenar na propriedade `result`.