# AngularJS ng-repeat não exibe os dados

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, laravel

Fiz a requisição via get utilizando o laravel como backend. Porem, se eu atualizo algum dado no proprio banco de dados, eu preciso dar um refresh na pagina onde esta carregado o angular para ele atualizar.
Utilizando o angular, ela nao teria que atualizar automaticamente?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>


<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="t in teste">
        <td>{{t.id}}</td>
        <td>{{t.total}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>    
</div>


<script>


var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("//localhost:8000/angular")
  .then(function(response) {        
      $scope.teste = response.data;
      console.log($scope.teste);



  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O que sai aqui? `console.log($scope.teste);`

Comment: Sai a requisiçao via get normal. (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0
:
{id: 1, quantidade_produtos: 2, total: 3, created_at: null, updated_at: null, …}
1
:
{id: 2, quantidade_produtos: 3, total: 55, created_at: null, updated_at: null, …}
2
:
{id: 3, quantidade_produtos: 4, total: 50, created_at: null, updated_at: null, …}
3
:
{id: 4, quantidade_produtos: 5, total: 60, created_at: null, updated_at: null, …}
length
:
4
__proto__
:
Array(0

Comment: Eu consigo exibir no {{t.id}} e t.{{total}}, porem se eu atualizo os dados no banco, ele nao atualiza na view. Tem que dar F5

Comment: Isso porque você não esta fazendo requisições em intervalos, você só esta fazendo a requisição ao abrir pela primeira vez, então se quer que atualize, utilize [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

Comment: Mas ele não devia trabalhar de forma assincrona com meu backend? Não estou entendendo..

Comment: Veja: [Como programação assíncrona funciona em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16950) e [Qual a diferença entre comunicação assíncrona e síncrona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51268)

Comment: Assíncrono não é reativo. Talvez você esteja confundindo os dois conceitos? A reatividade no angularjs (e demais frameworks reativos js) limita-se ao front-end.

Comment: A sim, entendi. Obrigado.