# Javascript: Função não está retornando o valor correto

Tags: javascript, json, return

O que pode estar de errado nessa função? Onde está o `alert`, está vindo o resultado correto, mas está retornando 0.

```
function AprovaCotacao(numForn) {
    var forn_aprovado = $("#cot_fornecedor" + numForn).val();
    var id = $("#cot_id").val();
    var url = host + "/cotacoes/Aprovar";
    var result = 0;

    $.ajax({
        url: url
        , data: { id: id, idFornecedor: forn_aprovado, numAprovado: numForn }
        , type: "GET"
        , dataType: "json"
        , contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        , success: function (data) {
            if (data.mensagem == '') {
                result = data.pedido;
                alert(result);
            }
            else {
                result = -1;
                alert(data.mensagem);
            }
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Resultado do json: `{"mensagem":"","pedido":46}`.

Comment: Tem dois `alert` aí, pode explicar melhor?

Comment: o alert que mostra a variável result alert(result);
está retornando o código correto: 46, porém quando chamo a função fica sempre 0

Comment: Luciano a melhor forma de resolver isto é entender o que é e como funciona assincrono e que querer forçar sincrono em JavaScript é desnecessário e provavelmente é porque você ainda não entende muito bem o comportamento de callback e assincrono em JS, recomendo os links: **1.** https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45706/3635 / **2.** https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16950/3635 **3.** https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51268/3635

Comment: Eu tenho uma noção, mas vou dar uma aprofundada no assunto. Obrigado!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Tinha certeza que era duplicata, mas não tinha encontrado a pergunta anterior.

Comment: @VictorStafusa tem mais umas 3 assim, até com respostas melhores, mas esta muito complicado achar, ainda mais porque se me recordo os titulos são coisas como: "problema com ajax", "erro no ajax" e "ajax não funciona", ai fica impossivel encontrar :/

Answer (score 0):

A chamada `$.ajax(...)` é assíncrona. Ou seja, ela não vai fazer a chamada imediatamente, e sim postar uma requisição para que seja feita. A execução do Javascript vai então encontrar o `return result;` e retornar zero. Só depois disso é que a chamada AJAX vai acontecer, mas aí, ao definir o valor da variável `result`, já será tarde demais.

Comment: Entendi, mas eu li que é contra indicado deixar a chamada síncrona, desta forma, qual seria a melhor forma de resolver esse problema?

Comment: @Luciano Isso depende de qual função está chamando a sua `AprovaCotacao` e o que ela está fazendo com o resultado. Sugiro editar a pergunta para incluir isso.