# Python - Como construir uma boa função para verificar se há internet?

Tags: python-3.x

A ideia é construir uma pequena função para verificar se há conexão com a internet. Tenho um rascunho de uma função que usa a biblioteca `socket`, mas acredito que não seja a maneira mais eficiente e nem a que melhor respeita as boas práticas de programação.

```
from socket import gethostbyname,create_connection

# Verifica se esta conectado a internet
def conectadoInternet():

    tentativas = 0
    servidorRemoto = 'www.google.com.br'

    while tentativas < 3:
        if tentativas == 1:
            servidorRemoto = 'www.lds.org'
        elif tentativas == 2:
            servidorRemoto = 'www.msn.com'

        try:
            host = gethostbyname(servidorRemoto)
            s = create_connection((host, 80), 2)
            return True
        except: tentativas += 1

    return False
```

Quais seriam outras melhores maneiras?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Não há só uma resposta correta**
>
> Primeiro deve-se entender o que significa **internet**, no conceito de sua aplicação/programa.
> Daí, implementar aplicações para verificar pelos serviços (qualidade e banda) que lhe são importantes, nos padrões aceitáveis. <sup>[1](https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-check-if-there-is-an-internet-connection-using-a-Python-script)</sup>

Aqui, creio que nos atemos a falar sobre [soluções síncronas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51268/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ass%C3%ADncrona-e-s%C3%ADncrona), como a sua.

[Saídas assíncronas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110593/asynchronous-requests-with-python-requests) podem ser mais interessantes, principalmente para *scripts*.

**Acho a sua solução uma das melhores**, ainda que uma lista contendo os *hosts* seja preferível, essa deve ter uma **boa performance** em tempo de execução. <sup>[4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33117579/10707951)</sup>

Mas não vejo também problema com:

```
import os
is_connected = (os.system('nc -z 8.8.8.8 53') == 0)
```

Ou [usando requests](https://gist.github.com/yasinkuyu/aa505c1f4bbb4016281d7167b8fa2fc2).. <sup>[6](http://docs.python-requests.org/pt_BR/latest/)</sup> <sup>[7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24460981/10707951)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Olá, você pode usar o seguinte código que tenta uma conexão com o IP do google, caso o ip não funcione, é só usar o comando ping e a url do google para conseguir um ip atualizado

```
import urllib2

def internet_on():
    try:
        urllib2.urlopen('http://216.58.192.142', timeout=1)
        return True
    except urllib2.URLError as err: 
        return False
```