# Existe diferença entre Programa, Thread e Processo?

Tags: thread, terminologia, processo

Eu gostaria de saber se existe diferença entre **Thread**, **Processo** e **Programa**?

Essas três palavras são muito utilizadas na área de Tecnologia da Informação, portanto, seria interessante saber a diferença entre cada uma delas caso existir, e também o conceito de cada uma.

O que eu entendo é que qualquer instrução ou sequencias de instruções, pode ser chamado de *programa*, veja este código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        char str[13] = "Stackoverflow";
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < 13; i++)
                printf("%c", str[i]);

        return 0;
}
```

Saída:

> Stackoverflow

Logo poderia ser considerado um *programa*, cuja a função é exibir a palavra `Stackoverflow` no console.

Agora um código um pouco mais complexo de um *programa* que executa varias *threads*, veja:

```
#ifdef __unix__
# include <unistd.h>
#elif defined _WIN32
# include <windows.h>
#define sleep(x) Sleep(1000 * x)
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct valor
{
        int tempo;
        int id;
};

void *espera(void *tmp)
{
        struct valor *v = (struct valor *) tmp;
        sleep(v->tempo);
        printf("Ola, eu sou a thread %d esperei %d segundos antes de executar.\n", v->id, v->tempo);
}

int main(void)
{
        pthread_t linhas[10];
        int execute, i;
        struct valor *v;
        srand(time(NULL));

        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
                v = (struct valor *) malloc(sizeof(struct valor *));
                v->tempo = (rand() % 10) + 2;
                v->id = i;

                printf("Criei a thread <%d> com tempo <%d>\n", i, v->tempo);

                execute = pthread_create(&linhas[i], NULL, espera, (void *)v);
        }

        pthread_exit(NULL);

        return 0;
}
```

Saída:

> Criei a thread <0> com tempo <8>
>   Criei a thread <1> com tempo <7>
>   Criei a thread <2> com tempo <8>
>   Ola, eu sou a thread 1 esperei 7 segundos antes de executar.
>   Ola, eu sou a thread 2 esperei 8 segundos antes de executar.
>   Ola, eu sou a thread 0 esperei 8 segundos antes de executar.

O exemplo acima é um *programa*, porém tem como tarefe criar varias *threads*, logo essas *threads* podem ser consideradas *processos* ou o *programa* todo pode ser considerado apenas um *processo*? Não consigo entender o sentido de cada palavra, e estou confuso ao que cada uma representa.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Programa

O programa é o que já está definido na pergunta. Em geral um programa gera um executável que pode ser chamado diretamente ou através de outros executáveis (bom, na verdade a chamada inicial não deixa por um executável do sistema operacional).

Programa é uma sequência de instruções codificadas (escritas) a serem executadas pelo computador. *Thread* é uma sequência de instruções sendo executadas. Propositalmente não falarei de processo aqui.

Nesse contexto talvez programa esteja sendo usado como sinônimo de executável.

## Processo

Todo executável chamado diretamente rodará em um processo. Executáveis chamados dentro de um processo podem rodar explicitamente em outro processo ou no mesmo processo (quando isso for possível), em geral usando uma DLL.

O processo é controlado pelo sistema operacional tanto o tempo de processador que ele tem à disposição quanto à memória disponível (que pode ir sendo solicitada pelo processo). Além, é claro, de permissões de acesso a outros recursos que ficam vinculados ao processo como um todo.

Um processo tem um espaço de endereçamento de memória virtual só para ele. É como se ele rodasse sozinho no computador. Claro que isso não ocorre na realidade, mas ele se comporta como se fosse. Mas isso é outro assunto. O mesmo executável pode rodar em vários processos.

## *Thread*

A/O *thread* se assemelha ao processo porque ele tem uma nova linha de execução (e tudo que está relacionado a isto) e o sistema operacional o trata de forma igual ao processo para alocação de tempo de processamento. Mas em termos de memória é responsabilidade da aplicação controlar o acesso compartilhado por todo o processo.

É comum que as aplicações possuam uma *stack* para cada *thread*, mas apenas um (já vi casos de ter mais que um) espaço de *heap* para todo processo. Por isso costuma-se dizer que é complicado programar com *threads*, compartilhar estado é difícil. *Threads* estão vinculadas ao processo, até porque o processo principal em si não deixa de ser uma *thread*.

Algumas aplicações possuem um controle próprio de *threads* internas não controladas pelo processador/sistema operacional. Isso tem algumas vantagens (principalmente evitar troca de contexto do sistema operacional que é algo relativamente caro) e desvantagens (principalmente não podem usar outros processadores). Costumam ser chamadas de *soft*, *light* ou *green threads*.

## Diferença

Então dependendo de como se analisa, *thread* pode ser considerado equivalente a um processo ou não. Do ponto de vista de agendamento do processador podemos considerar que só existem *threads*. Simplificadamente, do ponto de vista de gerenciamento de memória e acesso aos recursos externos só existe o processo.

| Feature | Processo | Thread |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Execução | Linha própria | Linha própria |
| Memória global (heap e data segmnent) | Própria | Compartilhada |
| Memória local (stack, registers, PCounter) | Sim | Geralmente |
| Consumo de memória | Normal | Ligeiramente menor |
| Manipuladores de recursos externos | Proprietário | Empresta do processo |
| Tempo de criação | Relativamente longo | Relativamente curto |
| Tempo de troca de contexto | Relativamente longo | Relativamente curto |
| Instâncias | Múltiplas | Múltiplas |
| Associação | Um programa (executável) | Um processo |
| Paralelismo | Limitado | Sim |
| Comunicação entre seus pares | Só com um mecanismo de IPC | Sim, dentro do processo |
| Eficiência de comunicação | Não | Sim |
| Comunicação direta com o OS | Sim | Não |
| Controle de exceções | Próprio | Próprio |
| Confiabilidade e segurança | Sim | Depende do código |

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito legal essa tabela.

Comment: Estou estudando sobre Threads, e, pude perceber como é bem complicado trabalhar com elas, como não existe uma sequência de execução das operações, essa responsabilidade fica por conta do programador gerenciar. Mas pelo que percebi através da explicação, se o programador não tiver domínio do assunto o programa está sujeito a apresentar muitos bugs.

Comment: @DiegoFarias em geral não é necessário ter uma ordem, mas nos casos que precisa não costuma ser o caso de usar *threads*. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101. Os piores *bugs* são os causados por compartilhamento de estado entre *threads*, principalmente http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101

Comment: @bigown, pelo que entendi. É mais vantajoso criar multi-threads quando existem processos distintos para serem executados e não sequenciais, como no exemplo de fibonacci citado, porém, o tempo que o processador leva para fazer as trocas de contexto ou revezamento entre as threads, tem que ser mínimo, se comparado ao processamento geral que será executado no processo. A ideia é essa mesmo ?

Comment: @DiegoFarias basicamente isso. Fibonacci realmente não dá. Note que o grosso do que pode ser multithread pode ser multiprocesso :) Poder não quer dizer que deva.

Answer (score 4):

Um programa consiste num conjunto de instruções que você elabora para atingir determinado objectivo. Ou seja o programa consiste essencialmente no código fonte.

Uma thread é um componente responsável por executar as instruções que você elaborou no seu programa. O processador executa sempre instruções no contexto duma thread.

Depois de elaborar um programa você normalmente obtém um executável, que resulta do processo de compilação do seu programa.
Um processo, é um componente do sistema operativo que corre esse mesmo executável.

Um processo pode ser composto por várias threads. A criação das threads faz parte da especificação do programa, você teve que chamar `pthread_create` para criar essas mesmas threads.

Answer (score 2):

**Programa**: é uma entidade estática e permanente, composto apenas por uma sequência de instruções. Exemplo: O MS-DOS, um programa em execução não é processo, pois o MS-DOS é um S.O monousuário e todos os recursos estão disponíveis apenas para um programa.

**Processo**: é uma entidade dinâmica, que altera seu estado à medida que avança sua execução. Assim, o processo pode ser encarado como uma abstração que representa um programa em execução. Um processo contém um único fluxo de controle e é composto por programa, dados e contexto. Resumindo: Um processo é um programa em execução, somado ao seu contexto.

**Threads**: É um processo com múltiplos fluxos de controle.

Answer (score 0):

Contribuindo:

**Process Control Block**: um **PCB** é uma estrutura criada pelo sistema operacional para gerenciar os processos que estão em execução. O PCB é constituído de 3 grandes áreas: *contexto de hardware*, uma cópia dos registradores do processador do processo, *contexto de software*, informações sobre o processo (owner, id, data criação, etc.) e *espaço de endereçamento*, a área de memória RAM a que o processo tem acesso.

**Programa**: um arquivo executável, geralmente gravado em disco, e que deve ser carregado em memória RAM para que possa ser executado pelo sistema operacional. Basicamente um programa fonte compilado para o sistema operacional específico.

**Processo**: um programa em execução. Depois de carregado, um **programa** torna-se um **processo** gerenciado pelo sistema operacional. Um programa pode criar novos processos, através de um comando (na verdade uma *system call*) **fork**. Cada processo tem o seu próprio **PCB** em separado.

**Thread**: um processo pode criar várias **threads**, que parecem processos, mas com 2 grandes diferenças: são gerenciados pelo processo que as criou (e não pelo sistema operacional), e compartilham o mesmo espaço de endereçamento, podendo existir, assim, várias **threads** que acessam as mesmas variáveis.

**Quando usar**: Crie um novo **processo** quando você quiser que ele tenha vida independente, executando alguma função em paralelo mas de forma autônoma. Crie uma **thread** quando você quiser compartilhar alguma variável de sua aplicação, ou então gerenciar manualmente a sua execução.

**Exemplos**: se sua aplicação envia um email cada vez que um registro é gravado, você pode enviar o email em um **processo** em separado, pois teoricamente são eventos independentes. Se você está fazendo uma rotina de ordenação como o *quicksort*, ou *mergesort*, você pode criar **threads** que vão ordenar partes diferentes do mesmo vetor, e portanto têm que compartilhar o acesso ao vetor que está sendo ordenado.