# Diferença entre Pipes, Fork e Threads

Tags: php, thread, processo

A partir [dessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131108/existe-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-programa-thread-e-processo), me veio a curiosidade de querer aprender mais sobre o assunto, então pesquisando mais a fundo, acabei me deparando com mais dúvida sobre o assunto. Pois vi que existe uma cadeia de formas de utilizar Threads.

Podemos ver as threads como pequenos processos.
A grande diferença das threads é que elas compartilham os mesmos recursos e endereçamento de memória. Ou seja, é como se tivéssemos um processo que dividido em processos menores, onde há um chaveamento entre eles, cada um executando um pouco (como ocorre nos processos), mas agora eles compartilham os mesmos dados e recursos, e tem um mesmo objetivo, trabalham juntos. E achei curioso, já que as vezes tive que apanhar bastante para melhorar o desempenho de sistemas complexos que ainda estão muito lentos, e que precisam utilizar sub sistemas para melhorar sua performance.

Considerando o meu caso, numa implementação futura, gostaria de saber o que exatamente muda entre os três exemplos abaixo, e quando devo usar um ou outro e vise-versa:

**Exemplo de Fork:**

```
$pid = pcntl_fork();

if ($pid == -1) {
     die('Erro ao lançar thread');
} else if ($pid) {
     // thread principal
     //aguardamos a thread child terminar
     pcntl_wait($status); 
     echo "Processo child terminado\n";
     exit(0);

} else {
     //thread secundario
     //mudamos para um usuário não privilegiado
     posix_setuid(1000);
     posix_setgid(1000);
     //colocamos a thread para fazer algo,
     //ate que uma condição seja satisfeita e ela termine
    $i=0;
    while(true){    

           if (file_exists('/tmp/stop')){
        echo "Terminado thread";
        exit(0);
       }
       echo "Iteração : ". ++$i . "\n";
       sleep(2);
    }
}
```

**Exemplo de Thread:**

```
// Classe que aguarda um tempo aleatorio e depois imprime algo na tela
class AguardaRand extends Thread {

    // ID da thread (usado para identificar a ordem que as threads terminaram)
    protected $id;

    // Construtor que apenas atribui um ID para identificar a thread
    public function __construct($id) { 
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    // Metodo principal da thread, que sera acionado quando chamarmos "start"
    public function run() {
        // Sortear um numero entre 1 e 4
        $tempo_rand = mt_rand(1, 4);

        // Aguardar o tempo sorteado
        sleep($tempo_rand);

        // Imprimir quem e' a thread e quanto tempo ela aguardou
        printf(
            "Sou a thread %d e aguardei %d segundos\n",
            $this->id,
            $tempo_rand
        );
    }
}

//Execucao do codigo

// Criar um vetor com 10 threads do mesmo tipo
$vetor = array();
for ($id = 0; $id < 10; $id++) {
    $vetor[] = new AguardaRand($id);
}

// Iniciar a execucao das threads
foreach ($vetor as $thread) {
    $thread->start();
}

// Encerrar o script
exit(0);
```

**Exemplo de Pipe:**

```
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    // abre 10 processos
    for ($j=0; $j<10; $j++) {
        $pipe[$j] = popen('script2.php', 'w');
    }

    // espera a finalização do processo
    for ($j=0; $j<10; ++$j) {
        pclose($pipe[$j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Fork

Efetivamente, você **copia** toda a stack de memória do programa, criando dois processos distintos. O código passa a ser executado na linha seguinte a execução do comando que criou o fork.
Normalmente, forks são utilizados quando a comunicação entre as execuções não são tão frequentes, já que a comunicação entre tais processos só pode ocorrer mediante a modos de [comunicação entre processos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

## Threads

Todo o stack da execução do programa até o momento de criação das threads são compartilhados.
Isso facilita a comunicação entre as threads, porém torna necessário o uso de mecanismos de exclusão mútua (mutex) em alguns casos.

## Pipes

Na verdade são [forks](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php), com uma única diferença: Ele permite a comunicação entre os processos com o STDIN / STDOUT. *Nota:: Essa diferença só existe no PHP, já que pipes na verdade são um método de comunicação entre processos.

---

Em relação aos códigos, não é possível comparar eles, já que os 3 são completamente diferentes!
Se reescrever eles para que os tornem com o mesmo objetivo (Dormir um tempo aleatório, então fechar), aí sim será possível.

### Fork

```
$pid = pcntl_fork();
$pid2 = pcntl_fork();

if ($pid == -1) {
    die('Error.');
} else if ($pid) {
    pcntl_wait($status);
    printf("Processo child terminado (PID: %d, PID2: %d)\n", $pid, $pid2);
    exit(0);
} else {
    // Processo filho
    posix_setuid(1000); // Diminui as permissões do processo
    posix_setgid(1000);

    $sleep_timer = mt_rand(1, 4);
    sleep($sleep_timer);

    printf("Pronto... (PID: %d, PID2: %d) - Dormi: %d\n", $pid, $pid2, $sleep_timer);
}
```

### Thread

```
class AguardaRand extends Thread {
    protected $id;

    public function __construct($id) { 
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function run() {
        $sleep_timer = mt_rand(1, 4);
        sleep($sleep_timer);

        printf("Pronto... - Dormi: %d", $sleep_timer);
    }
}

$vetor = array();
for ($id = 0; $id < 4; $id++) {
    $vetor[] = new AguardaRand($id);
}

foreach ($vetor as $thread) {
    $thread->start();
}

exit(0);
```

### Pipe

*dorme_nenem.php*

```
$sleep_timer = mt_rand(1, 4);
sleep($sleep_timer);

printf("Pronto... - Dormi: %d\n", $sleep_timer);
```

*que_a_cuca_ja_vem.php*

```
for ($j=0; $j<4; $j++) {
    $pipe[$j] = popen('php dorme_nenem.php', 'w');
}

for ($j=0; $j<4; ++$j) {
    pclose($pipe[$j]);
}
```

Agora que tem os códigos iguais, dá para comparar as diferenças.

- Os stacks de memória são diferentes. Nos três:

  - No primeiro caso (Fork), a stack é copiada por inteira.
  - No segundo caso (Thread), o stack é compartilhado, a única coisa que não é compartilhado e é próprio de cada execução é a variável $sleep_timer.
  - No terceiro caso (Pipes), cada processo tem uma stack de memória inteiramente nova.
- O thread executa a partir do local indicado para rodar, (função "run()"), já no fork ele executa no comando seguinte ao comando do fork, no pipe no começo do arquivo.

Em relação ao uso:
Não existem "indicações" para quando usar um e quando usar o outro. Antes, quando os processos eram tratados diferentes de threads pelo SO, até poderia ter, mas hoje em dia não há.
A recomendação geral é: Precisa de ter comunicação entre os códigos? Threads. Não precisa? Fork ou Threads.
A única nota que preciso deixar é: Não misture os dois. Se você fizer threads, depois fork, o fork irá copiar coisas do thread que não deveriam ser copiadas e em quase todas as linguagens dá pau.

Comment: fork cria outro processo, thread cria uma thread, pipes cria um processo epermite a comunicação entre eles, certo? porém você diz que os SOs já não fazem muita distinção entre thread e processos, é isso?

Comment: Exato @danilo! Foco no não fazem *muita* distinção, mas existe uma diferença absurda.
Se formos entrar em detalhes, a maior parte dos SO hoje em dia trata forks como outros processos separados (ou subprocessos) - o que pode ser visto facilmente no "Task Manager", enquanto threads a maior parte das vezes não é nem mostrado diretamente