# Número de requisições simultâneas que um servidor PHP suporta

Tags: php, arquitetura-de-software, multithreading, paralelismo

Vamos supor que tenho um servidor com um processador i7 com 4 núcleos/8 *threads*.

Em uma arquitetura *multi-thread*, assumindo que se crie uma *thread* por requisição, apenas será permitido 8 requisições simultâneas, uma vez que o processador possui 8 *threads*?

Se os servidores PHP são *multi-thread*, como conseguem responder a milhares de conexões simultâneas?

Comment: Creio que com simultâneas você quer dizer: "clientes acessando ao mesmo tempo". Teoricamente não há limitação, digo, a limitação é seu equipamento. Talvez tenha algum atraso no cliente (os browsers fazem várias tentativas antes de desistir), mas se seu servidor estiver bem configurado consegue atender 8000+ clientes simultâneos.

Comment: Como isso em tempo de depuração exigiria muitas máquinas para se fazer um teste realístico, não se faz isso em ambiente de desenvolvimento, Para se ter uma ideia da real capacidade do servidor terá que colocá-lo online e monitorar seus status. Claro que um desktop comum não vai apresentar o mesmo desempenho de um servidor com 4 Xeon, 128 GB de memória. Mesmo que tenha muitos processadores, há um gargalo na rede (um roteador, um NIC).

Comment: Na prática se precisa atender muitíssimos clientes terá que fazer algum tipo de balanceamento de carga com um roteador inteligente que distribui as conexões por anycast com parâmetro de distância de carga.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não fazem. Simultâneo só a quantidade de processadores existentes. Existe uma ilusão de simultaneidade, como ocorre no seu computador agora. Tem centenas ou milhares de processos rodando e parece que tudo está simultâneo, mas não está. Vai havendo troca de execução.

O sistema operacional vai agendando uma [*thread*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131108/101) de cada vez em cada processador existente. Como a troca ocorre muito rápido parece superficialmente que estão executando simultaneamente, mas se fizer um teste básico de tempo verá que não é bem assim.

Estamos falando de processador. Acontece que grande parte das tarefas envolvem entrada e saída, então enquanto está lendo ou escrevendo dados externamente ao processador este fica ocioso então ter várias *threads*, bem mais que estas 8 pode ser útil já que enquanto uma *thread* espera o recurso externo responder outra que não está dependendo de recurso externo pode executar, o que ajuda dar a ilusão de simultaneidade.

Na verdade hoje é mais comum aplicações trabalharem [assincronamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/157440/101) e não depender tanto assim de *threads* explícitas para compensar o uso de acessos externos.

De qualquer forma tenho minhas dúvidas se um único servidor consegue atender milhares de requisições "simultâneas" com PHP.

O Node limita à quantidade virtual de CPUs porque ele trabalha assincronamente, não tem porque usar *threads* em excesso porque o processador é acionado conforme a necessidade, não precisa haver concorrência de recursos de CPU. Ele enfileira as requisições em excesso já que não tem como atender mais que a capacidade do hardware, assim economiza com o gerenciamento e por isso escala muito melhor, fora o fato que o aproveitamento não fica tanto na "sorte" do momento.

O Node ficou conhecido por fazer isto, mas todas tecnologias fazem isto hoje, em geral usam a [libuv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libuv). Em geral as pessoas não entendem muito do que estão fazendo, elas leem algo e acham que é aquilo que está escrito sem questionar, sem entender o que está ocorrendo ali.

Leia [É sempre garantido que uma aplicação com múltiplas threads rode mais rápido que usando uma única thread?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101) para entender melhor.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Apenas adicionando um outro ponto que vale a pena esclarecer. As plataformas que processam milhões ou bilhões de requests não tem apenas um web server, geralmente elas tem N web servers e N load balancers na frente.

Comment: Obrigado. OK, percebi que um processador só pode processar uma thread de cada vez, porque então dizem que o processador possui 8 threads? Então uma arquitetura multi-thread, tal como a utilizada por alguns servidores PHP, essas threads não são as threads do processador, tal como o Júlio Neto disse na resposta dele?

Comment: Existe uma diferença de definição. Existe 1 chip com 4 processadores independentes dentro dele e cada um com capacidade de executar duas linhas de processamentos separadas cada, daí dá a **capacidade de 8 *threads*** realmente simultâneas, todas as outras se interpolarão. Em geral as pessoas usam terminologias mais ou menos certas. *thread* é *thread* não existe *thread* de baixo ou alto nível. *Thread* é um conceito do sistema operacional entregue para as aplicações. Nos *links* explica tudo isto.

Answer (score 1):

Aplicações não estão limitadas às threads e aos cores dos processadores. Na verdade apenas o sistema operacional tem acesso à essas threads de baixo nível. E os sistemas normalmente possuem API's para que as aplicações possam criar um número virtualmente ilimitado de threads, dividindo o tempo de CPU entre elas.

Comment: Mas isso se tratando de servidores PHP, correto? Estou a estudar NodeJS e pareceu-me que está limitado pelo número de threads do processador, pelo menos fiquei com essa ideia.

Comment: Isso é algo específico do nodejs. Foi uma escolha do projeto o nodejs ser single thread. Assim realmente ele está limitado às threads de baixo nível da máquina. Mas nada impede q exista uma API para o node q crie threads de alto nível como servers de outras linguagens fazem.

Comment: Vale lembrar que, uma aplicação PHP, por ser interpretada, cria-se uma thread da aplicação por requisição. Uma aplicação Node.js é instanciada uma thread que recebe e trata todas as requisições, e para cada requisição, uma sub thread é criada e recebe injeção de servicos já instanciados.

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi Não necessariamente. Veja como exemplo uma aplicação PHP bem feitinha [como a do guerrilamail](https://github.com/TwixtedChaox/Guerrilla-SMTPd), é um loop só, que atende muitas requisições TCP simultaneas, assincronamente. É uma state machine que gerencia vários sockets, bem robusta por sinal. Assincronismo é algo relativamente simples de se obter com sockets, seja em que linguagem for (independente de ser interpretada).