# Instâncias da mesma aplicação compartilham objetos estáticos?

Tags: c#, variáveis, processo, static

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Windows Form application em C#, e essa aplicação poderá ser executada simultaneamente várias vezes no mesmo computador.

E estou com dúvida se devo ou não utilizar objetos estáticos (classes, funções, variáveis, etc.), pois elas poderão receber valores diferentes na inicialização do programa.

Então gostaria de saber se as várias instâncias do mesmo programa iram compartilhar as mesmas informações da variável estática?

#### Exemplo:

- Existe uma variável estática **A**;
- Quando a primeira instância é aberta ela recebe **1**
- Quando a segunda instância é aberta ela recebe **2**

Na primeira instância a variável **A** continuará sendo  **1**?

Comment: Não. Cada instância da aplicação é um AppDomain diferente e cada AppDomain vai ter suas próprias variáveis estáticas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não, isso nunca ocorre, uma instância é um processo separado, e na verdade uma sequer tem ciência de que existe outra, é totalmente separado e não tem como haver compartilhamento entre quaisquer partes da memória, não importa se é estático ou não. Então sim, continuará valendo o mesmo valor. Pode ver mais em [Existe diferença entre Programa, Thread e Processo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131108/101).

A não ser que use algum mecanismo específico para isso, como o Memory Mapped File, e só o que for colocado dentro dele é que poderá ser visto por outra instância que abra o mesmo arquivo.