# Qual a relação e as diferenças entre a classe Process e Thread?

Tags: python-3.x, thread, processo, python-internals

Estou [lendo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class) a respeito da classe `Process` e na documentação fala que ela segue a implementação de Threads, entretanto, estou com uma dúvida em relação a classe process e threads.

## Dúvidas

- Qual a relação que a classe Process tem com a Thread?
- No contexto do Python, quais são as diferenças entre Process e Thread
  do módulo threaing?

Comment: Isso não responde? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131108/101

Comment: Pior que não :( gostaria de algo com foco em Python mesmo para aprofundar um pouco. Mas pode marcar como relacionada. A resposta sua me deu o entendimento no geral, mais agora é mais especifico.