# Quando usar uma Thread ou um Processo?

Tags: c, sistema-operacional

Estou me preparando para uma prova de Sistemas Operativos e eu gostaria de saber quais são as melhores situações para usar uma thread ou criar um outro processo.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Existe diferença entre Programa, Thread e Processo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131108/existe-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-programa-thread-e-processo)

Comment: Processos são áreas de memória isoladas (não compartilham dados em memória de forma fácil e portanto é mais difícil propagar problemas para outros processos). A troca de contexto entre eles é mais cara do que entre os threads de um mesmo processo. Processos são mais vantajosos quando você não precisa criar muitos e quer maior isolamento entre eles. Troca de dados entre processos requer mecanismos de IPC (comunicação entre processos) fornecidos pelo sistema operacional.

Comment: Já threads dentro de um mesmo processo compartilham memória (o que torna mais simples acessar dados comuns, embora necessite de sincronização para evitar condições de disputa) e a troca de contexto é menos custosa. São mais vantajosos quando você deseja criar um número mais elevado de tarefas e compartilhar dados entre elas, mas com a desvantagem de uma falha em uma delas poder se propagar para as outras. O livro de SO gratuito linkado nos detalhes da tag [tag:sistema-operacional] explica melhor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olha, primeiro que todo processo em Linux possuí pelo menos uma thread.

Processo é um programa em execução que tem a sua disposição um espaço de memoria virtual. Ele é administrado por chamadas direto ao kernel. São robustos e relativamente fáceis de trabalhar. Para o um processo você pode gerar um fork, que seria uma duplicação desse processo a partir de sua chamada gerando filhos, em uma tentativa de paralelizar ações do processo principal. Eles executam em contextos diferentes com memoria segmentada e como forma de comunicação é através de IPC (inter process comunication), normalmente por **PIPE**, **FIFO **ou** Socket.**

Já a thread, tem algumas características diferentes. Entenda ela como uma forma de segmentar operações de um processo, chamam de processo leve (apesar de eu não ver isso é aceito assim). Threads costumam ser mais leves de gerar que um processo e costumam ter acesso no mesmo contexto de memoria o que exige mais experiência para programar. Isso trás algumas vantagem como o paralelismo, mas se não for administrado este acesso compartilhado pode gerar problemas e para tentar solucionar isso você usa de mecanismo como **semáforos** ou **mutex** em casos de acessos concorrentes. 
Também tem como usar threads sem concorrecia, como threads leves, gerando sua propria gestão de threads. Um material muito bom para você estudar são as protothread, um lib de header aberta que tem. De uma olha e debuga ela. costuma ser rápido, mais leve que uma thread gerada por uma chamada no processo e só que tem um trabalhinho extra para gerar mesmo.

Agora, são assuntos complicados, não basta apenas saber o que responder, veja os links abaixos, da uma aprofundada. Sistema operacional não é um assunto trivial e nem mesmo simples de lidar, e mesmo te respondendo ainda corro o risco de ter falado bobagem. Então não da para negligenciar, mesmo que seja muito comum ver pessoal não levando a sério isso.

Links:
http://www.dunkels.com/adam/pt/
https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/thread-in-operating-system/

Bons estudos

Comment: Falei muito e não falei tudo, quando usar? Ai depende, thread é muito especifica e usada mais quando se necessita esforço paralelo com acesso a mesma região de memória. Já o processo não tem como não usar, ele sempre estará contigo como pelo menos uma thread. Só cuidado que quantidade de thread não é solução para paralismo, o numero de threads no processo suportado pelas threads do seu processador tem um limite também, passando disso você tem um gargalo e perderá performance com trabalho extra.

Comment: Já para processos filhos, quando você deseja duplicar sua executação para o outro trabalhe realizando uma operação semelhante, mas com sua propria memoria, tipo abas de um navegador. Isso limita o acesso as dados que uma aba tem com  outra, o que fica dificil fazer se você gerar uma thread por aba, podendo correr o risco de uma aba acessar memoria da outra e quebrar a execução.

Comment: Onde thread pode ser util? Relógios, tratamento de eventos (mesmo que trabalhar threads com eventos seja algo dificil de fazer, já que um está em um contexto bloqueante e outro não bloqueante e tem que cuidar pois um epoll em uma thead sem as devidas flags faz com que eles se conflitem e quebre. Processar alguma informação ou calculo paralelo e assíncrono ao processo principal. Em resumo, se você realmente precisa de algo externo ao seu processo trabalhando alguma função especifica que alimente o processo e que pode ser mantido em paralelo.