# Como trabalhar com Threads sem travar o GUI

Tags: java, multithreading

Criei um programa que lê as informações de alguns sites, armazenam essas informações em ArrayList's cada uma com sua respectiva classe.

Na GUI eu botei algumas opções como procurar por nome e data e assim comparava os campos digitados ou as datas selecionadas pelo usuário com as informações coletadas do site, alimentando um JTable com essas informações, enquanto uma (pelo que li) Worker Thread fica atualizando de forma errada(criando um outro objeto de cada classe puxando as informações do site e só no final, trocando as referencias da classe utilizada como alimentação para a JTable)

Exemplo:

```
MinhaClasse alimentadorDeJTable = new MinhaClasse();
MinhaClasse alimentadorDeJTablecache = new MinhaClasse();
alimentadorDeJTable = alimentadorDeJtablecache;
```

fora que em um outro botão chamado Terminal, quando clicado, usaria a JTable alimentada para gerar uma outra JTable com a diferença de datas de informações do site com o mesmo nome, mas não consigo manter a concurrency(simultaniedade) para que isso seja exibido da forma correta.

Oque eu realmente preciso é de ajuda com Threads, caso não queiram ler os códigos por serem bem extensos, aguardo alguém com mais experiencia para me dar uma luz em como Threads funcionam, direcionar para materiais um pouco mais amigáveis com quem está começando

Segue abaixo uma das classe que puxa informação:

```
public class Porto implements GeradorDeTabela,Terminais
{
    private ArrayList<String> nmNavio = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> nmTerminalE = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> nmAgente = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> dtChegada = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Porto(WebDriver driver, boolean getInfoSite)
    {
        if(getInfoSite){
        getSiteInfo(driver);
        }
    }
    public void clone(Porto porto)
    {
        this.nmNavio.clear();
        this.dtChegada.clear();
        this.nmAgente.clear();
        this.nmTerminalE.clear();
        this.nmNavio.addAll(porto.getNmNavio());
        this.dtChegada.addAll(porto.getDtChegada());
        this.nmTerminalE.addAll(porto.getTerminalE());
        this.nmAgente.addAll(porto.getNmAgente());  
    }
    //Getters
    public ArrayList<String> getNmNavio()
    {
        return nmNavio;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getTerminalE()
    {
        return nmTerminalE;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getNmAgente()
    {
        return nmAgente;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getDtChegada()
    {
        return dtChegada;
    }
    //Métodos
    public void getSiteInfo(WebDriver driver)
    {

        System.out.println("Conectando Porto");
        nmNavio.clear();
        dtChegada.clear();
        try{Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)  
            .withTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
            .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class);
        driver.get("http://www.portodesantos.com.br/esperados.php");
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("navios")));
        List<WebElement> lista = driver.findElements(By.tagName("tbody"));
        for(int a = 0; a<lista.size();a++)
        {
         List<WebElement> listabody = lista.get(a).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
         for(int b =0;b<listabody.size();b+=19)
         {
             nmNavio.add(listabody.get(b).getText());
             dtChegada.add(listabody.get(b+4).getText().substring(0,10));
             nmTerminalE.add(listabody.get(b+14).getText());
             nmAgente.add(listabody.get(b+7).getText());
         }
        }System.out.println("Dados Coletados Porto");}catch(WebDriverException e)
        {
            driver.quit();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Falha ao carregar dados do Porto de Santos" , "Erro", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            throw new RuntimeException("Erro ao carregar Porto: "+e);
        }
    }
    public DefaultTableModel geraTabela(JTable tbPesquisa)
    {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{"Navio","ETA","Terminal","Agente"});
        for(int a = 0;a<nmNavio.size();a++)
        {
            for(int b=0;b<tbPesquisa.getRowCount();b++)
            {
                if(nmNavio.get(a).toString().toLowerCase().equals(tbPesquisa.getValueAt(b, 0).toString().toLowerCase().trim()))
                model.addRow(new Object[]{nmNavio.get(a),dtChegada.get(a),nmTerminalE.get(a),nmAgente.get(a)});
            }
        }
        return model;
    }
    public DefaultTableModel geraTabelaData(Date dataInicial, Date dataFinal)
    {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(new Object[]{"Navio","ETA","Terminal","Agente"});
        for(int a = 0;a<dtChegada.size();a++)
        {
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                try {
                    Date today = formatter.parse(dtChegada.get(a));
                    System.out.println(today);
                    if( (today.before(dataInicial) && today.after(dataFinal)) || today.equals(dataInicial) || today.equals(dataFinal))
                    {
                        model.addRow(new Object[]{nmNavio.get(a),dtChegada.get(a),nmTerminalE.get(a),nmAgente.get(a)});
                    }
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    System.out.println("Alteraram o modo de exibição da data no site do Porto de santos");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        return model;
    }
}
```

Este é a parte do GUI que uso Threads:

```
class Verifica implements Runnable
    {
        private volatile boolean flag = true;
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
                while(flag)
                {
                    System.out.println("Entrei na Atualização");
                        getPorto().getSiteInfo(getDriver());
                        porto.clone(getPorto());


                        getPraticagem().getSiteInfo(getDriver());
                        praticagem.clone(getPraticagem());

                        btp.getSiteInfo(driver);
                        System.out.println("Dados da BTP ATUALIZADOS");
                        emb.getSiteInfo(driver);
                        System.out.println("Dados da Embraport ATUALIZADOS");
                        lbs.getSiteInfo(driver);
                        System.out.println("Dados da Libra ATUALIZADOS");
                        sbr.getSiteInfo(driver);
                        System.out.println("Dados da SantosBrasil ATUALIZADOS");
                        try {
                            Thread.currentThread().sleep(2500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }

        }
            public void pause()
            {
                flag=false;
            }

    }
    class VerificaTerminal implements Runnable
    {
        @Override

                public void run() 
            {



                        ArrayList<Object[]> btpArray = btp.verificaTabela(tbPorto);
                        if(!btpArray.isEmpty())
                        {
                            listaDivergentecache.addAll(btpArray);

                        }


                        ArrayList<Object[]> embArray = emb.verificaTabela(tbPorto);
                        if(!embArray.isEmpty())
                        {
                            listaDivergentecache.addAll(embArray);

                        }

                        ArrayList<Object[]> lbsArray = lbs.verificaTabela(tbPorto);
                        if(!lbsArray.isEmpty())
                        {

                            listaDivergentecache.addAll(lbsArray);

                        }

                        ArrayList<Object[]> sbrArray = sbr.verificaTabela(tbPorto);
                        if(!sbrArray.isEmpty())
                        {
                            listaDivergentecache.addAll(sbrArray);
                        }
                        listaDivergente.clear();
                        listaDivergente.addAll(listaDivergentecache);
                        listaDivergentecache.clear();




            }



    }
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new VerificaTerminal());

    t2.start();

    t1 = new Thread(new Verifica());

    t1.start();


    btnTerminais.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {

            if(!listaDivergente.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println(listaDivergente);
                TabelaTerminais panel = new TabelaTerminais();
                panel.setTabelaTerminais(listaDivergente);
                panel.setVisible(true);
                }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nenhuma informação divergente" , "InfoBox: " + "Lista Divergente", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }



        }
    });
}
```

Comment: [Essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14959/4808) pode te ajudar na questão do "*aguardo alguém com mais experiencia para me dar uma luz em como Threads funcionam*".

Comment: ótima leitura, entendi perfeitamente como funcionam as threads, como posso me aprofundar?   gostaria de material para iniciar os estudos nessa parte que to com dificuldade, já li sobre semaforico, notify, notifyall,wait, sei que há design patterns e boas praticas, mas não consigo aplicar em meus códigos, porque não consegui a compreensão total do assunto

Answer (score 0):

Troque

```
Thread t2 = new Thread(new VerificaTerminal());
t2.start();
```

por no Swing

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new VerificaTerminal());
```

ou no JavaFX

```
Platform.runLater(new VerificaTerminal())
```

Comment: Obrigado, troquei o local da thread para dentro de um botão que atualizava a lista utilizada como parametro para essa thread e mudei para SwingUtilities.invokeLater, funcionou perfeito!