# Existe alguma relação de thread, pipeline e núcleos?

Tags: thread, arquitetura-computadores, cpu

Existe alguma relação entre esses elementos (`thread`, *pipeline* e núcleo da CPU)?

Vi que o *pipeline* ajuda bastante quando se precisa executar muitas tarefas, assim fazendo com que agilize o poder de processamento e podendo aumentar o ganho de até 4x mais (comparando sem o *pipeline*)

> A segmentação de instruções é uma técnica hardware que permite que a
>   CPU realize a busca de uma ou mais instruções além da próxima a ser
>   executada - Wikipédia
>
> Thread é a tarefa que um determinado programa realiza. Fio de
>   execução, também conhecido como linha ou encadeamento de execução, é
>   uma forma de um processo dividir a si mesmo em duas ou mais tarefas
>   que podem ser executadas concorrencialmente. - Wikipédia
>
> Em computação, o núcleo ou *kernel* é o componente central do sistema
>   operativo da maioria dos computadores; ele serve de ponte entre
>   aplicativos e o processamento real de dados feito a nível de hardware.
>   - Wikipédia

Após ver esse conceito em arquitetura de computadores, automaticamente acabei relacionando com *threads* e núcleo da CPU, porém, não sei se são coisas totalmente distintas ou se possuem alguma ligação.

Se possuem alguma relação, qual seria elas?

[Fonte](http://producao.virtual.ufpb.br/books/ufpb-computacao/introducao-a-arquitetura-de-computadores-livro/livro/livro.pdf) - Página 27 - 28 (Aumentando o desempenho com Pipeline, Limitações do Pipeline)

Comment: De que *pipeline* está falando?

Comment: Como assim? (Não estudei a fundo esse conceito, então não sei te responder,  vou colocar a página da apostila para ficar melhor)

Comment: Rodrigo, qual a finalidade da leitura? Faculdade? Concursos ou para aprender novos conceitos? Se for para faculdade e concursos, as provas e os professores, constumam ser literais, copiar e colar o que está nos livros, geralmente usam como base os autores: Tanenbaum ou Patterson, Hennessy

Comment: @Luiz Augusto Conhecimento, e também para saber o que estou fazendo com meu código, etc.../

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pergunta é (ou era) um pouco vaga, mas eu diria que não há relação entre esses conceitos, pelo menos não com esses termos.

*Pipeline* é algo interno do processador, de forma geral você ou seu código não precisa saber que ele existe, como funciona, ou o que vai acontecer com ele, é transparente e ajuda seu código executar mais rápido por uma questão de engenharia do produto que você está usando, é um detalhe de implementação que te ajuda e só isso, se nunca ouvir falar nada sobre ele não muda nada a não ser que esteja fazendo algo muito baixo nível que demande altíssima performance, mas de qualquer forma você não pode manipular isso, no máximo criar algo que explore melhor o *pipeline*, em geral só quem faz um gerador de código para compilador ou alguma biblioteca muita específica precisa saber isso.

Claro, no momento que estuda arquitetura vai saber disto, é um conhecimento útil quando não é só *decoreba* e pode ajudar tomar decisões mais acertadas em certos cenários da programação, mas pára por aí o que é útil para a maioria das pessoas.

Núcleo é um termo pouco importante fora da área de hardware, para a programação para todos os efeitos cada núcleo é um processador diferente. Esse termo parece quase aleatório aí.

[*Thread*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131108/101) é um conceito do sistema operacional que pode ser exposta para sua aplicação e de forma geral o hardware nem tem conhecimento. É uma forma de manter um estado de memória compartilhado entre linhas de processamento. Algumas pessoas podem chamar essa linha de processamento de *pipeline*, um termo igual mas que nada tem a ver com o termo usado em arquitetura de computadores. A única relação que *thread* tem com núcleo é que o fato de existir mais de uma é possível fazer o mesmo processo ter mais de uma linha de execução e por isso pode usar mais de um núcleo, embora se você tivesse vários processadores com apenas um núcleo o mesmo aconteceria, portanto falar em núcleo aqui é circunstancial.

Por acaso *thread* [pode (mas não garante)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101) deixar a resposta a um pedido de execução acontecer antes (algumas pessoas classificam isso de ser mais rápido) porque o processamento (algo amplo) pode acontecer ao mesmo tempo.

Por acaso *pipeline* do processador pode (mas não garante) que algumas instruções que serão executadas ali (algo específico) ocorram ao mesmo tempo e isso pode responder mais rápido que o normal, o que acaba sendo considerado mais rápido.

Então ambos obtém um ganho semelhante em formas completamente diferentes. Se é esta relação que está procurando, então tem, ambos são coisas completamente distintas, não relacionadas, que executam de formas muito diferentes, que são usadas para propósitos gerais que podem ser considerados o mesmo (deixar a execução mais rápida na medida do possível), a relação é o propósito final.

Então elas têm uma relação semelhante a diminuir o peso de um carro ou aumentar a potência do motor ou usar um pneu mais aderente, nada tem a ver um com o outro, mas todos fazem o carro andar mais rápido se fizer certo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Esclareceu muita coisa que me deixou em dúvida, agradeço pela resposta. Até por quê como já mexi com pouquíssimo de programação gerou essa dúvida. Sobre a arquitetura, não é bom ir até o fim então a fim de obter mais conhecimento? Ou é melhor parar por aqui, lembrando que o meu objetivo é chegar lá na frente entendendo como funciona, e não apenas copiar e colar código igual no passado/presente.

Comment: `bom sim, mas se não vai trabalhar com hardware vai só no entendimento básico. Voc~e vai construir processadores? Se não vai precisa entender o *pipeline* mas só, detalhes maiores sobre ele só fazem sentido para quem vai construir processador. Um meio termo é se vai construir *backend* de compiladores ou algo semelhante porque precisa entender um pouco mais o *pipeline*. O grande problema de construir o conhecimento é não entender para que serve cada coisa, então nem sabe o que serve e o que não serve, e de certa está fazendo o mesmo que copiar e colar. Aprende e depois vê se te serve.

Comment: "o meu objetivo é chegar lá na frente entendendo como funciona" Ao ler isto me lembrei deste trecho, do próprio Maniero: "Todo programador deveria aprender como funciona um compilador. Mesmo que ele nunca vá escrever um. Há uma diferença enorme na qualidade do programador que entende isto (e outros assuntos) e do que não entende. Não precisa ser um profundo conhecedor, mas precisa saber como é para usar as ferramentas do seu dia a dia de forma melhor. Mas precisa evitar o cargo cult."  Recomendo a leitura:[Como é feito um compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/104818/110782)