# Impedir que o sistema trave durante um envia de e-mail em lotes

Tags: c#, .net, envio-de-email, assincronismo

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que envia e-mail em lotes para os clientes, porém se o usuário que estiver operando o sistema clicar em qualquer parte da janela durante o processo, aparece que o sistema não esta respondendo, interrompendo o processo de envio.

Gostaria de uma solução para que mesmo o usuário clicando na tela ou realizando operações em outros programas o sistema continue enviando os e-mails e informando a porcentagem concluída.

```
private void bnt_EnviarEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    for (int i = 0; i < grid1.RowCount; i++) {
        if (grid1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString() == "S") //VERIFICA SE E O ENVIO DE EMAIL ESTA ATIVO PARA ESTE CLIENTE
        {
            int COD_CLI_atual = int.Parse(grid1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            using(DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities()) {
                Clientes c = (from cli in db.Clientes where cli.CODIGO == COD_CLI_atual select cli).FirstOrDefault();
                string email = c.EMAIL;
                string nome_fantasia = c.NOME_FANTASIA;
                string cnpj = c.CNPJ;

                EnviarEmail em = new EnviarEmail();
                em.Enviar(email, "MENSAGEM DO EMAIL" + nome_fantasia + " " + cnpj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Método usado para enviar o e-mail:

```
public void Enviar(string Destinatario, string Assunto, string Texto) {
    string Usuario = usuario;
    string Senha = senha;
    int porta = 0;
    bool ssl;
    string servidor = true;
    Email = new MailMessage();
    Email.To.Add(new MailAddress(Destinatario));
    Email.From = new MailAddress(Usuario);
    Email.Subject = Assunto;
    Email.IsBodyHtml = false;
    Email.Body = Texto;
    SmtpClient cliente = new SmtpClient(servidor, porta);
    cliente.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Usuario, Senha);
    cliente.EnableSsl = true;
    cliente.Send(Email);
}
```

Comment: Trecho do código postado.

Comment: Idealmente esta classe `EnviarEmail` é que precisaria ser reescrita para usar assincronicidade. Dentro dela você está usando `SmtpClient`? Usa o método `Send`? Tentou mudar para `SendAsync`?

Comment: Editei o post e coloquei o código da classe EnviarEmail. Utilizo o método SmtpCliente. Como funciona o SendAsync?

Comment: Eu faria de uma das maneiras a seguir: utilizando [Application.DoEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) ou utilizando o componente [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), não vou responder oficialmente pois creio que existam soluções mais ideais.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O código básica para enviar mensagens de e-mail assincronamente é este:

```
public async Task EnviarAsync(string Destinatario, string Assunto, string Texto) {
    string Usuario = usuario;
    string Senha = senha;
    int porta = 0;
    bool ssl;
    string servidor = true;
    Email = new MailMessage();
    Email.To.Add(new MailAddress(Destinatario));
    Email.From = new MailAddress(Usuario);
    Email.Subject = Assunto;
    Email.IsBodyHtml = false;
    Email.Body = Texto;
    SmtpClient cliente = new SmtpClient(servidor, porta);
    cliente.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Usuario, Senha);
    cliente.EnableSsl = true;
    await cliente.SendAsync(Email);    
 }
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Async/SendMail.cs).

Seu código tem outros problemas como potencial vazamento de recurso, não trata de problemas no envio, mas a solução basicamente é esta.

Aí você chama assim:

```
await em.EnviarAsync(email, "MENSAGEM DO EMAIL" + nome_fantasia + " " + cnpj);
```

Note que você pode ter os dois métodos, um assíncrono e outro síncrono e escolher qual o mais adequado em cada momento. O sufixo `Async` no nome faz parte do padrão adotado.

Desta forma o código inicia a execução da tarefa mas não também continua executando o fluxo normal, ele não espera o fim da execução do método.

Para saber mais veja a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendasync?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_Net_Mail_SmtpClient_SendAsync_System_Net_Mail_MailMessage_System_Object_) do `SendAsync`.

Já tem uma [pergunta sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2793/101).

[Mais exemplos](https://www.dotnetperls.com/async) gerais de uso do `async`.

[Resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15140540/221800) com um exemplo mais completo.

Answer (score 2):

Seria deixar que fique assíncrono (não ao mesmo tempo). Utilize o relatório de erros ELMAH.MVC, e tente este exemplo:

```
public void SendThat(MailMessage message)
{
    AsyncMethodCaller caller = new AsyncMethodCaller(SendMailInSeperateThread);
    AsyncCallback callbackHandler = new AsyncCallback(AsyncCallback);
    caller.BeginInvoke(message, callbackHandler, null);
}

private delegate void AsyncMethodCaller(MailMessage message);

private void SendMailInSeperateThread(MailMessage message)
{
    try
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Timeout = 20000; // 20 second timeout... why more?
        client.Send(message);
        client.Dispose();
        message.Dispose();

        // If you have a flag checking to see if an email was sent, set it here
        // Pass more parameters in the delegate if you need to...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         // This is very necessary to catch errors since we are in
         // a different context & thread
         Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(null).Log(new Error(e));
    }
}

private void AsyncCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        AsyncResult result = (AsyncResult)ar;
        AsyncMethodCaller caller = (AsyncMethodCaller)result.AsyncDelegate;
        caller.EndInvoke(ar);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(null).Log(new Error(e));
        Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(null).Log(new Error(new Exception("Emailer - This hacky asynccallback thing is puking, serves you right.")));
    }
}
```

Comment: Como parece que o código veio de algum outro lugar você poderia citar a fonte.

Comment: Com certeza. Baseado aqui:http://stackoverflow.com/a/8758053/3973284.

Answer (score 0):

Uma boa solução seria a utilização de um webservice para envio dos emails, você só precisaria colocar os emails em uma fila persistida e o serviço de envio iria fazer o trabalho sem pressa e sem colocar carga no servidor da aplicação, você pode utilizar um serviço pronto como o [mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/) ou o [SES Amazon](http://aws.amazon.com/pt/ses/) ou criar se próprio serviço de envio que não é tão complicado.