# Um pouco mais sobre File.WriteAllBytes

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo, thread

Como exibir um progresso sincronizando a seguinte função:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(string path, byte[] content);
```

Esse método deve ser chamado de acordo com um `System.Threading.Thread`

Ex:

```
Thread wnd;
string wnd_file;
byte[] wnd_bytes;

void Install(string path, byte[] content){
   wnd_file=path; wnd_bytes=content;
   wnd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(BackgroundProgressTASK));
   wnd.Start();
}

void BackgroundProgressTASK(){
  File.WriteAllBytes(wnd_file, wnd_bytes);
}
```

Desse modo o aplicativo não sofra nenhuma travada durante o momento em que escreve o arquivo!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não dá. Este método é bloqueante mesmo. Ele deve executar por completo sem interferência externa. Você pode criar *thread* (e esta forma nem é a mais recomendada de fazer isso) que não vai resolver. O único jeito é criar um método que vá escrevendo aos poucos onde você tenha controle.

A pergunta está um pouco confusa. Para fazer o indicador de progresso não é necessário ter uma *thread* ou outro mecanismo semelhante. Se quer que todo o aplicativo continue livre para executar a melhor forma é usar uma técnica de as assincronicidade no método todo que faz o que você deseja. Veja um exemplo [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/47798/101).

Note que tentar executar GUI com *threads* diferentes você não consegue executar GUI em mais de uma *thread*. Pelo menos não em condições normais. O que dá para fazer é usar um [`BackgroudWorker`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1) (tem um exemplo de indicador de progresso). Simplificando seria algo assim (não testei):

```
var backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(); //estará fora do método de escrita

using (var stream = new FileStream(wnd_file, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)) {
    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream)) {
        var remain = wnd_bytes.Length;
        var written = 0;
        while (remain > 0) {
            var size = Math.Min(4096, remain);
            writer.Write(wnd_bytes, written, size);
            written += size;
            remain -= size;
            backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(written * 100 / wnd_bytes.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Async/SimpleBackground.cs).

Na documentação existe um exemplo de como escrever um [método de escrita assíncrono](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/using-async-for-file-access?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Mas se entendi o que você descreveu, não precisa disto.

Comment: então seu código me ajuda bastante mas o que eu quero é simplesmente criar um programa que realizasse a instalação de outro programa sem importar arquivos do tipo .zip ou outros!

Comment: Ok, se ainda tiver outras dúvidas é só ir criando perguntas.

Comment: outra coisa é eu tentar aplicar um thread em WebBrowser.Navigate("http://google.com") o Thread é iniciado mas a não tem ação nessa função!