# Stream sem conteúdo C#

Tags: c#

Boa tarde pessoal tenho o seguinte código:

```
 Stream retorno = new MemoryStream();

        using (var stream = new System.IO.StreamWriter(System.IO.File.Open("c:\\Temp\\file2.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)))
        {
            infoSerializer.Serialize(stream, Functions.ConvertLayoutConsultarSituacaoLoteRpsEnvio(objeto, Functions.PadraoNFSe(codigoMunicipio)));

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(retorno);

            Repositorio.XmlConsultarLote = reader.ReadToEnd();

        }

        using (var stream = new System.IO.StreamWriter(retorno))
        {
            infoSerializer.Serialize(stream, Functions.ConvertLayoutConsultarSituacaoLoteRpsEnvio(objeto, Functions.PadraoNFSe(codigoMunicipio)));

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(retorno);

            Repositorio.XmlConsultarLote = reader.ReadToEnd();

        }
```

O primeiro using é como a função era originalmente, e o segundo using é oque estou tentando alterar, pois bem... o objetivo e não precisar criar um arquivo físico na maquina, para isso estou tentando ao invés de criar o arquivo fisico estou tentando passar o conteudo para uma stream, porém ao chegar no `Repositorio.XmlConsultarLote = reader.ReadToEnd();` o Repositorio.XmlConsultarLote não recebe nada, auguem sabe onde esta o erro?

Comment: Não posso ver agora, veja: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101535/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/48747/101.

Comment: O 1º código já funciona certinho??

Comment: Sim funciona perfeitamente

Comment: Pelo código da pergunta não consigo entender onde você está setando a variável *retorno* e provavelmente esse é o problema. Você tem certeza que seu código está completo aí? Acho que está faltando informação, exemplo: onde está declarada a variável *infoSerializer*, etc. Quanto mais informações colocar melhor.

Comment: O primeiro bloco também não atribui a  `Repositorio.XmlConsultarLote` nada além do que uma string vazia, uma vez que em ambos o reder está lendo `Stream retorno = new MemoryStream();`. Se o primeiro está funcionando para você, o código que foi postado é diferente do que está rodando na sua aplicação.

Comment: @Brayan conseguiu resolver?