# Thread inicia mas não há nenhuma reação

Tags: c#, .net, thread

Estou com um pequeno problema que quando eu inicio um *thread* com uma função normal o as tarefas do *thread* são totalmente concluídas e o *thread* é finalizado!

Mas eu preciso iniciar um *thread* que faça com que um `WebBrowser` carregue a página sem haver o bloqueio da janela!

Ex:

```
Thread wm_thread;
string wm_addr="";
void Navega(string addr){
  wm_thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(nav));
  wm_addr=addr;
  wm_thread.Start();
}

void nav(){
  var wm_browser = new WebBrowser();
  wm_browser.Navigate(wm_addr);
  wm_browser.DocumentCompleted +=new delegate{
    CopyableMessageBox.Show("WEB URL: " + wm_addr + " LOADED!");
  };
}
```

O certo seria o `WebBrowser` carregar a URL desejada já definida na função! mas simplesmente o *thread* inicia mas o *thread* inicia mas não executa nenhuma das ações pedidas!

Comment: Você colocou um breakpoint no início do método? Se já, coloca uma MessageBox no começo do nav e veja se ela aparece....

Comment: não! apenas criei esse thread com as funções!

Comment: Coloca um breakpoint então no começo do método "nav" e vai indo por passo e vê se não gera exception ou algo do gênero

Comment: e só lembrando esse thread está no modo Single Thread Appartament se não haveria uma exception constando que o Active-X não conseguiu implementar o controle por causa de uma chamada de Thread!

Comment: @Metalus me dê um exemplo!

Comment: Breakpoint cara, você está usando o Visual Studio ou alguma IDE que dá suporte pra isso?

Comment: Visual Studio mas teve um bug na instalação que não aparece a opção de breakpoint!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20707/discussion-between-metalus-and-nathan1302).

Comment: A resposta resolveu o problema? Ou pelo menos ajudou? Precisa mudar algo para aceitá-la?

Answer (score 1):

*Threads* são complicadas. Mesmo especialistas nelas evitam usá-las de forma direta quando podem. Prefira usar [`Task`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1)s sempre que possível. Esta é a recomendação oficial e há motivos para isto. Evite usar exemplos antigos e mesmo usando exemplos novos, espere muitos problemas com uma tecnologia complexa (várias coisas no seu código usam coisas não recomendadas). Sem o completo domínio do que se está usando fica difícil desenvolver algo avançado.

[Nessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8610197/221800) no SO há uma implementação de um `WebBrowser` assíncrono que eu acho que é o que você realmente quer.

A implementação não é das melhores mas já é um começo. A resposta do Eric Lippert dá indicações do que pode ser melhorado e dos problemas existentes nessa implementação.

```
public class WebBrowserAsync {
    protected WebBrowser WebBrowser;
    private ManualResetEventmre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public void SetBrowser(WebBrowser browser) {
        this.WebBrowser = browser;
        browser.LoadCompleted += new LoadCompletedEventHandler(WebBrowser_LoadCompleted);
    }

    public async void NavigateAsync(string url, Action action) {
        Navigate(url);
        await Task.Factory.StartNew((Action)(() => { //isto ainda me parece certo
            mre.WaitOne();
            mre.Reset();
        }));
        action();
    }

    public void Navigate(string url) {
        WebBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(url));
    }

    void WebBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e) {
        mre.Set();
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Async/WebBrowser.cs).

Uso:

```
public async void NavigateToGoogle() {
    var browser = new WebBrowser();
    await browser.NavigateAsync("www.google.com", () => CopyableMessageBox.Show("WEB URL: " + wm_addr + " LOADED!"));
}
```

Com esta classe substituindo a `WebBrowser` já fica mais fácil obter o resultado desejado. Estou respondendo mais para não deixar sem alguma resposta. Esta implementação é ingênua, não contempla tudo o que é necessário fazer. Te dar pronto algo apropriado levaria horas.

Uma das coisas que falta nele é uma forma de executar algo quando a carga do documento é completada. Na verdade para deixar esta versão assíncrona rodando completamente separada no mesmo nível da versão oficial do .NET levaria dias para implementar.

A versão escrita em VB.NET está um pouco melhor mas teria que traduzir. Olhe especialmente o `WhenDocumentCompleted`.

[Leia mais sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/19172/101).

Não sei se te ajuda mas é o que eu consigo responder. Fora isto eu teria que passar horas ou dias estudando o assunto para algo que eu não estou precisando.

Se quiser continuar fazendo com `Thread` porque parece ser mais fácil, boa sorte em entender todas as implicações de fazer isto corretamente usando GUI. Não deixa de ser uma jornada interessante.

Um adendo sobre o *breakpoint*: não use um software que está mal instalado. Arrume este problema. Apesar que eu duvido que uma má instalação vai deixar você criar aplicações e não deixar usar o *breakpoint*. Aprender *debugar* é uma das coisas mais importantes que um desenvolvedor deve saber. E *debugar* tarefas paralelas é algo extremamente complexo. Sabendo seguir o fluxo de execução já ajuda entender o que está acontecendo.

Comment: thread's não são complicadas. Você pode fazer seu código como uma rotina normal, e depois de funcionar colocar o código dentro de uma thread.

Comment: Você pode ter esta opinião. Os especialistas em *threads* dizem que elas são complicadas, eles até criam melhores abstrações para não ter que lidar com elas. Justamente por achar que elas são simples é que mora o maior perigo. As pessoas usam indiscriminadamente sem entender todas as implicações.

Comment: Novamente discordo, pois sou especialista justamente nesta área.

Comment: Não tenho como saber. Eu sei apenas das pessoas que eu posso certificar que elas consideram complicado e recomendam evitar seu uso. Por isso a sua afirmação indica o oposto. De qualquer forma você pode responder a questão da forma que achar melhor.

Comment: Cada um adquire conhecimento em uma área de interesse, meu foco é background, programação a nível de sistema operacional, portanto multi-thread é inerente a esta área. Portanto a complexidade é inversamente proporcional ao desconhecimento ou domínio da tecnologia.