# Qual a diferença entre SmtpClient.SendAsync() e SmtpClient.Send() utilizando Thread?

Tags: c#, .net, thread, envio-de-email, async

Qual diferença entre utilizar `SmtpClient.SendAsync()` e criar *threads* e executar o `SmtpClient.Send()` para o envio de mensagens? Há muita diferença de performance ou consumo de recursos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os dois métodos produzem o mesmo resultado. A diferença é só na maneira de fazer. Um deles bloqueia a *thread* em que ele for chamado. A técnica que se costuma usar nesses casos é criar uma *thread* dedicada para sua execução não bloqueando a linha de execução normal. Pela pergunta imagino que saiba como fazer.

Grosso modo isso é a mesma coisa que fazer *layout* de HTML com `<table>`. O mecanismo não foi feito para isso, mas como não tinha nada melhor ele foi usado e dá resultado.

Mas se tem um mecanismo melhor, por que não o usar? O método assíncrono foi criado para oferecer uma forma mais conveniente, fácil de usar e com menos possibilidades de *bugs*. Fazer algo rodar em *threads* separadas não é tão fácil quanto parece. tem muita coisa que pode dar errada.

Um exemplo é ter que se virar para cancelar essa *thread*, outro é ter que dar uma volta enorme para saber quando ela termina e fazer o que precisa no encerramento da *thread*. Se tiver um erro (exceção) pode não tratar adequadamente por estar em outra *thread*.

O [`SmtpClient.SendAsync()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendasync?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0#System_Net_Mail_SmtpClient_SendAsync_System_Net_Mail_MailMessage_System_Object_) possui uma base bem desenvolvida para rodar sem bloquear a *thread* atual e você não precisa se preocupar como ele faz isso. Pode até ser que ele crie *threads*, mas ele fará do melhor jeito e você não precisa se preocupar.

Ele possui um sistema sofisticado incluindo uma técnica de cancelamento, que é algo que a maioria dos programadores ignoram até mesmo a importância dele.

O mais adequado é usar com [`await`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2793/101).

Por outro lado, não é possível enviar as mensagens assincronamente de forma paralela. Se precisa disto vai ter que fazer o envio paralelo por conta própria usando o [`SmtpClient.send()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.send?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-7.0#System_Net_Mail_SmtpClient_Send_System_Net_Mail_MailMessage_), provavelmente em conjunto com a [TPL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ou outro mecanismo (até mesmo tudo na mão). Ou pode usar uma outra API que tenha tudo isso mais pronto. [Um exemplo](https://talkdotnet.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/sending-bulk-emails-with-tasks-parallel-foreach/).

Answer (score 2):

[`smtpClient.send()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/swas0fwc(v=vs.110).aspx): Envia a mensagem especificada a um servidor SMTP para entrega. Vai iniciar o envio no thread main/ui e bloquearia.

[`smtpClient.SendAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/x5x13z6h(v=vs.110).aspx): Envia a mensagem de email especificada em um servidor SMTP para entrega. Esse método não bloqueia o thread de chamada e permite que o chamador transfira objeto ao método que é invocado quando a operação é terminada. Vai pegar um thread do pool de threads .NET e executar o método nesse segmento. Portanto, o seu UI principal não irá travar ou bloquear.

Comment: mas no caso que descrevi acima, o uso de SmtpClient.Send() em Threads teoricamente não evitaria que a Thread main travasse?

Comment: @TotallyUncool, o  SmtpClient.Send() envia a mensagem de e-mail especificado para um servidor SMTP para entrega. Este método não bloqueia o segmento de chamada e permite ao "chamador" passar um objeto para o método que é invocado quando a operação for concluída.

Comment: Vê se te ajuda a entender melhor: http://www.macoratti.net/10/12/c_email2.htm e http://www.andrealveslima.com.br/blog/index.php/2015/05/13/enviando-e-mails-com-c/

Answer (score 1):

É simples.

Se você utilizar o `.SendAsync()` ele cria uma nova *thread* pra fazer esse send e a *Main thread* continua a ler as linhas como se nada tivesse acontecido. Aí, quando a nova *thread* acabar o método `.SendAsync` ele devolve a resposta em um método de *callback*, que deve ser configurado.

O `.Send` faz a *Main thread* esperar a resposta desse método e essa *thread* fica travada esperando o `.Send` terminar.

Se você usar `.SendAsync` você consegue fazer o envio da mensagem paralelamente enquanto faz outra coisa, aumentando a *performance*. Mas tem que tomar cuidado, não use *threads* assim se você precisa da resposta já no fluxo principal do código porque pode acontecer de passar por essa parte de código e você não ter ela ainda.