# Diferença é a entre BackgroundWorker e Task.Run()?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, async

Geralmente quando eu tinha que fazer alguma operação em *background*, principalmente que envolvesse atualização de barra de progresso ou *labels* eu utilizava o `BackgroundWorker`, com seus eventos `WorkerReportsProgress`e `DoWork`.

Recentemente me deparei com o fonte de outro desenvolvedor que utilizava `Task.Run()` com `await` e a interface `IProgress`.

Há diferença significativas de performance ou quando um método é mais recomendado que o outro?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vamos olhar á interface do [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) (coloquei só a infomacao mais relevante).

**Métodos**

- `CancelAsync()` - cancela uma operação
- `RunWorkerAsync()` - o woker começa a trabalhar
- `ReportProgress()` - Invoca o `ProgressChanged`

**Eventos**

- `DoWork` - Este evento é chamado quando o worker começa a trabalhar
- `ProgressChanged` - Este evento é chamado quando o worker quer notificar a user-interface que completou parte do seu trabalho
- `RunWorkerCompleted`  - Este evento é chamado quando o woker completou o seu trabalho

Um exemplo da sua utilização está no `link` que mencionei.

---

Agora tenho que provar que posso fazer o mesmo com uma `Task`.

```
var task = Task.Run(() => {/*O trabalho vai aqui*/});
var result = await task; // A task acaba aqui (Do Work + RunWorkerCompleted)
```

Faltam duas coisas para resolver: cancelamento e *report* de progresso.

Cancelamento é feito com um [CancellationToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var cancela = new CancellationTokenSource();
var task = Task.Run(() => {
    cancela.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();/*pode chamar mais vezes*/
    /*O trabalho vai aqui*/
}, cancela.Token);
cancela.Cancel();
var result = await task; // A task acaba aqui (Do Work + RunWorkerCompleted)
```

Mas de fato a única coisa que a `Task` nao tem é report de progresso e daí surge a necessidade de algo extra, tal como [`IProgress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298(v=vs.110).aspx). Que é simples de implementar.

Resumindo o `Task` faz o mesmo, com menos código (ou com código mais limpo) e ele substitui de fato o velho `BackgroundWorker`.

Answer (score 7):

Significativas eu não saberia dizer. Os mecanismos são muito diferentes, mas servem para mais ou menos a mesma coisa, pelo menos se o `Task.Run()` for usado para resolver o mesmo problema.

Obviamente a forma de usá-lo é bem diferente, especialmente se deseja ser notificado do progresso, mas o resultado não muda muito.

O `BackgroundWorker` não teria sido criado se o .NET tivesse o [`await`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2793/101) desde o princípio. Ele é mais modernos, é o jeito certo de fazer, foi melhor pensado e é um mecanismo mais geral. Certamente a forma mais moderna é mais simples de escrever e pra mim é mais intuitiva.

Não tem nada errado em continuar com a forma antiga se preferir mesmo, mas [é considerado obsoleto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Claro que se comparar o `Task.Run()` sem contexto não dá, ele é mais poderoso, flexível e geral. A comparação só cabe em uma forma bem específica de seu uso.

Exemplo de operação que não trava a UI:

```
private async void buttonGeraBoletos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    await Task.Run(() => GeraBoletos());
    MessageBox.Show("Tudo gerado");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Async/Background.cs).

Dá para fazer em paralelo também, o que pode terminar bem mais rápido.