# Abortar Thread através de outro processo em C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, thread

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em ASP.Net 5.0, onde ele precisa iniciar uma tarefa através de uma `Thread` Secundária, conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
//Inicia processo de pesquisa            
var ppBlo = new ProcessoPesquisaBLO();

//Cria a Thread para rodar o processo
Thread tProcesso = new Thread(ppBlo.IniciarPesquisa);
tProcesso.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
tProcesso.Start();
```

Essa implementação esta dentro de uma função que pode ser disparada por usuários distintos em momentos diferentes, por se tratar de uma aplicação Web.

Porém, em uma segunda tela tem a listagem de todas as `Threads`. E o usuário poderá interromper a execução a qualquer momento.

Além de ter um limite de `Threads` em execução simultânea que o usuário pode ter.

**Dúvida**

Precioso de alguma forma para abortar as `Threads` que estão em execução (já que o usuário poderá encerrar a qualquer momento). E a função que ira fazer esse procedimento, não tem acesso aos atributos da classe da função de onde é criadas as `Threads`.

Não sei se é útil para alguma coisa, mas, estou armazenando o valor do atributo `ManagedThreadId` de cada `Thread` criada no banco de dados.

Comment: Meio perigoso, mas se for fazer, pode criar uma classe singleton que possua uma lista de threads com a identificação do usuário, daí vc pode acessar de qualquer parte do sistema, poderia filtrar por usuário finalizar e etc. Eu usaria Task, é mais atual, e se adapta melhor à diversas situações, além de possuir o método ContinueWith, com ele vc pode colocar uma ação para quando a tarefa terminar, como remove-la da lista por exemplo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em .Net as threads sao recicladas automáticamente quando acabam o trabalho delas.
A única coisa que voce tem que assegurar é que as threads acabam o mais rápido possível. Também nao existe nenhuma forma **fácil** de obter todas as threads managed associadas a um processo, pelo que deve de guardar as threads que cria numa lista.

```
private static readonly List<Thread> _threads = new List<Thread>();

Thread tProcesso = new Thread(ppBlo.IniciarPesquisa);
tProcesso.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
tProcesso.Start();
_threads.Add(tProcesso);
```

Agora voce pode Interromper as threads

A ideia é que voce interrompa a thread, de forma a que ela saia com `ThreadInterruptedException`.

Para isso voce tem que chamar o método `Interrupt` da thread.

```
//procure as threads do usuario aqui
var threads = _threads.where(t => t.ManagedThreadId == 1);
foreach(var thread in threads){
    thread.Interrupt();
    _threads.Remove(thread); //lembre-se de apagar a thread da lista
}
```

Nota que se as threads nunca entrarem numa condicao de bloqueio como `Thread.Sleep`, `WaitForSingleObject` (como o `Mutex.WaitOne`), `Thread.Join`, esta excepcao nunca ocerrerá (isto só acontece se a thread for 100% trabalho de processador).

---

Como sugerido nos comentários por @FBatista o melhor mesmo era ter usado um mecanismo que permitisse cancelamento como a task.

[Eu expliquei nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/162450) como o cancelamento pode ser feito

Answer (score 2):

Bom, a primeira coisa necessária você já está fazendo, que é salvar o **ManagedThreadId**.

Para o usuário abortar, você precisa também salvar a lista para mostrar somente as dele, mas não é disso que se trata a pergunta.

O primeiro passo é importar a DLL **kernel32.dll** e utilizar para abrir e terminar a Thread pelo **ManagedThreadId**. Ficaria assim:

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr OpenThread(uint dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, uint dwThreadId);


    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool TerminateThread(IntPtr hThread, uint dwExitCode);
```

Após isso, basta terminar a Thread selecionada, desta forma:

```
        IntPtr ptrThread = OpenThread(1, false, (uint)id);
        TerminateThread(ptrThread, 1);
```

Veja um exemplo completo no código abaixo:

```
class Program
{

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr OpenThread(uint dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, uint dwThreadId);


    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool TerminateThread(IntPtr hThread, uint dwExitCode);


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Forking off threads...");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunInfinite));
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Thread " + t.Name + "(ManagedThreadId: " + t.ManagedThreadId + ") created!");
        }


        ProcessThreadCollection processThreads = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads;
        Console.Out.WriteLine("=> Total threads: " + processThreads.Count);
        foreach (ProcessThread pt in processThreads)
        {
            int timerSeconds = 5;
            while (timerSeconds-- > 0)
            {
                Console.Out.Write("\r Seconds before thread " + pt.Id + " dies: " + timerSeconds);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }


            IntPtr ptrThread = OpenThread(1, false, (uint)pt.Id);
            if (AppDomain.GetCurrentThreadId() != pt.Id)
            {
                try
                {
                    TerminateThread(ptrThread, 1);
                    Console.Out.Write(". Thread killed.\n");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }
            }
            else
                Console.Out.Write(". Not killing... It's the current thread!\n");


        }
        Console.Out.WriteLine("=> Total threads now: " + Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }




    public static void RunInfinite()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
    }
}
```

Outra forma seria igual [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2357626/4843158), onde você buscaria as Threads e verificaria se o id é igual, mas desta forma eu não aconselharia muito, pois pelo que disse, terá muitas Threads em seu sistema.

```
public void KillThread(int index)
    {
        string id = string.Format("MyThread{0}",index);
        foreach (Thread thread in _threads)
        {
            if (thread.Name == id)
                thread.Abort();
        }
    }
```

Referências:

- [How to we Kill a ProcessThread](https://forums.asp.net/t/1092427.aspx?How%20to%20we%20Kill%20a%20ProcessThread%20)
- [Kill Thread in C#](https://gist.github.com/fresky/4984544)

Comment: Eu votei negativo porque creio que essa nao seja uma solucao adequada para o problema.

Comment: @BrunoCosta Poderia informar o motivo que pensa assim? Não criticando o seu pensamento, apenas para eu ver uma forma de melhorar a resposta.

Comment: Sim. Tem a haver com o fato que as threads em .net sao geridas automáticamente. Ou seja quando elas acabarem o trabalho delas o .net termina-as (ou reaproveita-as). O que voce está fazendo no seu código é criando threads nativas e creio que essa nao seja a melhor solucao.

Comment: @BrunoCosta Então, eu apenas fiz um exemplo para ele entender. Pelo que o AO disse, ele possui as threads por usuário, e que devem demorar para concluir. Ele possui uma tabela no banco com o **ManagedThreadId** de cada Thread. Basicamente, ele deverá alterar o campo **id** do código que eu postei, pelo ID do banco que ele diz ter na pergunta.

Comment: Eu acho essa abordagem meio estranha, mas sem conhecer o cenário do AP, não tem como eu falar se é "certo ou errado". O que deu para fazer é mostrar como excluir uma Thread pelo **ManagedThreadId**, que é o que foi perguntado. Mas entendo o seu ponto de vista.

Comment: @Randrade vou tentar te explicar o cenário. É uma ferramenta que sera usada por Call Center. E diariamente a Anatel manda uma lista de CPFs querendo obter todas as gravações das ligações efetuadas para o mesmo. Dependendo do tamanho do arquivo, poderá demorar horas. Mas, a qualquer momento o usuário pode querer interromper esse processo (porque importou o arquivo errado, e por ai vai). E não pode ter muitas pesquisas rodando simultaneamente por usuário, porque pode onerá a rede e os servidores. Talvez assim você consiga entender melhor.

Comment: @DiegoMoreno Já pensou em [trabalhar com Task](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/162450/20615) como sugerido na outra resposta?. Todavia, a resposta não funciona no modelo citado na pergunta?