# Como acessar e parar uma Thread? ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#

Desenvolvo em ASP.NET MVC5 e dentro de uma `Action` de `POST` eu inicio uma `Thread`:

```
[HttpPost]
[AutorizacaoFilterAttribute]
public ActionResult ProcessarEmails(ProcessEmailModel model)
{
    ViewBag.Processing = false;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (EmailAnalisys.State == AnalyseStatus.Stopped || EmailAnalisys.State == AnalyseStatus.Finished)
        {
           Thread thread = new Thread(() => EmailAnalisys.FilterErrorEmails(model.Label, model.Email));
           thread.Start();
            ViewBag.Processing = true ;
         }
     }
     return View(model);
```

}

Como eu abortar a `Thread` uma vez que eu não tenho mais acesso a ela pois já retornei a `View` ?

Edit: A necessidade de retornar uma View() é porque imagina que a caixa de email tem 1000 mensagens, e eu estou processando 1 a 1, eu preciso mostrar para o usuário qual mensagem está sendo processada, tipo "1/1000" > "2/1000", essa é a justificativa de eu precisar retornar a View().

Comment: No seu exemplo se a sua Thread gerar uma exceção, você nunca vai saber. O mais correto é você esperar a thread finalizar ao invés de abortar ela.

Comment: Fica aqui uma referencia para [como fazer o cancelamente duma Task](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/162450/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-backgroundworker-e-task-run)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pensando numa resposta pra pergunta, e pegando o gancho da discussão com @perozzo, que já postou uma solução usando `Thread.Abort`, fiquei pensando em outras formas de abortar a *thread*, coisas como semáforos por exemplo, e me deparei com o interessante artigo do MVP Joydip Kanjilal: [My two cents on the Thread.Abort and Thread.Interrupt methods](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3105821/application-development/my-two-cents-on-the-thread-abort-and-thread-interrupt-methods.html)

Nesse artigo, ele aborda alguns aspectos do uso de `Thread.Abort()` e `Thread.Interrupt()`, e lembra que na *thread* podemos tratar isso (detectar que foi abortada), usando `ThreadAbortException`.

No artigo ele lembra também que nenhum dos dois métodos é *thread-safe* (se não conhece o conceito, pode ler mais aqui: [Thread safety](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety)), ou seja, temos que tratar a concorrência a recursos compartilhados.

A parte que realmente chamou a atenção foi que ele, "em sua opinião", não recomenda abortar a *thread* usando `Thread.Abort()` por exemplo (em tradução livre):

> Minha resposta sincera é que você nunca deve usar nenhum desses
>   métodos para encerrar uma *thread*. É aconselhável não usar os métodos Thread.Abort
>   ou Thread.Interrupt para terminar uma *thread* - você deve ao invés disso,
>   aproveitar os objetos de sincronização (como, *WaitHandles* ou
>   *Semáforos*) e encerrar de forma "graciosa" as *threads* que você
>   está usando.

Uma outra ideia que ele menciona é usar uma variável *boolean* `volatile` compartilhada com a *thread*, que é verificada para continuar a execução da *thread* e pode ser alterada por outra *thread*, fazendo assim com que seja encerrada de forma "graciosa" como ele menciona.

Um exemplo que código do [C# Programming Guide](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55984):

```
// variável de controle
internal volatile bool _shouldStop;

// método para "parar a thread", que vai setar a variável
public void RequestStop()
{
   _shouldStop = true;
}

// método da thread
public void DoWork()
{
   while (!_shouldStop)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("worker thread: working...");
   }
   Console.WriteLine("worker thread: terminating gracefully.");
}
```

Uma outra forma de fazer algo parecido é usando um objeto [CancellationTokenSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource(v=vs.110).aspx)  . Esse pedaço de código (baseado [No MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/how-to-listen-for-cancellation-requests-that-have-wait-handles)) mostra um exemplo:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

void ExecutarThread() 
{
    // inicia o token
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    // Passa o token para a thread
    Task.Run(() => DoWork(cts.Token), cts.Token);
}

void CancelarThread()
{
    cts.Cancel();
    cts.Dispose();
}

void DoWork(CancellationToken token)
{
  while (alguma_condicao_de_loop)
  {
     // verifica se foi cancelado
     if (token.IsCancellationRequested) {
        Console.WriteLine("I was canceled while running.");
        // sai e trata
        break;  
        // ou dispara uma exception tratada pelo token
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
     }
  }
}
```

Os códigos são exemplos adaptados para demonstrar a funcionalidade, provavelmente necessitam de algum ajuste pra funcionar em cada cenário, mas são outras formas de tentar abortar uma *thread*.

Answer (score 1):

O que você esta tentando fazer é um **bad design**. Perceba que, o seu request é retornado sem a finalização da thread, mas e se a thread gerar uma exceção e não finalizar corretamente sua operação? Como você vai saber sobre isso se não tem um sistema de log, e pior que isso, provavelmente já apresentou uma mensagem de sucesso ao usuário.

Abortar uma thread pode causar muitos problemas, se você abortar a thread no meio da sua execução você pode ter inconsistência de dados. E já que você já retornou a thread principal, você não tem como saber se essa thread já finalizou seu trabalho.

Sobre todas as respostas sobre `Thread.Abort()`, vale ressaltar que isso **não garante a finalização de uma thread**. Quando você chama o `Thread.Abort()`, você faz com que a Thread receba um `ThreadAbortException`, mas a mesma pode chamar o `Thread.ResetAbort()` e cancelar o pedido.

O mais correto é você esperar o retorno da Thread:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => EmailAnalisys.FilterErrorEmails(model.Label, model.Email));
thread.Start();
//Se tiver algo para fazer a mais, pode ser feito aqui.
thread.Join();
```

Assim a sua thread principal vai esperar a thread ser finalizada, e caso aconteça algo de errado com a thread eu posso tratar de maneira eficaz (Não exemplifico no código como fazer isso).

Claro que, fazendo isso o meu código perdeu os benefícios do uso da thread. Por isso comentei do bad design. Para saber uma maneira boa de trabalhar com thread no seu caso teria que saber o que `FilterErrorEmails` implementa.

Comment: Eu discordo em partes com o que você disse, pois se eu esperar a `Thread` executar que vantagem eu tenho utilizando essa nova Thread? sendo que ela precisa ser assíncrona como já está sendo na action?

Comment: Se eu precisar esperar a `Thread` eu apenas chamo o método, é mais simples e limpo e da na mesma, mas não eu preciso chamar a `Thread` e retornar a `View`

Comment: Você não leu meu comentário por completo. Como eu mesmo comentei não tem vantagem em fazer da maneira correta, por isso o seu código esta com bad design.

Comment: Se você não quer travar seu front-end esperando um processo muito grande, o mais certo é fazer um Worker e deixar ele esperando enquanto o processo não finaliza. Simplesmente ignorar a thread e retornar o valor abre sua aplicação a falhas.

Comment: imagina que você recebeu um POST , você processa os valores e precisa retornar a `View()`(pois o usuário precisa de uma interface para saber o que está acontecendo), imagina que o POST é um trigger para executar algo que **NÃO** pode ficar rodando 24 horas em background. Como você faria isso com um "good design" ?  porque ao meu ver(posso estar enganado) não tem um "bad design" no meu código. É apenas programação assíncrona.

Comment: você mesmo disse que precisa de uma interface do que esta acontecendo. Como vai retornar um resultado de algo que ainda nem foi finalizado?

Comment: Puts, desculpa eu não expliquei direito na pergunta, vou editar...

Comment: Pronto Gabriel, por isso eu preciso retornar a View()

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74458/discussion-between-gabriel-coletta-and-leonardo-bonetti).

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar `Thread.Abort`. Segundo seu código, `thread.Abort();`.

Porém segundo um [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1560567/2466497) do Eric Lippert, não é certo que isso irá realmente parar a `Thread`, sem falar que é arriscado utilizar.

Segue:

> Deixe me adicionar que não há garantias que chamar `Thread.Abort` irá realmente abortar a thread em questão. É possível (porém nem um pouco fácil) de dificultar uma thread de ser abortada. Se por exemplo, você estiver abortando uma thread por que acredita que ela está rodando um código hostil e então o código hostil pode estar resistindo a sua própria destruição. 
>   Se você possui uma operação longa envolvendo código que você não é responsável que precise ser parada corretamente, a correta forma de fazer isso é colocar o respectivo código no seu próprio processo, não na sua própria thread. (E de preferência em um processo altamente seguro-restrito). Então você pode corretamente matar o processo.
>   Resumindo, `Thread.Abort` é a melhor indicativa de design ruim, possivelmente não confiável, e extremamente perigoso. Deve ser evitado a qualquer custo; o único momento que você deveria considerar em abortar uma thread é em caso de algum código de "desligamento de emergência" onde você está tentando desligar um `appdomain` da forma mais limpa possível.

Comment: é possível fazer o `Thread.Abort` a partir de outra thread, como no exemplo onde a controller já devolveu o resultado?

Comment: perozzo ok eu posso utilizar o Abort, mas como eu vou ter acesso aquela Thread para dar o abort?

Comment: @RicardoPontual é possível sim, mas não é muito fácil de fazer não.

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti porque você está querendo abortar a thread?

Comment: @perozzo porque a thread que eu dou start processa uma caixa de emails com + 1000 emails, e surgiu a necessidade de dar um stop nela, para por exemplo eu recomeçar. É mais para ter um controle dessa thread, porque se a caixa de email tem 20mil emails, eu teria que esperar todo esse tempo caso, e se eu precisar parar o processo?

Comment: E se você colocasse esse processo de emails dentro de uma Async Task com um timeout? Esta seria a forma correta de fazer o que está querendo.

Comment: A minha dúvida é a mesma do @LeonardoBonetti, se dá pra fazer isso no caso da pergunta dele, porque, até onde conheço, se você encerrar a execução de quem criou a `thread` (no caso, a Controller que já retornou), você "perde" a `thread`, ela fica executando mas você não consegue ter acesso a ela, para fazer o *Abort* por exemplo

Comment: Se você abortar a thread sem ela finalizar, vai dar problema. O mais correto é você esperar o resultado dela antes de retornar.

Comment: @leonardo-bonetti você teria acesso a thread se salvar numa variavel estática no controller (não recomendado!), mas acredito que o melhor é implementar uma das soluções proposta pela Ricardo Pontual de finalizar de forma mais "graciosa" que seria fazer "checagens" dentro do seu metodo de envio de email, voce pode utilizar session ou o banco para fazer este controle de semafaro