# A palavra-chave "async" realmente faz o método assíncrono?

Tags: c#, .net, async, assincronismo

Estava vendo um [vídeo](https://youtu.be/B2HDDKq4d3c?t=1871) (aos 31:11 minutos) e lá diz que `async` não faz o método realmente assíncrono, é mais uma "dica". Como estava em inglês e eu não sou totalmente avançado, ficou meio vazio o entendimento.

Pra poder adentrar no mundo assíncrono, eu fiz alguns testes, porém com pouco conhecimento e usando o *debug* ele não vai atuar de forma assíncrona acredito eu.

Se a resposta for "não faz assíncrono", então se é uma dica, qual seria a "razão" dessa "dica".

Comment: Tão importante quanto entender o async, é entender também como o await funciona, assim como o Maniero falou, esses dois comandos ajudam muito e já abstraem muita coisa, porém, cabe a você entender também o que tá acontecendo por trás dos comandos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

De fato declarar um método como `async` não garante nada. Esta dizendo para o compilador apenas que o método pode ser chamado de forma assíncrona, ou seja, pode ser usado com um [`await`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2793/101). Este é o comando que fará a assincronicidade. Você pode chamar esse método sincronamente se desejar, ainda que provavelmente ele não tenha sido escrito para usar assim.

Quando marcamos o método como `async` permitimos que ele possa conter um `await` dentro dele.

Atualmente um método marcado com `async` deve retornar `void`, `Task` ou `Task<T>`, `ValueTask<T>` ou qualquer coisa derivada de `Task`.

Você, o programador, deve garantir que o código seja executado de forma assíncrona, esse par de comandos só faz o trabalho sujo.

[Documentação sobre o assunto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Tem como traduzir as páginas, mas saber ler em inglês mesmo ajuda mais.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Opa... Obrigado mesmo, vou dar uma lida nessa documentação agora mesmo.