# Projetos com APIs síncronas e assíncronas

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, async, .net-core

Estou desenvolvendo um pequeno projeto e possuo, por enquanto, duas entidades:

- Produto e Cliente

A API de produto está assíncrona (com Task e async) e a API de cliente é síncrona.

Gostaria de saber se existe algum problema em utilizar essas duas abordagens no mesmo projeto? Quais os problemas, se existirem?

Outra dúvida também é quando é realmente recomendado utilizar APIs assíncronas nos projetos?

Comment: Acredito que não, você tem o código pra verificar .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em princípio nenhum problema. Claro que no momento que elas se inter-relacionem o síncrono sempre prevalecerá e a parte síncrona causará espera naquele ponto, mas se estiver dentro de algo sendo chamado assincronamente essa parte ainda manterá concorrência. Se você chamar sincronamente um código em um método assíncrono esta chamada será síncrona, e só uma chamada a este método chamador será assíncrono, oque pode não ser relevante.

Lembre-se que `async` é útil para IO, então o último caso que citei não deve ter vantagem em condições normais. A operação de IO tem que ser originalmente assíncrona para ter ganhos. Se a execução for muito rápida não compensa usar um mecanismo tão pesado. Estabelece-se o mínimo de 50ms de tempo de execução (não é receita de bolo), o que é relativamente raro ter operações assim. Somente com grandes volumes ou algum IO muito lento é que dará ganho.

Em processamento ganha-se concorrência ou até paralelismo com `thread` e não com `async`.

Respondi com mais detalhes em outras perguntas:

- [Quando usar método assíncronos ou síncronos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/201998/101)
- [É sempre garantido que uma aplicação com múltiplas threads rode mais rápido que usando uma única thread?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101)
- [O que são métodos Async?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175304/101)
- [Em C#, para que serve a palavra chave await?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2793/101)
- [Existem diferenças entre os termos Thread, Multithread, Async e Await?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/208321/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre os async, multithreading, paralelismo e concorrência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157435/101)
- [A palavra-chave "async" realmente faz o método assíncrono?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168186/101)
- [Diferença entre Task e Thread](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123173/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: A resposta é interessante porque está correcta para .NET Core mas nao necessáriamente para .Net Framewrok (estou a falar dos deadlocks que podem ocorrer devido aos contextos de sincronizacao...). https://stackoverflow.com/q/15021304 https://stackoverflow.com/q/48606313

Comment: @BrunoCosta No geral não vejo diferença, em código específico pode ser, mas a pergunta não é específica. É possível ficar ruim em qualquer um deles, esse mecanismo é bem capcioso.