# Qual é a diferença entre os public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> Index() e public ActionResult Index()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, async

Segue o código:

#### Exemplo 1 :

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> Index()
{

   return View();
}
```

#### Exemplo 2:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}
```

Por favor explicar a diferença entre os 2 com mais detalhes possível com `get` e `post`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A diferença é que o primeiro poderá ser executado assincronamente, então não bloqueará a execução da aplicação se o método demorar muito tempo.

Em geral você terá um [`await`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2793/101) dentro deste método chamando outro de forma assíncrona.

Até onde eu sei não faz diferença entre os métodos de requisição.

A pergunta não dá muito contexto, então não consigo responder muito mais que isso.

Answer (score 0):

No caso não vai fazer diferença e nem deve compilar porque o seu método não faz nada assíncrono.

Caso você faça alguma chamada assíncrona no seu código a assinatura do exemplo 1 é necessária:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    await MetodoAsync();
    return View();
}

public async Task MetodoAsync()
{
    // faz algo assíncrono
}
```

Na prática, todos os métodos que façam algo assíncrono precisam ser marcados como `async` e devem retornar uma `Task`.

No caso dos métodos dos públicos da Controller, isso permite que eles sejam executados assíncronamente pelo framework.