# O que exatamente faz o método Application.DoEvents()?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, terminologia

De acordo com o *help* da Microsoft, o método [Application.DoEvents()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Processa todas as mensagens do Windows que estão atualmente na fila de mensagens.

Mas o que isso quer dizer?

Por que ele diz mensagens? Que fila é esta?

Comment: Pode adicionar a tag [tag:winforms] se sua pergunta se limita à essa biblioteca. Ele existe no WPF entretando existem alternativas melhores para ele.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mensagem é um termo que o Windows usa. Quando você programa para Windows meio que você está usando um [*framework*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101) dele, então a aplicação fica o tempo todo se comunicando com o sistema operacional através de mensagens. É fácil mandar mensagens para ele quando deseja, mas para receber precisa se inscrever no *pool* de eventos e ele chamará sua função sempre que ele tiver uma mensagem sua aplicação. É como o sistema de eventos do C#, mas de forma um pouco mais baixo nível, basicamente uma função de *callback* e um enorme `switch` para decidir o que fazer de acordo com a mensagem recebida.

Este método lê essas mensagens. Não tenho certeza, mas é possível que faça com mensagens internas do Windows Forms que não são provenientes do Windows. Isto pode ser necessário para "destravar" o *loop* de eventos em aplicações com uma única *thread*. O seu uso simplifica a aplicação mantendo uma certa responsividade (no sentido correto da palavra, não como usam em web) da UI.

Na maioria das aplicações seu uso não é necessário e hoje quando tem algo que pode tratar a execução é recomendado o uso de [assincronicidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2793/101). Se não souber usar certo, e é difícil, pode criar [complicadores para a aplicação](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5183623/221800). Teve época que tinha mais utilidade por falta de opção melhor, então muitos artigos antigos sobre o assunto podem ter sua data de validade expirada.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

#### Que fila é esta?

Essa é a fila de mensagens de janelas. Não tem um nome próprio para além disso, e é algo que existe desdes os primórdios do Windows.

Veja mais em: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/win32/learnwin32/window-messages

#### Por que ele diz mensagens?

Porque o Windows não interrompe imediatamente um programa/janela para que ele processe, também imediatamente, algo "interessante" que tenha acontecido e que seja direcionado a um programa/janela.

Ao invés disso, empacota esse algo "interessante" numa mensagem, coloca numa fila, e espera que o programa venha consultar essa fila para processar as coisas que sejam do seu interesse.

Estamos falando de coisas bem básicas aqui: teclas tecladas, movimentos do mouse, cliques de mouse, a até coisas mais complexas como comandos de maximizar, minimizar ou fechar janelas, ou mesmo comando de encerrar programas.

#### Mas o que isso quer dizer?

Um exemplo muito prático disso é o comando `Alt+F4`. Ele não fecha um programa. Pelo menos não diretamente. Essa sequência de teclado é capturada pelo Windows, que transforma numa mensagem `WM_CLOSE`, que é colocada na fila, para que quando o programa a receba, daí e só daí, comece a processar o fechamento organizado da janela/programa.

Veja mais detalhes em: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-close

Em resumo, isso quer dizer que muitas coisas acontecem assincronamente no Windows. E isso ajuda a explicar um comportamento que talvez já tenha presenciado, onde um programa trava, o mouse não é atualizado, e tentativas de cliques do mouse ou teclas do teclado são "recusados" com um sinal sonoro.

Esse é um caso onde a aplicação *não* processou as mensagens até o ponto que a fila de mensagens está cheia (ela tem um tamanho fixo), e portanto não é possível colocar novas mensagens na fila. O sinal sonoro não é para a avisar que o programa está travado. O sinal sonoro é para avisar que a fila de mensagens está cheia.

O `Application.DoEvents()` meio que é para evitar a chegar a esse ponto. Na falta de um modelo de threads melhor definido, o `DoEvents` resolve isso. Ele *interrompe* o seu programa num ponto bem definido, e *repassa* o controle para rotinas internas que fazem o processamento mais baixo nível dessas mensagens.

Se tudo dá certo, o seu programa volta a processar depois do `DoEvents` e você provavelmente nunca nem ficou sabendo se houve ou não mensagens processadas.

Provavelmente, mas não necessariamente. Continuando o exemplo do `Ctrl+F4` acima, quando o processamento interno das mensagens encontra um `WM_CLOSE` na fila, ele não devolve o controle do seu programa após o `DoEvents`. Ao invéz disso, ele chama o evento/rotina de encerramento do programa/janela.