# Qual o sentido de usar await em métodos assíncronos?

Tags: c#, assincronismo, async-await

Estudando sobre operações assíncronas/síncronas um ponto não ficou claro, que seria o uso do `await` em métodos `async` como neste [exemplo](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4) encontrado no próprio site da MS.
Se o método `GetGizmosAsync()` é declarado como assíncrono qual o sentido de usar um `await` em `httpClient.GetAsync(uri)` não seria melhor que `GetGizmosAsync()`  já fosse declarado sem o `async`?

```
public async Task<List<Gizmo>> GetGizmosAsync()
{
    var uri = Util.getServiceUri("Gizmos");
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
        return (await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Gizmo>>());
    }
}
```

Comment: Isso já não responde? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2793/101

Comment: @Maniero, @Leandro Angelo. Minha dúvida não está necessariamente relacionada ao uso de `async`e `await` mas a razão pela qual usar um `await` em um método que é está declarado com `async`. Por qual motivo `GetGizmosAsync()` deve ser um `async` se o comportamento dele parece ser de um método síncrono ?

Comment: Mas o comportamento não é de método síncrono.